# Shortest terminating program whose output size exceeds Graham's number

Tags: code-golf, math, busy-beaver

Write the shortest possible program (length measured in bytes) satisfying the following requirements:

- no input
- output is to stdout
- execution eventually terminates
- total number of output bytes exceeds [Graham's number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graham%27s_number)

Assume that programs run until "normal" termination on an *ideal* computer<sup>1</sup> able to access unlimited resources, and that the common programming languages are modified if necessary (without changing the syntax) to allow this. Because of these assumptions, we might call this a kind of Gedankenexperiment.

To get things started, here's a 73-byte Ruby program that computes f<sub>ω+1</sub>(99) in the [fast-growing hierarchy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast-growing_hierarchy#Functions_in_fast-growing_hierarchies):

```
f=proc{|k,n|k>0?n.times{n=f[k-1,n]}:n+=1;n};n=99;n.times{n=f[n,n]};puts n
```

<sup>1</sup> EDIT: More precisely, suppose we're taking an existing system and modifying it only to have no upper limit on storage size (but it is always finite). The execution-times of instructions are *not* supposed to be modified, but the machine is assumed to be ideal in that it will have no upper limit on its operating lifetime.

Comment: This takes my [tetration](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/5562/implement-hyperexponentiation-tetration-without-the-use-of) question to a whole new level!

Comment: There was once a similar programming contest called the Bignum Bakeoff. Some of the entries are quite interesting; the results are here: http://djm.cc/bignum-results.txt

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## Binary Lambda Calculus, 78 bits = 9.75 bytes

Here is an expression in Binary Lambda Calculus that is less than 10 bytes, yet surpasses Graham's Number. This is over 5x shorter than my [previous post](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/6430/post/219469) in JavaScript. Since [Binary Lambda Calculus](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Binary_lambda_calculus) is radically different than JavaScript, I decided to answer this in a separate post.

```
010101000001110011101000000101011000000101101101011010000110100000011100111010
```

You can find some interpreters [here](https://tromp.github.io/cl/cl.html).

### **[Explanation I made on another post](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/31695/post/219649)**

Essentially, this binary expression encodes this lambda calculus expression:

```
(\f x.f (f x))(\f n.n (\g m.m g m) f n)(\x.x x)(\f x.f (f x))
```

The decodings can be described like this:

- `(\f x.f (f x))` at the start and at the end corresponds to the Church Numeral \$2\$.
- `(\f n.n (\g m.m g m) f n)` takes in a function \$f\$ and a number \$n\$, and returns \$f_n (n)\$ where \$f_0 (n) = f(n)\$ and \$f_{m+1} (n) = f_m^n (n)\$ using functional recursion. Let's call this function \$S\$.
- `(\x.x x)` corresponds to the function that raises a number to the power of itself, or \$f(x)=x^x\$.

Since Church Numerals naturally nest the function that they apply to, the lambda calculus string gets reduced as follows:
$$2Sf2 \rightarrow S(Sf)2$$
Since each \$S\$ adds \$\omega\$ to the growth rate of the function, and the \$f(x)=x^x\$ has growth rate \$f_2\$ in the Fast Growing Hierarchy, then \$(Sf)\$ has growth rate \$f_{\omega}\$, and \$S(Sf) = 2Sf\$ has growth rate \$f_{\omega2}\$.

This means the expression \$2Sf2\$ described above has the value of about \$f_{\omega2} (2)\$ in the Fast-growing Hierarchy. This is greater than Graham's Number.

Therefore, Graham's Number can be beaten by a program that less than 10 bytes!

Comment: You can remove 1 byte by doing `(\t. t S f t) 2 -> 2 S f 2` at the beginning. The 70 bits: `0100010101100000010101100000010110110101101000011010100000011100111010`

Comment: 63 bits: `010001010110010110000000010101101110110101010100000011100111010`. This encodes `(\t.t (t (\h g m.m h g m) t) t t) (\f x.f (f x))` and becomes `2 (\f n.n (\g m.m 2 g m) f n) (\x.2 x) 2`, which is greater than `2 S f 2`.

Comment: @2014MELO03 Unfortunately, my lambda-fu is not good enough to confirm the *"... and becomes ..."* in your last comment. Would you (or anyone) be so kind as to briefly describe the main steps involved in that conversion?

Comment: I just wrote a post about this program at https://googology.fandom.com/wiki/User_blog:JohnTromp/The_largest_number_representable_in_64_bits

Comment: @JohnTromp Does it output anything to stdout? This program computes a Church numeral, not a string. [The number 2 doesn't output "2".](https://tio.run/##S8pJ/v/fwErBwFzBOPH/fwA)

Comment: @2014MELO03 That website is for BLC8, the byte oriented variant. For BLC itself, there are several I/O conventions. For use in AIT, https://tromp.github.io/cl/Binary_lambda_calculus.html#Complexity.2C_concretely defines output for the universal machine for either delimited or self-delimiting programs. This entry is for Busy Beaver rather than AIT purposes, so the output is defined according to https://oeis.org/A333479 as the term's normal form. If you could please send me email, we can continue to discuss there.

Comment: @JohnTromp Your googology blog posting is very helpful, especially the easy-to-follow proof sketch -- thanks! That proof of course bypasses any need to show `2 (\f n.n (\g m.m 2 g m) f n) (\x.2 x) 2` eventually arises -- although I would still be interested in knowing how to show it does.

Comment: @r.e.s. Replacing `(\f x.f (f x))` with `2`: `(\t.t (t (\h g m.m h g m) t) t t) 2` -> `2 (2 (\h g m.m h g m) 2) 2 2`. This new expression has 4 terms, the first and last term (both `2`) stay the same. The 3rd one (`2`) is equivalent to `(\x.2 x)`. The 2nd term will be further reduced: `2 (\h g m.m h g m) 2` -> `(\h g m.m h g m) ((\h g m.m h g m) 2)` -> `(\h g m.m h g m) (\g m.m 2 g m)`. Renaming some variables to avoid confusion we get: `(\h f n.n h f n) (\g m.m 2 g m)` and finally the second term becomes `(\f n.n (\g m.m 2 g m) f n)`.

Comment: @2014MELO03 @JohnTromp It's only the `(\x. 2 x)` that I don't get. I apologize if this is something elementary, but letting `T = (H (H 2))` in `(2 T 2 2)=(((2 T) 2) 2)`, why can we say that the 3rd term (the second 2 from the right) "is equivalent to `(\x.2 x)`"?

Comment: @r.e.s. If we give any argument `n` to `2` we will have `2 n`. If we give the same argument `n` to `(\x.2 x)` we will have `(\x.2 x) n` -> `2 n`. Both reduce to the same term once any argument is given. Iff two functions give the same result for every argument, they are the same function. This is called [η-reduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus#Reduction).

Comment: @2014MELO03 Aaarrg ... it is too trivial :( Thank you for removing my misery!

Answer (score 21):

### Haskell, <sub><del>59</del> <del>57</del> <del>55</del></sub> 63

```
(f%s)1=s;(f%s)n=f.(f%s)$n-1
main=print$((flip((%3)%(3^))3)%4)66
```

How it works: `%` simply takes a function and composes it `n-1` times on top of `s`; i.e. `%3` takes a function `f` and returns a function of `n` that equals applying it `f` to 3, `n-1` times in a row. If we iterate the application of this higher-order function, we get a fast-growing sequence of functions – starting with exponentiation, it's exactly the sequence of Knuth-arrow-forest sizes:

`((%3)%(3^))1 n = (3^)n     = 3ⁿ = 3↑n`

`((%3)%(3^))2 n = ((3^)%3)n = (3↑)ⁿ⁻¹ $ 3  = 3↑↑n`

`((%3)%(3^))3 n = (((3^)%3)%3)n = (3↑↑)ⁿ⁻¹ $ 3  = 3↑↑↑n`

 and so on. `((%3)%(3^))n 3` is `3 ↑ⁿ 3`, which is what appears in the calculation to Graham's number. All that's left to do is composing the function `(\n -> 3 ↑ⁿ 3) ≡ flip((%3)%(3^))3` more than 64 times, on top of 4 (the number of arrows the calculation starts with), to get a number larger than Graham's number. It's obvious that the logarithm (what a lamely slow function that is!) of `g₆₅` is still larger than `g₆₄=G`, so if we print that number the output length exceeds `G`.

⬛

Comment: When I [test this](http://ideone.com/hb8xk#view_edit_box) with `print$((flip((%3)%(3*))3)%2)1`, there's a run-time error - can you say why? It succeeds when the `2` is changed to `1` (output is 81).

Comment: Oh... ideone seems to run a 32-bit version, so it gets to an overflow of `Int` quickly. On a 64-bit system, that consumes too much memory to reproduce, but of course it still won't allow to reach `G`. I need the (big-int) `Integer` type, so I can't use `!!`; wait...

Comment: Fixed it now, had to use explicit recursion to implement `%`.

Comment: I find `((%3)%(3*))2 n` actually grows faster than you say (a *good* thing), but my Haskell-fu is inadequate to understand why. For `n = 0, 1, 2, ...`, instead of giving `3, 3^3, 3^(3^3), ...`, it gives `3, 3^(3+1), 3^((3^(3+1))+1), ...`.

Comment: As I said: "`((%3)%(3*))n 3` is **larger** than `3 ↑ⁿ 3`". Or do you mean something else? Anyway, I changed the definition so that it's all equalities (at least I think so, to lazy to check now...) rather than larger-thans. And if you change `66` to `65`, it actually produces `G` itself, ain't that nice?

Comment: With respect to the program *before your latest changes*, I wrote `2 n`, not `n 3`: `((%3)%(3*))2 n` grows faster than what you said, i.e. faster than `3↑↑n`. The specific growth pattern is in my previous comment, and I don't understand Haskell syntax well enough to know what produced the `+1` in that pattern. But I think *your new version eliminates this discrepancy*, and it's very neat that now your `((flip((%3)%(3^))3)%4)n` produces exactly g_(n-1), where g_64 is Graham's number.

Comment: I'm struggling with the syntax, and it would help immensely if I could see why, given your definition of `%`, does `((%3)%(3^))2 n` == `((3^)%3)n`. I'm deriving (incorrectly?) that `((%3)%(3^))2 n` == `((%3).(3^))n`, then not seeing why `((%3).(3^))n`==`((3^)%3)n`. (I know comments are not the place for lengthy discussion, but perhaps something brief will help others too?)

Comment: Hm... I suppose this wouldn't suffice for a StackOverflow question, would it? I could of course explain it in more detail here, but this challenge isn't really about how Haskell function compositions work, is it?

Comment: No, of course this challenge isn't about how Haskell syntax works (hence my remark about brevity). SO might be the best idea. (I'm about to go offline for the day, though -- maybe I'll post something there later.) Thanks for your answer ... I'm trying to grok Haskell because of it.

Answer (score 11):

### GolfScript (<strike>49</strike> 47 chars)

```
4.,{\):i\.0={.0+.({<}+??\((\+.@<i*\+}{(;}if.}do
```

See [Lifetime of a worm](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/18931/194) for lots of explanation. In short, this prints a number greater than f<sub>ω<sup>ω</sup></sub>(2).

Comment: f_(ω^ω)(2) is about as large as g_(f_8(8)), so not as overkill as that expression would imply.

Answer (score 10):

## [Binary Lambda Calculus](https://tromp.github.io/cl/cl.html), <s>7.625</s> <s>7.5</s> <s>6.75</s> 6.125 bytes, <s>61</s> <s>60</s> <s>54</s> 49 bits

```
0100011010000110011000000101101100000011100111010
```

This encodes:

```
(\x.x x) (\y.y (y (\g m.m g (\f n.f (f n)))))
```

To simplify things a bit, let `H = (\g m.m g 2)` where `2` is the [Church numeral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church_encoding) `(\f n.f (f n))`. These are the first few steps of the reduction:

```
(\x.x x) (\y.y (y H))
(\y.y (y H)) (\y.y (y H))
(\y.y (y H)) ((\y.y (y H)) H)
(\y.y (y H)) (H (H H))
H (H H) (H (H H) H)
H (H H) H (H H) 2
H (H H) 2 (H H) 2
2 (H H) 2 (H H) 2
H H (H H 2) (H H) 2
H H 2 H 2 (H H) 2
2 H 2 H 2 (H H) 2
H (H 2) H 2 (H H) 2
H (H 2) 2 2 (H H) 2
2 (H 2) 2 2 (H H) 2
H 2 (H 2 2) 2 (H H) 2
H 2 2 2 2 2 (H H) 2
2 2 2 2 2 2 (H H) 2
2^^6 (H H) 2
```

The next step is applying `H H` \$2\uparrow\uparrow6\$ times to `2`. After an odd number of aplications the result is not a number, but after an even number of aplications it is. Here \$2\uparrow\uparrow6\$ is not an aproximation, and since it is even, the final answer will be a number. We will use \$\frac{2\uparrow\uparrow6}{2}\$ times a function that applies `H H` twice. The function `H H (H H n)` grows as fast as the [Ackermann function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_function), to see this, let's take a look at a more general case. The function `k H 2 n` grows as fast as \$2\uparrow^kn\$:

```
0 H 2 n = 2 n = n^2 > 2*n = 2{0}n

k+1 H 2 n = H (k H 2) n = H (\x.k H 2 x) n >= H (\x. 2{k}x) n
    = n (\x. 2{k}x) 2 = 2{k+1}(n+1) > 2{k+1}n
```

Applying this to `H H (H H n)` we get `H H (H H n) = H H n H 2 = n H 2 H 2 = H (n-1 H 2) H 2 = H (n-1 H 2) 2 2 = 2 (n-1 H 2) 2 2 = n-1 H 2 (n-1 H 2 2) 2 >= n-1 H 2 2{n-1}2 2 >= 2{n-1}2{n-1}2 2 = 2{n}3 2 > 2{n}3`, which is about the same as \$A(n,n)\$. So the size of the expression `2^^6 (H H) 2` is about \$g_{\frac{2\uparrow\uparrow6}{2}} > g_{64}\$.

Comment: Brilliant! This deserves way more up votes. I've detailed the proof a bit more at https://github.com/tromp/AIT/blob/master/fast_growing_and_conjectures/melo.lam

Comment: Always knew BLC was concise, but wow.

Answer (score 7):

## Python 3, 53 bytes

```python
m=lambda x:-x if x<0 else m(x-m(x-1))/2;print(1/m(9))
```

It computes the reciprocal of the gap between the 9 and the smallest tame fusible number above it, which is shown [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2003.14342.pdf) to be at least \$f_{\varepsilon_0}(2)\$ in the fast-growing hierarchy, thus beating Graham's number.

## Pyth, <s>24</s> 22 bytes

-2 bytes thanks to r.e.s.

```
DlHR?<HZ_H/l-Hl-H12)lT
```

Same algorithm as before. I changed the argument 9 to 10 (which due to the predefined variable `T` doesn't increase the length), thus making the output at least \$f_{\varepsilon_0}(3)\$, absolutely dominating Graham's number and every other answer so far.

Comment: This is very cool! I think you can also make a great submission to [Write a program whose nontermination is independent of Peano arithmetic](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/79470/20260) based the termination of `M` for all natural numbers. (Edit: Or not, the "for all" quantifier goes the wrong way.)

Comment: By the way you can golf the base case to `-x*(x<0)or ...`

Comment: You don't need to take the reciprocal, because it's just the total number of output bytes that matters.

Comment: This program is an infinite loop due to floating point precision. While Python `int`s are arbitrarily long, Python `float`s are not. We get `m(9) = m(9 - m(8 - m(7 - m(6 - m(5 - m(4 - m(2.999023318232446)/2/2/2/2)/2)/2)/2)/2)/2)/2`, which then recurses forever at `m(2.999023318232446) = m(2.999023318232446 - 1.1102230246251565e-16)/2 = m(2.999023318232446)/2`. Consider using the [`fractions`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fractions.html) module or pairs of `int`s.

Comment: @AndersKaseorg @E.Z.L. The program will avoid floating point if it's considered to be in the SageMath language (rather than Python), where the variables default to Integer and Rational types. In this language, the program can also be shortened to 43 bytes: `M=lambda x:-x if x<0else M(x-M(x-1))/2;M(9)`'

Answer (score 6):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), <s>29</s> 28 bytes

```
M?*GHgtGtgGtH^ThH=ZTV99=gZTZ
```

Defines a lambda for hyper-operation and recursively calls it. Like the definition for Graham's number, but with larger values.

This:

```
M?*GHgtGtgGtH^3hH
```

Defines a lambda, roughly equal to the python

```
g = lambda G, H:
  g(G-1, g(G, H-1)-1) if G*H else 3^(H+1)
```

This gives the hyper-operation function, g(G,H) = 3↑<sup>G+1</sup>(H+1).
So, for example, g(1,2)=3↑<sup>2</sup>3 = 7,625,597,484,987, [which you can test here](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/39dey90jvcS9JN29xCPOOMMj3VDB6P9/AA).

`V<x><y>` starts a loop that executes the body, `y`, `x` times.
`=gZT` is the body of the loop here, which is equivalent to `Z=g(Z,10)`

The code:

```
M?*GHgtGtgGtH^3hH=Z3V64=gZ2)Z
```

Should recursively call the hyperoperation above 64 times, giving Graham's Number.

In my answer, however, I've replaced the single digits with `T`, which is initialized to 10, and increased the depth of recursion to 99. Using [Graham Array Notation](http://googology.wikia.com/wiki/Graham_Array_Notation), Graham's Number is [3,3,4,64], and my program outputs the larger [10,11,11,99]. I've also removed the `)` that closes the loop to save one byte, so it prints each successive value in the 99 iterations.

Answer (score 4):

## Javascript, 50 Bytes, \$f_{\omega+8} (9)\$

```
n=(y,x=9)=>y?y-9?n(y-1,x?n(y,x-1)*9:9):x:n(x);n(8)
```

Here, n is a binary function. The function is defined as followed:

- `n(9,x) = x`
- `n(y,0) = n(y-1,9)`
- `n(y,x) = n(y-1,n(y,x-1)*9)`

The `*9` ensures that `n(y,x)` is an increasing function with respect to x.

- `n(9,x)` = x
- `n(10,x)` = 9^(x+1)
- `n(11,x)` ~ 9^^x
- `n(12,x)` ~ 9^^^x
- `n(y+1,x)` recurses over `n(y,x)` with respect to x.

We also defined n(y)=n(y,9), so n(y) grows as fast as  \$f_{\omega}\$  in the Fast Growing Hierarchy.

Now here is the twist:

- `n(0,x)=n(x)=n(x,9)`

This starts an entirely new hierarchy starting from `y=0` all the way up to `y=8`.

- `n(0,x)` grows at \$f_{\omega}\$ in the FGH
- `n(1,x)` grows at \$f_{\omega+1} = G\$
- `n(2,x)` grows at \$f_{\omega+2}\$
- ...
- `n(8,x)` grows at \$f_{\omega+8}\$

Therefore, `n(8)` ~ \$f_{\omega+8} (9) > G_{64}\$

Answer (score 3):

### Ruby, <s>54</s> <s>52</s> 50 bytes

```
f=->b{a*=a;eval"f[b-1];"*b*a};eval"f[a];"*a=99;p a
```

---

### Ruby, <s>85</s> <s>81</s> <s>76</s> <s>71</s> <s>68</s> <s>64</s> <s>63</s> <s>59</s> 57 bytes

```
f=->a,b=-a{eval"a*=b<0?f[a,a]:b<1?a:f[a,b-1];"*a};p f[99]
```

Pretty much fast growing hierarchy with f(a+1) > f<sub>ω+1</sub>(a).

---

### Ruby, 61 bytes

```
f=->a,b=-a{a<0?9:b==0?a*a:f[f[a-1,b],b>0?b-1:f[a,b+1]]};f[99]
```

Basically an Ackermann function with a twist.

---

### Ruby, <s>63</s> 59 bytes

```
n=99;(H=->a{b,*c=a;n.times{b ?H[[b-1]*n*b+c]:n+=n}})[n];p n
```

---

### Another Ruby, <s>74</s> 71 bytes

```
def f(a,b=a)a<0?b:b<0?f(a-1):f(a-1,f(a,b-1))end;n=99;n.times{n=f n};p n
```

Basically Ackermann function to itself 99 times.

Answer (score 2):

### Python (111+n), n=length(x)

Although this one is not as short as the answerer's Ruby program, I'll post it anyway, to rule this possibility out.

It uses the Ackermann function, and calls the Ackermann function with m and n being the values from another call to the Ackermann function, and recurses 1000 times.

This is **probably** bigger than Graham's number, but I'm not sure, because nobody knows the exact length of it. It can be easily extended, if it's not bigger.

```
x=999
b='A('*x+'5,5'+')'*x
def A(m,n):n+1 if m==0 else A(m-1,A(m,n-1)if n>0 else 1)
exec('print A('%s,%s')'%(b,b))
```

Comment: output to stdout?  also, you need a `return` statement or a `lambda`.

Comment: Also if A(m,n) returns a single value, then isn't A(A(5,5)) missing an argument? ... This is the problem with a challenge like this: it encourages people not to test their code, because a complete run is purely theoretical.

Comment: If you replace your last line with `exec'x=A(x,x);'*x;print x`, then the program is ok and the output is approximately f_(ω+1)(x) (assumimg the Ackermann function code is correct), which has more than G bytes even for x=99, say. (In my Ruby program, `f[m,n]` is a version of `A(m,n)`.)

Comment: @breadbox - Good point ... Theoretical questions like this require us to make sure a program is ok for small-parameter (i.e. non-theoretical) test-cases that clearly generalize to give a correct answer.

Comment: Its's longer, but if you want to use `eval` instead of `exec`, your last line could be `f=lambda x:A(x,x);print eval('f('*x+'x'+')'*x)`. Also, your def of A(m,n) needs to be corrected per boothby's comment.

Comment: Boothby: Yes, something I forgot to do. Breadbox: Yep, I noticed that at about midnight, when I was in bed, half-asleep. r.e.s: Will do. Thanks, guys!

Comment: @breadbox: Except if you have an compiler, which proves your theorem for free.

Answer (score 2):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), <s>24</s> <s>20</s> 18 bytes

```
"`'1$,*~'+"{.~~})*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/XylB3VBFR6tOXVupWq@urlZT6/9/AA)

```
"`'1$,*~'+"         # Push this string
           {.~~})*  # Becomes {.~}126* and this duplicates and executes the string 126 times
```

When executed, this string modifies the string at the top of the stack:

```
 `          # Parse it to a string inside the string  'foo'  -> '"foo"'
  '1$,*~'+  # Add '1$,*~' at the end                  '"foo"' -> '"foo"1$,*~'
```

When we execute this new string it does whatever `foo` used to do, but many times.

```
     1$,     # Get the number of bytes of the string at the top of the stack
"foo"   *    # Make that many copies of foo
         ~   # Execute all of them
```

We will be dealing with only one string, that will modify itself 126 times. Let `L` be the number of loops and `B` the number of bytes the string has. These values can be calculated with \$B=2^{L+1}+3L+7\$, but for simplicity's sake we will round `B` down to `L`. The number of bytes grows exponentially because every time a loop is added, every `"` becomes `\"` and every `\` becomes `\\`. Now the loops execute `L` times instead of `B`. When the string has no loops it just adds `"` `"1$,*~` around itself, in other words `L = L + 1`. With `a` loops it executes `L` times the version with `a-1` loops. This is exactly the same definition of `f` in the [fast growing hierarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast-growing_hierarchy) for when `a` is a successor:

$$f_0(L)=L+1$$
$$f_a(L)=f_{a-1}^L(L)$$

Before each execution `a` and `L` are the same number, so every time we execute the string, `L` becomes \$f_\omega(L)\$.

We execute it 126 times starting with `L = 0`, so the number of bytes in the output will be:

$$f_\omega^{126}(0)=f_\omega^{122}(f_8(8))>f_\omega^{122}(122)=f_{\omega+1}(122)$$

Answer (score 2):

## [Functoid](https://github.com/bforte/Functoid), 14 bytes

```
B"W(BiCA])9.Ef
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyvNSy7Jz0z5/99JKVzDKdPZMVbTUs817f9/AA)

The pointer wraps around whenever it moves out of the source code, this happens once here, making the code equivalent to `B"W(BiCA])9.EfB"W(BiCA])9.Ef`. The string `"W(BiCA])9.EfB"` gets converted to base 10 and becomes `"91772447243986"`. Now we can rewrite the code as `BkW(BiCA])9.Ef`, where `k` represents that big number.

```
BkW(BiCA])9         # set the current function to B k W (B i C A ]) 9
           .        # evaluate and print the current function as a number
            Ef      # terminate the program
```

Let `f_a` be a lambda function equivalent to \$f_a\$ in the [fast growing hierarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast-growing_hierarchy). To increase the index by 1, the function needs to be applied to itself `n` times \$f_a^n(n) = f_{a+1}(n)\$. In code this would be `f_(a+1) n = n f_a n = C A f_a n`. To get any finite index we just need to apply `C A` a lot of times to `f_0 = ]`:

```
f_0 = ]
f_1 = C A ]
f_2 = C A (C A ])
f_3 = C A (C A (C A ]))
...
```

\$f_\omega(n) = f_n(n)\$ = `n (C A) ] n = W (i (C A) ]) n`

The expression `B k W (B i C A ]) 9` can be reduced to `k (W (i (C A) ])) 9 = k f_ω 9` and this returns \$f_\omega^{91772447243986}(9)\$.

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3, 79 bytes

```
f=lambda x,y:f(x-1,f(x,y-1))if x*y else x+y+1
z=9;exec("z=f(z,z);"*99);print(z)
```

f(x,y) is a modified version of ackermann for golfing purposes

f(x,y) = f(x-1,f(x,y-1)) if both x and y are greater than 0

f(x,0) and f(0,y) each add one to the nonzero entry (if both are zero, it is 1)

Then the program does recursion on f(x,x) 99 times.

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf, and nice answer!

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, 68 bytes, however uncompeting for using ES6

```
a=(x,y)=>y?x?a(a(x-1,y)*9,y-1):a(9,y-1):x;b=x=>x?a(9,b(x-1)):9;b(99)
```

`a` function is similar to up-arrow notation with base 9.

```
       /a(a(x-1,y)*9,y-1)  x>0, y>0
a(x,y)=|a(9,y-1)           x=0, y>0
       \x                  y=0
```

`b` function is: b(x)=b<sup>x</sup>(9).

`b(99)` is ~f<sub>ω+1</sub>(99), compared to Graham's number<f<sub>ω+1</sub>(64).

Comment: If you've marked this non-competing due to the language being newer than the question, [you don't have to do that anymore](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12930/76162)

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3, <s>174</s> <s>171</s> <s>168</s> <s>148</s> <s>125</s> <s>117</s> <s>116</s> <s>112</s> 101 bytes

3^^^...^3 with Graham's number arrows i.e. G(65) (boring, I know)

```python
a=lambda b,c:3if b<2else(a(a(b-1,c),c-1)if c else 3*b)
G=lambda k:a(3,G(k-1))if k else 4
print(G(65))
```

Pretty human-readable. a implements arrow notation, G is Graham's sequence.

### Improvements

- Replaced G(64)+1 with G(65), saving two bytes
- Replaced `if c==1:return a**b` with `if c==0:return a*b`, saving one byte
- Renamed ar function to a and renamed variable a to k, saving three bytes
- Turned G function from a proper function into a lambda, saving twenty bytes, believe it or not!
- Turned a function from a proper function also into a lambda, saving twenty-three bytes!
- Removed k from a function since we will only be using it with base 3, saving eight bytes.
- Removed an unnecessary space
- Removed some more unnecessary spaces, saving four bytes
- Shortened definitions of a and G, saving eleven bytes

Comment: You can save 7 bytes with `a=lambda b,c:3if b<2else(a(a(b-1,c),c-1)if c else 3*b)`, and another 4 bytes with `G=lambda k:a(3,G(k-1))if k else 4`.

Comment: Thank you so much! I will definitely do that.

Answer (score 1):

## [7](https://esolangs.org/wiki/7), 17.5 bytes

```
00000000: 505e 91e7 a3a4 63c8 edda 476d ea0b d556  P^....c...Gm...V
00000010: d7e                                      ..
```

Written in octal:

```
24057221717216443074435566443555724057252555375
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYqxDQAACMJeUhT5/zI0LrRJkY0OCkilkNNdoRty5nHtD8R5ifYC)

`721gge644355` is a function that, given a function `f_a()`, returns `f_(a+1)()`:

```
|f_a() 721gge644355
|c7{f_a()}ggerr          # Where {f_a()} represents the pacified version of f_a()

# Applying the result to some number n, to see that it worked:
|n c7{f_a()}ggerr
|n|f_a() nr
   f_a() n               # Make n copies of f_a(), resulting in f^n_a()
 n        r              # Apply it to n, resulting in f^n_a(n) = f_(a+1)(n)
```

From that, a function `f_w()` can be written:

```
|n cc71721644307443556ggerrr
|n|n|721gge644355 nrr
   n                              # A function (\x -> x^n), representing f_0()
     721gge644355 nr              # Add 1 n times to the index of f_0(), resulting in f_n()
 n                  r             # Apply the result to n, resulting in f_n(n) = f_w(n)
```

The full program computes `f^256_w(2)`, which is greater than Graham's number:

```
|| 24057221717216443074435566443555724057252555375
||cg6r|cc71721644307443556ggerrr|cg6r|crcrrre|r
||cg6r|cc71721644307443556ggerrr|cg6r|crcrrre|r r
||cg6r|cc71721644307443556ggerrr|cg6r|crcrrre r
||cg6r|cc71721644307443556ggerrr|cg6r crcrrre
                                 cg6r              # The number 2
                                      cr           # Raise 2, to itself returning 4
                                        cr         # Raise 4, to itself returning 256
       cc71721644307443556ggerrr          r        # Make 256 copies of f_w(), resulting in f^256_w()
  cg6r                                     r       # Apply this function to 2, resulting in f^256_w(2)
                                            e      # Print the result in the same encoding as the source code
```

We can see the code working by reducing it to just `f_w(2)`. This outputs `2^2^18`, which is represented by `2^18` copies of `2405` in the same encoding as the source.

```
2405722171721644307443556644355575375
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcXBEQAgCAPBliQQrv/KouNnl0RzjFQUqp3pw8Pe/Rk3Ti4)

Answer (score 0):

**Python: 85**

```
f=lambda a,a:a*a
exec'f=lambda a,b,f=f:reduce(f,[a]*b,1)'*99
exec'f('*64+'3'+',3)'*64
```

Which maybe could be shortened to *74 + `length(X)`*:

```
f=lambda a,a:a*a
exec'f=lambda a,b,f=f:reduce(f,[a]*b,1)'*int('9'*X)
f(3,3)
```

Where `X` is an appropriate big number such that the resultant hyperoperation on `3, 3` is bigger than Grahams number(if this number is less than `99999999999` then some byte is saved).

---

Note: I assume the python code is executed on the interactive interpreter hence the result is printed to stdout, otherwise add `9` bytes to each solution for the call to `print`.

Comment: Your 74ish byte solution does not produce an output nearly large enough.

Answer (score 0):

## Javascript, 83 bytes

Another Ackermann function solution.

```
(function a(m,n,x){return x?a(a(m,n,x-1),n,0):(m?a(m-1,n?a(m,n-1):1):n+1)})(9,9,99)
```

Answer (score 0):

## Ruby, 60 bytes

```
f=->n{n.times{eval("n.times{"*n+"n+=1"+"}"*n)};n};f.call(64)
```

This is \$f_{\omega+1}(64)\$, exactly, which is slightly bigger than Graham's number :) I copied this from Simply Beautiful Art on their Bignum Bakeoff post.