# Largest Number Printable

Tags: number, code-challenge, busy-beaver

Your goal is to write a program that prints a number. The bigger the number, the more points you'll get. But be careful! Code length is both limited and heavily weighted in the scoring function. Your printed number will be divided by the **cube of the number of bytes you used for your solution**.

So, let's say you printed `10000000` and your code is `100` bytes long. Your final score will be \$\frac {10000000} {100^3} = 10\$.

There are other rules to follow, in order to make this challenge a bit harder.

- You cannot use digits in your code (0123456789);
- You **can** use mathematical/physical/etc. constants, **but** only if they are less than 10. (e.g. You can use \$\pi \approx 3.14\$ but you can't use the **Avogadro constant** \$= 6\times 10^{23}\$)
- Recursion is allowed **but** the generated number needs to be finite (so **infinite** is not accepted as a solution. Your program needs to terminate correctly, assuming unbounded time and memory, and generate the requested output);
- You cannot use the operations `*` (multiply), `/` (divide), `^` (power) nor any other way to indicate them (e.g. `2 div 2` is not allowed);
- Your program **can output more than one number, if you need it to do that**. Only the highest one will count for scoring;
- However, you **can** concatenate strings: this means that any sequence of adjacent digits will be considered as a single number;
- Your code will be run as-is. This means that the end-user cannot edit any line of code, nor he can input a number or anything else;
- Maximum code length is 100 bytes.

---

#### Leaderboard

1. [*Steven H.*, Pyth](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/149781) \$\approx f_{\varphi(1,0,0)+7}(256^{26})\$
2. [*Simply Beautiful Art*, Ruby](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/149763) \$\approx f_{\varphi(1,0,0)}(3)\$
3. [*Peter Taylor*, GolfScript](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/18028/largest-number-printable/18954#18954) \$\approx f_{\varepsilon_0+\omega+1}(17)\$
4. [*r.e.s.*, GolfScript](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/18920/58880) \$\approx f_{\epsilon_0}^9(126)\approx f_{\epsilon_0+1}(9)\$ <sup>[1]</sup>
5. [*Simply Beautiful Art*, Ruby](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/120228/58880) \$\approx f_{\omega^{\omega2}+1}(126^22^{126})\$
6. [*eaglgenes101*, Julia](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/146791) \$\approx f_{\omega^3}(127)\$
7. [*col6y*, Python 3,](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/18359/2183) \$\approx 127\to126\to\dots\to2\to1\approx f_{\omega^2}(127)\$ <sup>[1][3]</sup>
8. [*Toeofdoom*, Haskell,](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/18169/2183) \$\approx a_{20}(1)\approx f_{\omega+1}(18)\$ <sup>[1]</sup>
9. [*Fraxtil*, dc,](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/18153/2183) \$\approx 15\uparrow^{166665}15\$ <sup>[3]</sup>
10. [*Magenta*, Python,](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/79694/58880) \$\approx\mathrm{ack}(126,126)\approx10\uparrow^{124}129\$
11. [*Kendall Frey*, ECMAScript 6,](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/18075/2183) \$\approx1000\uparrow^43\$ <sup>[1]</sup>
12. [*Ilmari Karonen*, GolfScript,](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/18064/2183) \$\approx10\uparrow^310^{377}\$ <sup>[1]</sup>
13. [*Aiden4*, Rust,](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/214246/58880) \$\approx10\uparrow^3127\$
14. [*BlackCap*, Haskell,](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/121675/58880) \$\approx10\uparrow\uparrow65503\$
15. [*recursive*, Python,](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/18092/2183) \$\approx2\uparrow\uparrow11\approx10\uparrow\uparrow8.63297\$ <sup>[1][3]</sup>
16. [*n.m.*, Haskell,](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/18134/2183) \$\approx2\uparrow\uparrow7\approx10\uparrow\uparrow4.63297\$ <sup>[1]</sup>
17. [*David Yaw*, C,](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/18060/2183) \$\approx10^{10^{4\times10^{22}}}\approx10\uparrow\uparrow4.11821\$ <sup>[2]</sup>
18. [*primo*, Perl,](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/18058/2183) \$\approx10^{(12750684161!)^{5\times2^{27}}}\approx10\uparrow\uparrow4.11369\$
19. [*Art*, C,](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/18196/2183) \$\approx10^{10^{2\times10^6}}\approx10\uparrow\uparrow3.80587\$
20. [*Robert Sørlie*, x86,](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/18253/2183) \$\approx10^{2^{2^{19}+32}}\approx10\uparrow\uparrow3.71585\$
21. [*Tobia*, APL,](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/18033/2183) \$\approx10^{10^{353}}\approx10\uparrow\uparrow3.40616\$
22. [*Darren Stone*, C,](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/18029/2183) \$\approx10^{10^{97.61735}}\approx10\uparrow\uparrow3.29875\$
23. [*ecksemmess*, C,](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/18049/2183) \$\approx10^{2^{320}}\approx10\uparrow\uparrow3.29749\$
24. [*Adam Speight*, vb.net,](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/18182/2183) \$\approx10^{5000\times2^{256}}\approx10\uparrow\uparrow3.28039\$
25. [*Joshua*, bash,](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/18085/2183) \$\approx10^{10^{15}}\approx10\uparrow\uparrow3.07282\$

<sub>**Footnotes**</sub>

1. <sup>If every electron in the universe were a qubit, and every superposition thereof could be gainfully used to store information (which, as long as you don't actually need to *know* what's being stored is theoretically possible), this program requires more memory than could possibly exist, and therefore cannot be run - now, or at any conceiveable point in the future. If the author intended to print a value larger than ≈10↑↑3.26 all at once, this condition applies.</sup>
2. <sup>This program requires more memory than currently exists, but not so much that it couldn't theoretically be stored on a meager number of qubits, and therefore a computer may one day exist which could run this program.</sup>
3. <sup>All interpreters currently available issue a runtime error, or the program otherwise fails to execute as the author intended.</sup>
4. <sup>Running this program will cause irreparable damage to your system.</sup>

---

**Edit** [@primo](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/4098/primo): I've updated a portion of the scoreboard using a hopefully easier to compare notation, with decimals to denote the logarithmic distance to the next higher power. For example \$10↑↑2.5 = 10^{10^{\sqrt {10}}}\$. I've also changed some scores if I believed to user's analysis to be faulty, feel free to dispute any of these.

Explanation of this notation:

If \$0 \le b \lt 1\$, then \$a \uparrow\uparrow b = a^b\$.

If \$b \ge 1\$, then \$a \uparrow\uparrow b = a^{a \uparrow\uparrow (b-1)}\$.

If \$b \lt 0\$, then \$a \uparrow\uparrow b = \log_a(a \uparrow\uparrow (b+1))\$

An [implementation](https://tio.run/##7Rtpb9s29Lt@BSNgqOXaruX0NOwARbsABbb2w9JiWNEYckw7AmTJk@QcC/Lbs8dDEkmRknwE8NbkQ2FRj@@@@KiubtPLKDx@sG3b@hCFqeeHCfLQii4jf7kK8BLDcurDYzRHKU5j9jDDF/7SC5KONcNzP8QzNL1F6SVG8ygIoms/XMCveLkOvGRoIfjz0Pk5mqIx@YGmHST/@XPUR6MxAIyQW4Zv0afWFHWR6zgdCj9FJ2MVNogWEy8Hfs6AKewI9S3ra@ItMGPnA7DprRKM8BWOQVzCcAT8xyCEF1JJnp1GUYrjZz2LqGceR0s0mczX6TrGkwlRThSnyAvDiOknsfjS0ksvGXh6uyJ4@fqXFQHzgg46u13hb17cQV9DWLGsycQLAsA5Rt/ts0zFH5mG7R@W9QcO5vCSb2vZ5NnuoGm0Dmfj8g7Hsk5/@/L@bPL7p89DNA8iL4Xdr3D3ePAye/P@z@KN23vz7s3rd8fu8cu3rwfH7qs3@Plx/@0DWJZotHXlBWs8ZMx@V6l1GJofwI6XAFQm5Xe2DOg/RyF2UPcEqVuZJcA8oELkJ@B7qRdeYEavg1oGUmDRMHUctpv8xZ4PhiTa@TWOo7g1ty@idTBjaEMw4SrGKTUpxYw84uMx9gLEKS0A8I7@PorvQX0EKQ6I34BIwBnFRMQAc89UbgkMMLsra5SUwhmKYkqWc0hAFAYZGAROX6X5jbzJiM6iJYQ2wuSxQlyNDQxiYYiCkDqHaiS202HuIOCm6uOqpLIejRn3vQl1HB1uhgq9oCHVIysKUo7gEvuLyxSdoIGIJlkHxLv1DDL@xgIHjrI1R9vN0ozAHQPhjIjcC05DJC5ekD/6RhJbxVtiNpecGkJWrk4Gy7qAlJsYYo2pmoURW2AySkuJvwiHxOIWe54kQZQmND3d5fzaFJUty2efZY5MagX8zutFz@4IWxlR3Wau8urthEHdZrJu3HrPpCE5bTLxQz@dTFoJ5NEhItm0gxomuXaW5/Lk2ae5TTb27jnt0fJaHjubpLHm3OjSmDZ9yTkWMpirIydlsTxNLtcJUMJoATTSrGS7RjLEzCw@wF5S1Glznmoih2Z9IcrQmKGRGWZUqA/mIU6eNEDcy8dy/pLV0oCvLejfGBNike6INeW1LNPIaZL8QY@HoBeChOiFC9wq71SYzHgQtdluo5sqJd3oFcR8fiyVPs3ufq9vVlNfQKnaMydxolIooXGl12VUpQ1dt/Sei4O69EelRNLL60s/wDmnrokw3/1cZVYkndcaoUI6VhUuxquQWL1pIuVVmhvJDyE3crcGgtAfYwrs0H@5lxXh6kiByvdlSiRaVCymQJTLdgYhsTybKaWAngPqSkFFR6uvABTrphWAsf05Sj9lZzE8yyHYeUUT0JxUlTZFdyyFkKkZqcNL45IC1aEmu@VtkmtBORiQ4x3HxZuURjyyPok6FRwA2RNF49QxDr7L943ob7ZLpnoRYXISK4hAc8rgyGlTzR8MeqyLSs4@3dsge3BwirCt7Crv4Fy6sgKAVSre5lxK1mrKJN0kxFlsDDTKY308aWKpNnKaujBoSnFJVUB9KAry4b8fJ43smEK2ThKK/YuIFgOcdEZyeVKCdheNUqHK5YQuDzdNZmIfkJdSkXVLLYdFkCu9kbjkFArT9EIypMxXRkboTqETkqs/552BtgU5RTUt8P/P8WSjnog@Z8w7Z7HSNwl1haIZNUJz6gVJNR5tQyiFSjaQMAWDDmvZc6tlq8jAai3dW0Qu0idXO1BX25en6Xhq7Gr78zSwcjnzw@Kw3NKnYs/niEiCp8zY0M9G@3H7xu46OoTMeLLHzBg8ZcZDdbVDyIwn@/O05Tp4mleQm7FGg4YSrX7dGOAxBhHt5oOIsj/weyz5nNAic7p8YtFB8lk2e5nRE95Whbh8uDN6tnD51SgSunyDOAwwevEhDAPaOw8DQvwzDAOO5GEAxKQUPEd7rK8hXpT7QbOqzLe/NYPm7O6XCtSWJvWy9wu8raJkM96KoZqE5Xobn@mgZTRbB9GQ3bDXfm6xS7InFmbUxI8iNikB6tUWp0uwl25fmLOOdBU58@NueX4q3LO7fOLZIFPxHSVosx@5NdHC7mUYo9peJZfwFygx@vGrwEFbubmUGDe95GPfF1DErPo8vs/yXFVJTNnYbVaZH6fe89a0X3MJbV944bMU4ZsVOH6Y@l6K0bWfXiLIT0D2Cid2VTtBzLx96@Ju1roAKTKeFWmNDKRaWag4pLfoqvcLGjEGJdxlF96p2kiVo3xvqb0/ac5p6epwXtx@5t/OyV0Vb@HNJ5ZNPK@2Z9LWraL92@ReSzmIuENzVZe6S1Yp5b6IUZTxmxXHB9/ZEaxhwPb6GzbIDfrvWo2JvamxEvNauFXBrWlYqZMWtbVcV/NyMZaOAsUFTNWpeMtmyPBBnPYjgi3PBs178t2b8hiv4nKjlqTxxpdJc/uu@HahB92pt4SG/z4P@buC83vHrjlfbkThTnDr@8bUKpP/3O627vKj5FEs4zBoGfgTqBLr2JAeSnde5AbaJEndzZpBPMGgYLr92NPub2UkICXPnrdSvajH83Ok6sXdxh5aPLLu1tODPKIK9Qicp9UtVZzNw94o6iPOGliuJgLI31xswX8ar/HMv/oJh341bTJtzv/CcfTRvwIZorDo0YlYoDN/hsn/S/kHYOwtDhO1BWfj0Vz3PzCaq/S3QxjPvdiqE3jQfvvqDl471iomxecGusAbcpYesE9St1l9@Bc) of this notation is provided in Python that let's you test reasonably sized values.

Comment: Has someone explicitly said "base 10" yet?

Comment: Does the large number count if it's say `12e10` (12*10^10) as `12*10^10`?

Comment: I think a better constraint instead of forbidding *, /, and ^, would've been to _allow_ only _linear_ operations, _e.g._ +, -, ++, --, +=, -=, etc. Otherwise, coders can take advantage of Knuth's up-arrow/Ackermann library functions if made available in their language of choice, which seems like cheating.

Comment: [This question is the subject of a meta question](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/11001/194)

Comment: I'm still waiting to see someone earn footnote [4].

Comment: @hichris123 I think that counts as exponentiation.

Comment: Say, if my program prints `500b`, is this invalid? That is, may we ignore all non-numeric things a program prints?  And if so, would something like `50r7` count as `507`?

Comment: I cannot find a language nor a constant that does, but what about a constant `x` that is `x<-10`?

Comment: Requesting change of accept votes someday.

Comment: Can we output in base-256 (if our language is allowed to output in Unicode numbers normally)

Comment: Can I get some clarification on the `no constants` rule? I don't really understand it; May I not use stuff like `Integer.MAX_VALUE` or may I not use constants in general? I'm a bit confused

Comment: Is a zero-byte program valid?

Comment: I was about to ask whether `11` counts as a constant bigger than 10 but then I realized that no digits are allowed.

Comment: Is it ok to only error because of the recursion limit?

Comment: @keshlam using a very high base is now a loophole.

Comment: Is $f_n$ the fast-growing function or…?

Comment: @Someone The fast-growing hierarchy, I believe.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

### GolfScript; score at least f<sub>ε_0+ω+1</sub>(17) / 1000

Following [r.e.s.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/3440/r-e-s)'s suggestion to use the [Lifetime of a worm](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/18912/194) answer for this question, I present two programs which vastly improve on his derivation of Howard's solution.

They share a common prefix, modulo the function name:

```
,:z){.[]+{\):i\.z={.z+.({<}+??\((\+.@<i*\+}{(;}if.}do;}:g~g
```

computes `g(g(1)) = g(5)` where `g(x) = worm_lifetime(x, [x])` grows roughly as f<sub>ε<sub>0</sub></sub> (which r.e.s. notes is "the function in the [fast-growing hierarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast-growing_hierarchy#Functions_in_fast-growing_hierarchies) that grows at roughly the same rate as the Goodstein function").

The slightly easier (!) to analyse is

```
,:z){.[]+{\):i\.z={.z+.({<}+??\((\+.@<i*\+}{(;}if.}do;}:g~g.{.{.{.{.{.{.{.{.{.{g}*}*}*}*}*}*}*}*}*}*
```

`.{foo}*` maps `x` to `foo^x x`.

```
,:z){[]+z\{\):i\.z={.z+.({<}+??\((\+.@<i*\+}{(;}if.}do;}:g~g.{g}*
```

thus gives `g^(g(5)) ( g(5) )`; the further 8 levels of iteration are similar to arrow chaining. To express in simple terms: if `h_0 = g` and `h_{i+1} (x) = h_i^x (x)` then we calculate `h_10 (g(5))`.

I think this second program almost certainly scores far better. This time the label assigned to function `g` is a newline (sic).

```
,:z){.[]+{\):i\.z={.z+.({<}+??\((\+.@<i*\+}{(;}if.}do;}:
~
{.['.{
}*'n/]*zip n*~}:^~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

This time I make better use of `^` as a different function.

```
.['.{
}*'n/]*zip n*~
```

takes `x` on the stack, and leaves `x` followed by a string containing `x` copies of `.{` followed by `g` followed by `x` copies of `}*`; it then evaluates the string. Since I had a better place to burn spare characters, we start with `j_0 = g`; if `j_{i+1} (x) = j_i^x (x)` then the first evaluation of `^` computes `j_{g(5)} (g(5))` (which I'm pretty sure already beats the previous program). I then execute `^` 16 more times; so if `k_0 = g(5)` and `k_{i+1} = j_{k_i} (k_i)` then it calculates `k_17`. I'm grateful (again) to r.e.s. for estimating that `k_i` >> f<sub>ε_0+ω+1</sub>(i).

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the number your program computes (call it n) can be written n = f^9 (g(3)), where f(x) = g^(4x) (x), and g(x) is the lifetime of worm [x]. If we treat g as being approximately the same as f_eps_0 in the fast-growing hierarchy, then my "back-of-envelope" calculations show that f_(eps_0 + 2)(9) < n < f_(eps_0 + 2)(10). Of course it's the current winner -- by far.

Comment: @r.e.s., I think that's underestimating it quite a lot. `.{foo}*` maps `x` to `foo^x (x)`. If we take `h_0 (x) = g^4 (x)` and `h_{i+1} (x) = h_i^x (x)` then the value calculated is `h_9 (g(3))`. Your `f(x) = g^(4x) (x) = h_0^x (x) = h_1 (x)`.

Comment: (This pertains to your original program -- I just saw that you've made some edits.) Ohhh... I misunderstood how the `*` works. It is safe to say that h_0(x) = g^4(x) >> f_eps_0(x); consequently, the relation h_{i+1} (x) = h_i^x (x) effectively defines an "accelerated" fast-growing hierarchy such that h_i(x) >> f_(eps_0 + i)(x). I.e., the computed number h_9 (g(3)) is certainly much greater than f_(eps_0 + 9)(g(3)). As for g(3), I think I can show that it's greater than g_4, the fourth number in the g_i sequence used to define Graham's number (which is g_64).

Comment: @r.e.s., so `j_i ~ f_{eps_0 + i}`; does that make `k_i ~ f_{eps_0 + i omega + i^2}`?

Comment: Given what you wrote, I get `k_i ~ f_{ε_0 + ω}^i (k_0)`. Here's the reasoning:
k_{i+1} = j_{k_i} (k_i) = j_ω (k_i) ~ f_{ε_0 + ω} (k_i) 
~ f_{ε_0 + ω}^2 (k_{i-1}) 
... ~ f_{ε_0 + ω}^{i+1} (k_0),  
so k_i ~ f_{ε_0 + ω}^i (k_0). 
A very conservative lower bound on k_i, entirely in terms of the fast-growing hierarchy, is then 
`k_i >> f_{ε_0 + ω}^i (i) =  f_{ε_0 + ω + 1} (i)`.

Comment: About the scoring (dividing by 100^3) ... The funny thing is that this computed number (call it C) is **so big** that operations like C/G or C^(1/G), etc., where G is Graham's number, result in numbers that are *still approximately equal to C*.

Comment: Is there a mistake in your second program (the string copying part)? According to the description, if `3` were on the stack, it should produce `3.{.{.{g}*}*}*` -- but it seems to produce `3.{g}*.{g}*.{g}*` instead.

Comment: @r.e.s., are you sure? I just tested `3{.['.{
}*'n/]*zip'g'*]p}:^~` (i.e. replacing the `~` which evaluates the string with `]p` to print the contents of the stack) and got `[3 ".{.{.{g}*}*}*"]`

Comment: @r.e.s. PS Thanks for your comment on your question about starting the age at `x` rather than `0`: hadn't occurred to me!

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce what you just did, but I'm sure that's just my ignorance of the syntax. However, the description seems to say `3.['.{g}*'n/]*zip n*` (replacing the newline with g) should produce `3.{.{.{g}*}*}*` -- but it produces `3.{g}*.{g}*.{g}*`.

Comment: @r.e.s., you also need to replace that `g` with a newline so that the `n/` splits the string into prefix and suffix.

Comment: Ok, got it. BTW, I think your core program will also give a winning answer to the [Shortest terminating program whose output size exceeds Graham's number](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/6430/shortest-terminating-program-whose-output-size-exceeds-grahams-number). (The current winner is 63 bytes of Haskell code.) E.g., at 51 bytes, *something like* (since I hardly know the syntax) `9.[]+{\):i\.0={.0+.({<}+??\((\+.@<i*\+}{(;}if.}do;~` computes g(9) >> Graham's number. You may know how to golf it even more.

Comment: In the same spirit, you and @r.e.s. might be interested in [Golf a number bigger than TREE(3)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/139355).

Answer (score 118):

### Windows 2000 - Windows 8 (3907172 / 23³ = 321)

**NOTE: *DON'T F'ING RUN THIS!***

Save the following to a batch file and run it as Administrator.

```
CD|Format D:/FS:FAT/V/Q
```

Output when run on a 4TB drive with the first printed number in bold.

> Insert new disk for drive D:
>   and press ENTER when ready... The type of the file system is NTFS.
>   The new file system is FAT.
>   QuickFormatting **3907172M**
>   The volume is too big for FAT16/12.

Comment: Sheer unadulterated genius!

Comment: I think you're supposed to cube the solution length in which I get about 321 as score `Your printed number will be divided for the number of bytes you used for your solution^3.`

Comment: That rule changed after I read it.  Fixed!

Comment: 77 upvotes, and yet... I note the score is 321...

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt, it's not the score, but the journey. :-D

Comment: Apparently so, one that gave many a good laugh.  Now if only we could get this up to the leaderboard...someone needs to earn the "irreparable damage" tag ;)

Comment: I think such thing is generally banned, you shouldn't require an exact amount of free space

Comment: Why is `CD|` needed? It shouldn't matter what directory you're in, right?

Comment: @CanadianLuke It’s to pass the “Press ENTER when ready...” prompt. The number doesn’t appear before that.

Answer (score 97):

### GolfScript, score: *way* too much

OK, how big a number can we print in a few chars of GolfScript?

Let's start with the following code ([thanks, Ben!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/18050)), which prints `126`:

```
'~'(
```

Next, let's repeat it 126 times, giving us a number equal to about 1.26126 × 10<sup>377</sup>:

```
'~'(.`*
```

(That's string repetition, not multiplication, so it should be OK under the rules.)

Now, let's repeat *that* 378-digit number a little over 10<sup>377</sup> times:

```
'~'(.`*.~*
```

You'll never actually see this program finish, since it tries to compute a number with about 10<sup>380</sup> ≈ 2<sup>1140</sup> digits.  No computer ever built could store a number that big, nor could such a computer ever be built using known physics; the [number of atoms in the observable universe](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observable_universe#Matter_content_.E2.80.94_number_of_atoms) is estimated to be about 10<sup>80</sup>, so even if we could somehow use *all the matter in the universe* to store this huge number, we'd still somehow have to cram about 10<sup>380</sup> / 10<sup>80</sup> = 10<sup>300</sup> digits into *each atom!*

But let's assume that we have God's own GolfScript interpreter, capable of running such a calculation, and that we're still not satisfied.  OK, *let's do that again!*

```
'~'(.`*.~*.~*
```

The output of this program, if it could complete, would have about 10<sup>10<sup>383</sup></sup> digits, and so would equal approximately 10<sup>10<sup>10<sup>383</sup></sup></sup>.

But wait!  That program is getting kind of repetitive... why don't we turn it into a loop?

```
'~'(.`*.{.~*}*
```

Here, the loop body gets run about 10<sup>377</sup> times, giving us a theoretical output consisting of about 10<sup>10⋰<sup>10<sup>377</sup></sup></sup> digits or so, where the tower of [iterated powers](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration) of 10 is about 10<sup>377</sup> steps long.  (Actually, that's a gross underestimate, since I'm neglecting the fact that the number being repeated also gets longer every time, but relatively speaking that's a minor issue.)

But we're not done yet.  Let's add another loop!

```
'~'(.`*.{.{.~*}*}*
```

To even properly write down an *approximation* of such numbers requires esoteric mathematical notation.  For example, in [Knuth up-arrow notation](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%27s_up-arrow_notation), the number (theoretically) output by the program above should be about 10 ↑<sup>3</sup> 10<sup>377</sup>, give or take a few (or 10<sup>377</sup>) powers of ten, assuming I did the math right.

Numbers like this get way beyond just "incredibly huge", and into the realm of "inconceivable".  As in, not only is it impossible to count up to or to write down such numbers (we crossed beyond that point already at the third example above), but they literally have no conceivable use or existence outside abstract mathematics.  We can prove, from the [axioms of mathematics](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foundations_of_mathematics), that such numbers exist, just like we can prove from the GolfScript specification that program above *would* compute them, if the limits of reality and available storage space did not intervene), but there's literally *nothing* in the physical universe that we could use them to count or measure in any sense.

Still, mathematicians do sometimes make use of [even larger numbers](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graham%27s_number).  (Theoretically) computing numbers *that* large takes a little bit more work — instead of just nesting more loops one by one, we need to use recursion to telescope the *depth* of the nested loops.  Still, in principle, it should be possible to write a short GolfScript program (well under 100 bytes, I would expect) to (theoretically) compute any number expressible in, say, [Conway chained arrow notation](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway_chained_arrow_notation); the details are left as an exercise. ;-)

Comment: ***`"...No computer ever built could store a number that big...`*** Correct me if I'm wrong, but I don't think that applies here. Isn't it just repeatedly "storing" and printing 3 digits at a time (?) so no need to store the final result.

Comment: @KevinFegan: That is true — the number is incredibly repetitive, so it would be easy to compress. But then we're no longer really storing the number itself, but rather some abstract formula from which the number may, theoretically, be computed; indeed, one of the most compact such formulas is probably the GolfScript program above that generates it. Also, once we go a step further to the next program, even "printing" the digits one at a time before discarding them becomes impractical — there's simply no known way to carry out that many steps of classical computation in the universe.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen's GolfScript just gave the Googol a wedgie!

Comment: How about actually pushing this to the limit, see how big precisely you can really make it in GolfScript within 100 chars? As it stands, your result is less than Graham's number (which [my Haskell solution](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/18145/2183) "approximates"), but as you say GolfScript can probably go even further.

Comment: @leftaroundabout: I managed to write a Conway arrow notation evaluator in 80 chars of GolfScript, although it doesn't pass all the requirements of this challenge (it uses numeric constants and arithmetic operators). It could probably be improved, but I thought I might pose that as a new challenge.

Comment: @KevinFegan the issue is that a finite computer can't keep track of how far along in the process of printing digits it is. Note that a computer with $n$ bits of memory can only enter at most $2^n$ different states before necessarily running into an infinite loop! Of course, I don't think this a particularly interesting objection, and we should only be concerning ourselves with infinite machines.

Comment: This finally got beat by the dc operation below (right now far below). An absurd number of towers he has.

Comment: @KevinFegan Once the number has been generated it doesn't just magically float on your screen. That my friend is memory and anything a computer wants to output at any one time must be able to fit into it.

Comment: Just to make it clear, in the third step, when you say "Now, let's repeat that 378-digit number a little over 10^377 times" you're already in the land of fantasy, because a common integer variable cannot store 10^377. So there is a limit to how many digits your program would print if left running for an unlimited time, and the limit is *way* below the score you computed.

Comment: @Tobia: GolfScript integers are bignums, so in principle they have no size limit. That said, the reference interpreter, which is written in Ruby, [does limit string length to less than 2^31 or 2^63 bytes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3638622/do-ruby-objects-have-a-size-limit) (depending on platform), so you're right, that step is going to fail on the reference interpreter. That said, the string length limit is _not_ part of the GolfScript spec (which, admittedly, is pretty vague), so it's arguably a bug in the interpreter rather than a fundamental limitation.

Comment: @GeorgeReith - I don't know **GolfScript** programming syntax (at all), but my understandg is that the GolfScript code given will display the number as it's generating the number. If I'm wrong about that (perhaps someone can comment), and the code is trying to store the number in memory, then you are correct... it couldn't possibly store the entire number, at some point it would run out of memory. But, if it's displaying the number (in small groups of digits) as it's generating the (output) number, these displayed digits are constantly being discarded (scrolling away) and do not accumulate.

Comment: @KevinFegan: It's storing the number. The usual way to output something in GolfScript is to just leave it on the stack when the program exits, and that's what my code does. GolfScript _does_ have an explicit `print` command, but I'm not using it in any of the examples above.

Comment: So, how large would the output of [this](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/X71OXUMvQUuvmgRYp1VLAvz/HwA) be?

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing Somewhere around `10↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑(10^377)` I think. That's 23 `↑`'s.

Answer (score 49):

## JavaScript 44 chars

This may seem a little cheaty:

```javascript
alert((Math.PI+''+Math.E).replace(/\./g,""))
```

**Score = 31415926535897932718281828459045 / 44^3 ≈ 3.688007904758867e+26 ≈ 10↑↑2.1536134004**

Comment: No rules bent at all: ;)
* Can't use 0123456789 [check]

* Use any language in which digits are valid characters; [check]

* You can use mathematic/physic/etc. constants <10. [check, used 2]

* Recursion is allowed but the generated number needs to be finite; [check, no recursion]

Can't use *, /, ^; [check]

Your program can output more than one number; [check]

You can concatenate strings; [check]

Your code will be run as-is; [check]

Max code length: 100 bytes; [check]

Needs to terminate w/i 5 sec [check]

Comment: Shave off 2 characters by passing `"."` to replace instead of `/\./g`

Comment: @gengkev Sadly, only using .replace(".","") only removes the first . character; I *have* to use the global replace to replace ALL . characters from the string...

Comment: You can do `m=Math,p=m.PI,e=m.E,s="",alert((p*p*p+s+e*e*e).replace(/\./g,s))` instead, your score is then 3100627668029981620085536923187664 / 63^3 = 1.240017943838551e+28

Comment: @A.M.K I could, but that would violate the rule *"You cannot use the operations *, /, ^ nor any other way to indicate them (e.g. 2 div 2 is not allowed)"*

Comment: @WallyWest Why even use `Math.E` when `Math.PI` is larger? `p=Math.PI;(''+p+p+p+p).replace(/\./g,"")`

Comment: @Cory For one, I'm not going to repeat a constant, otherwise everyone would be using it... Second, I really don't have a second argument...

Answer (score 29):

## C, score = 10<sup>10<sup>97.61735</sup></sup>/98<sup>3</sup> ≈ 10↑↑2.29874984

```c
unsigned long a,b,c,d,e;main(){while(++a)while(++b)while(++c)while(++d)while(++e)printf("%lu",a);}
```

I appreciate the help in scoring. Any insights or corrections are appreciated. Here is my method:

**n** = the concatenation of **every number from 1 to 2<sup>64</sup>-1, repeated (2<sup>64</sup>-1)<sup>4</sup> times**.  First, here's how I'm estimating (low) the cumulative number of digits from 1 to 2<sup>64</sup>-1 (the "subsequence"): The final number in the subsequence sequence is 2<sup>64</sup>-1 = `18446744073709551615` with 20 digits.  Thus, more than 90% of the numbers in the subsequence (those starting with `1`..`9`) have 19 digits.  Let's assume the remaining 10% average 10 digits. It will be much more than that, but this is a low estimate for easy math and no cheating. That subsequence gets repeated (2<sup>64</sup>-1)<sup>4</sup> times, so the *length* of **n** will be *at least* (0.9×(2<sup>64</sup>-1)×19 + 0.1×(2<sup>64</sup>-1)×10) × (2<sup>64</sup>-1)<sup>4</sup> = 3.86613 × 10<sup>97</sup> digits. In the comments below, @primo confirms the length of **n** to be 4.1433x10<sup>97</sup>. So **n** itself will be 10 to that power, or 10<sup>10<sup>97.61735</sup></sup>.

**l** = 98 chars of code

**score** = **n/l<sup>3</sup>** = **10<sup>10<sup>97.61735</sup></sup>/98<sup>3</sup>**

Requirement: Must run on a 64-bit computer where `sizeof(long) == 8`. Mac and Linux will do it.

Comment: I'm sorry, I changed some specs after comment suggestions, you may want to review your solution.

Comment: I checked.  Thanks.  I think it's fine.

Comment: Oh, I see you added a new time limit.  That would seem to favour golfers who have hardware that can scroll many digits to `stdout` very quickly. Was that your intent?

Comment: The time limit has since been removed.

Comment: In C, `'z'` is the constant value `122`. Right?

Comment: @primo, yes, `'z'` is simply a literal character constant with `char` or `int` value of 122.  `man ascii` was useful on the console!

Comment: Global variables have an initial value of 0 in C. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1597405/what-happens-to-a-declared-uninitialized-variable-in-c-does-it-have-a-value

Comment: Would it be better to use `uint64` instead of long, because long is signed, hence you've "only" 2^63-1 instead of 2^64-1 values for n?

Comment: @klingt.net, it should not matter.  The `while` loop will see 2^64-1 iterations, regardless of sign.  With a signed value, `n` gets progressively smaller (more negative), then wraps to maximum positive, then continues to decrease until it hits `0` and exits.

Comment: i think `printf("%d",n)` will make the number much larger. Also, 64-bit computer doesn't mean 64-bit longs, for example Windows use the LLP64 model so long is still 32 bits

Comment: *it should not matter* It does. Signed integer overflow is undefined behavior in C, so it's impossible to predict what will happen when your code is executed. It might violate the finitude requirement.

Comment: @Lưu Vĩnh Phúc:
I don't want to be a nit-picker, but he uses `long n` so `print("%l",n)` will be correct. :)

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc, agreed, that's why I noted the requirement `sizeof(long) == 8`. It ran fine on 64-bit OS X and Linux. Too bad about Windows. I like your idea about the `printf` but I think that will only work with an `unsigned long`, otherwise many `-` chars will find their way into output.

Comment: @klingt.net, good catch but it actually needs to be `%ld` since `l` is a modifier not a type specifier.

Comment: `%lu` for `unsigned long`, and @klingt.net, `uint64_t` or another type would require a #include and add extra bytes.  And digits in the source code.

Comment: If you `sprintf` instead of `printf` (or somehow otherwise store the digits), then `atoi` back into `n` and repeat the while loop, imagine... :-) (That's essentially what [my answer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/18062/14255) does, 5 times.)

Comment: Thanks, I just improved the answer a bunch. I think it's similar to what you suggest.  It does 5 nested loops, each of 2^64-1 iterations, and the inner loop is concatenating every integer from 1 to 2^64-1. Cheers.

Comment: To (more) accurately calculate the length of your final number: make a copy of your program and use a method [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3068397/606539) and sum length of each (a) instead of printing (a), So something like: `unsigned long a,b,c,d,e,f;main(){while(++a)while(++b)while(++c)while(++d)while(++e)f=f+lengthof(a);printf("%lu",f);}` Well, it sounds like `unsigned long f` won't be big enough to hold the total accumulated length so a little more work is necessary to finish this.

Comment: Also, the scoring uses the `value` of the output-number for (n), not the `number of digits` in the output-number. If using `number of digits` to calculate score, then Score is (approximately): `(number_of_digits)-log10(script_length^3)`.

Comment: Good point.  I will re-compute the score.

Comment: I think the analysis may be a bit off. The concatenation of `0..2^64-1` is exactly 357823770363079921190 digits long. Repeated `(2^64-1)^4` times is 4.1433x10^97. Take 10 to that power is `10^10^97.61735` ≈ 10↑↑3.29875. I think you're claiming a power of ten you don't have (note where `3.866×10^97` became `3.866^10^97`.

Comment: Hi @primo.  Thanks for putting in the time to check this.  Appreciate it.  I see what you're saying.  My final exponent is wrong.  It should be `2.0` instead of `97`.  `10^10^10^2.00` = `10^10^97.6`.  I will reflect that in my score now.

Answer (score 21):

## Python 3 - 99 chars - (most likely) significantly larger than Graham's number

I've come up with a more quickly increasing function based on an extension of the Ackermann function.

```
A=lambda a,b,*c:A(~-a,A(a,~-b,*c)if b else a,*c)if a else(A(b,*c)if c else-~b);A(*range(ord('~')))
```

http://fora.xkcd.com/viewtopic.php?f=17&t=31598 inspired me, but you don't need to look there to understand my number.

Here is the modified version of the ackermann function that I'll be using in my analysis:

```
A(b)=b+1
A(0,b,...)=A(b,...)
A(a,0,...)=A(a-1,1,...)
A(a,b,...)=A(a-1,A(a,b-1,...),...)
```

My function `A` in the code above is technically not the same, but it is actually stronger, with the following statement to replace the third line of the above definition:

```
A(a,0,...)=A(a-1,a,...)
```

(a has to be at least 1, so it has to be stronger)

But for my purposes I will assume that it is the same as the simpler one, because the analysis is already partially done for Ackermann's function, and therefore for this function when it has two arguments.

My function is guaranteed to eventually stop recursing because it always either: removes an argument, decrements the first argument, or keeps the same first argument and decrements the second argument.

## Analysis of size

Graham's number, AFAIK, can be represented as `G(64)` using:

```
G(n) = g^n(4)
g(n) = 3 ↑^(n) 3
```

Where a `↑^(n)` b is knuth's up-arrow notation.

As well:

```
A(a,b) = 2 ↑^(a-2) (b+3) - 3
A(a,0) ≈ 2 ↑^(a-2) 3
g(n) ≈ A(n+2,0) // although it will be somewhat smaller due to using 2 instead of 3. Using a number larger than 0 should resolve this.
g(n) ≈ A(n+2,100) // this should be good enough for my purposes.

g(g(n)) ≈ A(A(n+2,100),100)

A(1,a+1,100) ≈ A(0,A(1,a,100),100) = A(A(1,a,100),100)

g^k(n) ≈ A(A(A(A(...(A(n+2,100)+2)...,100)+2,100)+2,100)+2,100) // where there are k instances of A(_,100)
A(1,a,100) ≈ A(A(A(A(...(A(100+2),100)...,100),100),100),100)

g^k(100) ≈ A(1,k,100)
g^k(4) < A(1,k,100) // in general
g^64(4) < A(1,64,100)
```

The number expressed in the program above is `A(0,1,2,3,4,...,123,124,125)`.

Since `g^64(4)` is Graham's number, and assuming my math is correct then it is less than `A(1,64,100)`, my number is *significantly* larger than Graham's number.

Please point out any mistakes in my math - although if there aren't any, this should be the largest number computed so far to answer this question.

Comment: Looks great; apparently your "modified Ackermann" is exactly a [Conway-chain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway_chained_arrow_notation) evaluator.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Not quite, but I think that it has about the same recursive strength. Also - zeroes aren't valid in chains, so you'll want to drop the zero from your Conway chain in the scores list.

Comment: Why did you do `range(ord('~'))`? Couldn't you have done `range(125)` for fewer bytes, which would allow you to squeeze in a higher number like `range(A(9,9,9))`?

Comment: @Challenger5: rule 1 says "You cannot use digits in your code (0123456789)"

Comment: @CelSkeggs: Oh, I forgot about that.

Comment: where does it print?

Comment: Perhaps I know not how to do Python, but it doesn't appear to work: https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/39E2JzE3KSVRIVEnSUcr2cpRo043UcdRI1GnThckoJmZppCkkJpTnApUAeEmgrkajhow@WSwgG5dkqa1o4aR5v//AA

Answer (score 20):

### Perl - score ≈ 10↑↑4.1

```
$_=$^Fx($]<<-$]),/(?<R>(((((((((((((((((((.(?&R))*)*)*)*)*)*)*)*)*)*)*)*)*)*)*)*)*)*)*)*(??{print})/
```

Once again abusing perl's regex engine to grind through an unimaginable amount of combinations, this time using a recursive descent.

In the inner most of the expression, we have a bare `.` to prevent infinite recursion, and thus limiting the levels of recursion to the length of the string.

What we'll end up with is this:

```
/((((((((((((((((((((.[ ])*)*)*)*)*)*)*)*)*)*)*)*)*)*)*)*)*)*)*)*/
   ___________________/ \_____________________________________
  /                                                           \
  (((((((((((((((((((.[ ])*)*)*)*)*)*)*)*)*)*)*)*)*)*)*)*)*)*)*
   ___________________/ \_____________________________________
  /                                                           \
  (((((((((((((((((((.[ ])*)*)*)*)*)*)*)*)*)*)*)*)*)*)*)*)*)*)*
   ___________________/ \_____________________________________
  /                    .                                      \
                       .
                       .
```

... repeated *671088640* times, for a total of *12750684161* nestings - which quite thoroughly puts my previous attempt of *23* nestings to shame. Remarkably, perl doesn't even choke on this (once again, memory usage holds steady at about 1.3GB), although it will take quite a while before the first print statement is even issued.

From my previous analysis below, it can be concluded that the number of digits output will be on the order of *(!12750684161)<sup>671088640</sup>*, where *!k* is the [Left Factorial](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LeftFactorial.html) of *k* (see [A003422](http://oeis.org/A003422)). We can approximate this as *(k-1)!*, which is strictly smaller, but on the same order of magnitude.

And if we [ask wolframalpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=10%5E12750684160%21%5E671088640):

[image]

...which barely changes my score at all. I thought for sure that'd be at least **10↑↑5**. I guess the difference between **10↑↑4** and **10↑↑4.1** is a lot bigger than you'd think.

---

### Perl - score ≈ 10↑↑4

```
$_=$^Fx($]<<-$]),/((((((((((((((((((((((.*.*)*)*)*)*)*)*)*)*)*)*)*)*)*)*)*)*)*)*)*)*)*)*(??{print})/
```

Abusing the perl regex engine to do some combinatorics for us. The embedded codeblock
`(??{print})` will insert its result directly into the regex. Since `$_` is composed entirely of `2`s (and the result of `print` is always `1`), this can never match, and sends perl spinning through all possible combinations, of which there's quite a few.

**Constants used**

- `$^F` - the maximum system file handle, typically `2`.
- `$]` - the perl version number, similar to `5.016002`.

`$_` is then a string containing the digit `2` repeated *671088640* times. Memory usage is constant at about 1.3GB, output begins immediately.

**Analysis**

Let's define *P<sub>k</sub>(n)* to be the number of times the print statement is executed, where *k* is the number of nestings, and *n* is the length of the string plus one (just because I don't feel like writing *n+1* everywhere).

`(.*.*)*`
*P<sub>2</sub>(n)* = [*2, 8, 28, 96, 328, 1120, 3824, 13056, ...*]

[image]

`((.*.*)*)*`
*P<sub>3</sub>(n)* = [*3, 18, 123, 900, 6693, 49926, 372615, 2781192, ...*]

[image]

`(((.*.*)*)*)*`
*P<sub>4</sub>(n)* = [*4, 56, 1044, 20272, 394940, 7696008, 149970676, 2922453344, ...*]

[image]

`((((.*.*)*)*)*)*`
*P<sub>5</sub>(n)* = [*5, 250, 16695, 1126580, 76039585, 5132387790, 346417023515, 23381856413800, ...*]

[image]

`(((((.*.*)*)*)*)*)*`
*P<sub>6</sub>(n)* = [*6, 1452, 445698, 137050584, 42142941390, 12958920156996, ...*]

[image]

`((((((.*.*)*)*)*)*)*)*`
*P<sub>7</sub>(n)* = [*7, 10094, 17634981, 30817120348, 53852913389555, ...*]

[image]

etc. In general, the formula can be generalized as the following:

[image]

where

[image]

That is, the [Left Factorial](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LeftFactorial.html) of *k*, i.e. the sum of all factorials less than *k* (see [A003422](http://oeis.org/A003422)).

[image]
[image]

I've been unable to determine closed forms for *D<sub>k</sub>* and *E<sub>k</sub>*, but this doesn't matter too much, if we observe that

[image] and [image]

With *23* nestings, this gives us an approximate score of:

[image]

This should be nearly exact, actually.

But to put this into a notation that's a bit easier to visualize, we can approximate the base of the inner exponent:

[image]

and then the exponent itself:

[image]

and then [ask wolframalpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2%2F9*10%5E%28671088640*%2822*%2810%5E14342538182%29%2B671088641%29-6%29):

[image]

which you may as well just call **10↑↑4** and be done with it.

Comment: So, this will only be a valid solution so long as the version number remains lower than 10?

Comment: @MrLister Yes. Fortunately, no major version higher than 6 exists, and even that's not considered to be fully 'ready', despite having been originally announced in 2000.

Comment: @primo You do realize that you will have to revise this answer once Perl goes into a version number > 10, right? ;)

Comment: @Eliseod'Annunzio If I'm still alive when that day arrives - if ever - I promise to come back and fix it.

Comment: My brain hurts after reading the errr... wotsit symbologies... :D

Comment: A running solution that surpasses 10↑↑4. That's impressive. Bravo!

Answer (score 16):

## Javascript, 10↑↑↑↑210

100 chars:

```js
z=~~Math.E+'';o={get f(){for(i=z;i--;)z+=i}};o.f;for(i=z;i--;)for(j=z;j--;)for(k=z;k--;)o.f;alert(z)
```

Based on the observation that maximally iterating `f` is the optimal way to go, I replaced the 13 calls to `f` with 3 levels of nested loops calling `f`, `z` times each (while `f` keeps increasing `z`).

I estimated the score analytically on a piece of paper—I'll type it up if anyone is interested in seeing it.

---

## Improved Score: 10↑↑13

Javascript, in exactly 100 characters, again:

```js
z=~~Math.E+'';__defineGetter__('f',function(){for(i=z;i--;)z+=i});f;f;f;f;f;f;f;f;f;f;f;f;f;alert(z)
```

This improves my original answer in three ways—

1. Defining `z` on the global scope saves us from having to type `o.z` each time.
2. It's possible to define a getter on the global scope (window) and type `f` instead of `o.f`.
3. Having more iterations of `f` is worth more than starting with a larger number, so instead of `(Math.E+'').replace('.','')` (=2718281828459045, 27 chars), it's better to use `~~Math.E+''` (=2, 11 chars), and use the salvaged characters to call `f` many more times.

Since, as analyzed further below, each iteration produces, from a number in the order of magnitude *M*, a larger number in the order of magnitude 10<sup>M</sup>, this code produces after each iteration

1. 210 ∼ O(10<sup>2</sup>)
2. O(10<sup>10<sup>2</sup></sup>) ∼ O(10↑↑2)
3. O(10<sup>10↑↑2</sup>) = O(10↑↑3)
4. O(10<sup>10↑↑3</sup>) = O(10↑↑4)
5. O(10<sup>10↑↑4</sup>) = O(10↑↑5)
6. O(10<sup>10↑↑5</sup>) = O(10↑↑6)
7. O(10<sup>10↑↑6</sup>) = O(10↑↑7)
8. O(10<sup>10↑↑7</sup>) = O(10↑↑8)
9. O(10<sup>10↑↑8</sup>) = O(10↑↑9)
10. O(10<sup>10↑↑9</sup>) = O(10↑↑10)
11. O(10<sup>10↑↑10</sup>) = O(10↑↑11)
12. O(10<sup>10↑↑11</sup>) = O(10↑↑12)
13. O(10<sup>10↑↑12</sup>) = O(10↑↑13)

---

## Score: ∼10<sup>10<sup>10<sup>10<sup>10<sup>16</sup></sup></sup></sup></sup> ≈ 10↑↑6.080669764

Javascript, in exactly 100 characters:

```js
o={'z':(Math.E+'').replace('.',''),get f(){i=o.z;while(i--){o.z+=i}}};o.f;o.f;o.f;o.f;o.f;alert(o.z)
```

Each `o.f` invokes the while loop, for a total of 5 loops. After only the first iteration, the score is already over 10<sup>42381398144233621</sup>. By the second iteration, Mathematica was unable to compute even the *number of digits* in the result.

Here's a walkthrough of the code:

### Init

Start with 2718281828459045 by removing the decimal point from `Math.E`.

### Iteration 1

Concatenate the decreasing sequence of numbers,

- 2718281828459045
- 2718281828459044
- 2718281828459043
- ...
- 3
- 2
- 1
- 0

to form a new (gigantic) number,

- 271828182845904527182818284590442718281828459043...9876543210.

How many digits are in this number? Well, it's the concatenation of

- 1718281828459046 16-digit numbers
- 900000000000000 15-digit numbers
- 90000000000000 14-digit numbers,
- 9000000000000 13-digit numbers
- ...
- 900 3-digit numbers
- 90 2-digit numbers
- 10 1-digit numbers

In Mathematica,

```js
In[1]:= 1718281828459046*16+Sum[9*10^i*(i+1),{i,-1,14}]+1
Out[1]= 42381398144233626
```

In other words, it's 2.72⋅10<sup>42381398144233625</sup>.

Making my score, after only the first iteration, **2.72⋅10<sup>42381398144233619</sup>**.

### Iteration 2

But that's only the beginning. Now, repeat the steps, *starting with the gigantic number*! That is, concatenate the decreasing sequence of numbers,

- 271828182845904527182818284590442718281828459043...9876543210
- 271828182845904527182818284590442718281828459043...9876543209
- 271828182845904527182818284590442718281828459043...9876543208
- ...
- 3
- 2
- 1
- 0

So, what's my new score, Mathematica?

```js
In[2]:= 1.718281828459046*10^42381398144233624*42381398144233625 + Sum[9*10^i*(i + 1), {i, -1, 42381398144233623}] + 1

During evaluation of In[2]:= General::ovfl: Overflow occurred in computation. >>

During evaluation of In[2]:= General::ovfl: Overflow occurred in computation. >>

Out[2]= Overflow[]
```

### Iteration 3

Repeat.

### Iteration 4

Repeat.

### Iteration 5

Repeat.

---

### Analytical Score

In the first iteration, we calculated the number of digits in the concatenation of the decreasing sequence starting at 2718281828459045, by counting the number of digits in

- 1718281828459046 16-digit numbers
- 900000000000000 15-digit numbers
- 90000000000000 14-digit numbers,
- 9000000000000 13-digit numbers
- ...
- 900 3-digit numbers
- 90 2-digit numbers
- 10 1-digit numbers

This sum can be represented by the formula,

[image]

where *Z* denotes the starting number (*e.g.* 2718281828459045) and *O<sub>Z</sub>* denotes its order of magnitude (*e.g.* 15, since *Z* ∼ 10<sup>15</sup>). Using [equivalences for finite sums](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_series#Low-order_polylogarithms), the above can be expressed explicitly as

[image]

which, if we take 9 ≈ 10, reduces even further to

[image]

and, finally, expanding terms and ordering them by decreasing order of magnitude, we get

[image]

Now, since we're only interested in the order of magnitude of the result, let's substitute *Z* with "a number in the order of magnitude of *O<sub>Z</sub>*," *i.e.* 10<sup>*O<sub>Z</sub>*</sup>—

[image]

Finally, the 2nd and 3rd terms cancel out, and the last two terms can be dropped (their size is trivial), leaving us with

[image]

from which the first term wins out.

**Restated, `f` takes a number in the order of magnitude of *M* and produces a number approximately in the order of magnitude of *M*(10<sup>*M*</sup>).**

The first iteration can easily be checked by hand. 2718281828459045 is a number in the order of magnitude of 15—therefore `f` should produce a number in the order of magnitude of 15(10<sup>15</sup>) ∼ 10<sup>16</sup>. Indeed, the number produced is, from before, 2.72⋅10<sup>42381398144233625</sup>—that is, 10<sup>42381398144233625</sup> ∼ 10<sup>10<sup>16</sup></sup>.

Noting that *M* is not a significant factor in *M*(10<sup>*M*</sup>), the order of magnitude of the result of each iteration, then, follows a simple pattern of tetration:

1. 10<sup>16</sup>
2. 10<sup>10<sup>16</sup></sup>
3. 10<sup>10<sup>10<sup>16</sup></sup></sup>
4. 10<sup>10<sup>10<sup>10<sup>16</sup></sup></sup></sup>
5. 10<sup>10<sup>10<sup>10<sup>10<sup>16</sup></sup></sup></sup></sup>

---

#### LaTeX sources

```js
(Z-10^{\mathcal{O}_Z}+1)(\mathcal{O}_Z+1)+\sum_{k=0}^{\mathcal{O}_Z-1}{(9\cdot10^k(k+1))}+1

(Z-10^{\mathcal{O}_Z}+1)(\mathcal{O}_Z+1)+\frac{10-\mathcal{O}_Z10^{\mathcal{O}_Z}+(\mathcal{O}_Z-1)10^{\mathcal{O}_Z+1}}{9}+10^{\mathcal{O}_Z}

(Z-10^{\mathcal{O}_Z}+1)(\mathcal{O}_Z+1)+\mathcal{O}_Z10^{\mathcal{O}_Z}-\mathcal{O}_Z10^{\mathcal{O}_Z-1}+1

Z\mathcal{O}_Z+Z-10^{\mathcal{O}_Z}-\mathcal{O}_Z10^{\mathcal{O}_Z-1}+\mathcal{O}_Z+2

\mathcal{O}_Z10^{\mathcal{O}_Z}+10^{\mathcal{O}_Z}-10^{\mathcal{O}_Z}-\mathcal{O}_Z10^{\mathcal{O}_Z-1}+\mathcal{O}_Z+2

\mathcal{O}_Z10^{\mathcal{O}_Z}-\mathcal{O}_Z10^{\mathcal{O}_Z-1}
```

Comment: My reckoning about your score is based on the observation that `f` does something like take the number `z` to its own power. So that's something like `↑↑↑`. Of course the score is _not_ `2↑↑↑2`, sorry... more like, `2↑↑↑5+1` it seems. Would you agree, should I put that in the leaderboard?

Comment: @leftaroundabout - Thanks for looking into it again. I don't feel comfortable enough with up-arrow notation to say whether your suggestion sounds right or not, but I calculated the order of magnitude of my score (see edit) if you'd like to update the leaderboard with that.

Comment: Excellent! I'm not at all firm with up-arrows either. So actually you have "only" a tower of power; I'm afraid that places you two spots lower in the ranking. Kudos for properly analysing the result; my estimations have probably yet more flaws in them, but I felt someone should at least try to get some order in the answers.

Comment: @leftaroundabout - No worries, fair is fair. I made some improvements though (see edit) to bring my score to 10↑↑13. And yes, I was hoping someone would at least attempt to verify and order the lot of these answers, so I appreciate your work, and I'm sure others do too.

Comment: @leftaroundabout - One last update, please :-) The new score is `10↑↑↑↑210`. Well, actually, it's `10↑↑(10↑↑↑↑210)`—but it appears that for such large numbers, larger "forests" on the inside "override" smaller forests on the outside. Take, for example, `10↑(10↑↑200)`. This is essentially `10^(10^...^10)` 200 times, which is simply `10↑↑201`—not much different from `10↑↑200`. Thus, though I don't mean to knock his answer, I believe Kendall Frey's score is essentially in the order of magnitude of `3 ↑↑↑↑ 3`, the `10^` being trivial.

Comment: Shouldn't the code be able to be executed?

Comment: @ŁukaszL. - The code should execute—given ample (seriously _ample_) time and memory—the loops are finite—and Javascript doesn't have a maximum string length. If I'm wrong though, please let me know!

Comment: Well, it can't use more memory as you have, and the browser will probably crash much earlier. The question is, if you have really executed that code on any computer. After removing 5 second limitation, the task is going madness anyway...

Comment: @ŁukaszL. - But I think that's true of all the top-ranked answers... You can't really print any of these numbers to screen (while keeping hidden digits in memory).

Comment: Your score is wrong. Whenever you start a loop with `i=o.z;while(i--)...` you are not executing the loop `o.z` times, because a loop is based on an integer variable and `o.z` contains a string larger than the largest representable integer, depending on your interpreter's word size. Supposing for your benefit that your interpreter won't barf on converting such a string to int, `i` will start each time with its largest representable integer value, let's say 2^63, and not with the current value of `o.z`.

Comment: @Tobia - Ah, you're correct. I thought JS was keeping the string a string during assignment and simply juggled types to decrement when asked to—but even so, I should have realized, it would have to convert the string to a number in order to decrement (unless it does so typographically). I guess this disqualifies my answer—I'll remove myself from the list.

Comment: I don't know enough about JavaScript to judge this... for small numbers, decrementing this way would work, wouldn't it? We've long thrown out "real-word restrictions" anyway, so I think your submission might still be ok.

Comment: @acheong87 Don't remove yourself, you just have to recompute your score, capping the loop variables to 2^63 or such. PS: leave your analytical score posted here, it's very instructive!

Answer (score 15):

## APL, 10↑↑3.4

Here's my revised attempt:

```
{⍞←⎕D}⍣n⍣n⍣n⍣n⍣n⍣n⍣n⍣n⍣n⍣n⍣n⍣n⍣n⍣n⍣n⍣n⍣n⍣n⍣n⍣n⍣n⍣n⍣n⍣n⍣n⍣n⍣n⍣n⍣n⍣n⍣n⍣n⍣n⍣n⍣n⍣n⍣n⍣n⍣n⍣n⍣n⍣n⍣n⍣n⊢n←⍎⎕D
```

100 char/byte* program, running on current hardware (uses a negligible amount of memory and regular 32-bit int variables) although it will take a very long time to complete.

You can actually run it on an APL interpreter and it will start printing digits. If allowed to complete, it will have printed a number with 10 × 123456789<sup>44</sup> digits.

Therefore the score is 10<sup>10 × 123456789<sup>44</sup></sup> / 100<sup>3</sup> ≈ 10<sup>10<sup>353</sup></sup> ≈ 10↑↑3.406161

**Explanation**

- `⎕D` is a predefined constant string equal to `'0123456789'`
- `n←⍎⎕D` defines **n** to be the number represented by that string: 123456789 (which is < 2<sup>31</sup> and therefore can be used as a loop control variable)
- `{⍞←⎕D}` will print the 10 digits to standard output, without a newline
- `{⍞←⎕D}⍣n` will do it **n** times (`⍣` is the "power operator": it's neither *, /, nor ^, because it's not a math operation, it's a kind of loop)
- `{⍞←n}⍣n⍣n` will repeat the previous operation **n** times, therefore printing the 10 digits **n**<sup>2</sup> times
- `{⍞←n}⍣n⍣n⍣n` will do it **n**<sup>3</sup> times
- I could fit 44 `⍣n` in there, so it prints **n**<sup>44</sup> times the string `'0123456789'`.

⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯
<sup>*: APL can be written in its own (legacy) single-byte charset that maps APL symbols to the upper 128 byte values. Therefore, for the purpose of scoring, a program of N chars *that only uses ASCII characters and APL symbols* can be considered to be N bytes long.</sup>

Comment: Your printed number will be **divided for the number of bytes you used for your solution^3.**, you're dividing by 100 right now.

Comment: @ToastyMallows - looks like **`100 cubed`** (100^3) to me.

Comment: I know but it's bytes, not characters.

Comment: @ToastyMallows Read the end notes on the answer.

Comment: Change `{⍞←⎕D}` to `⍞←` which saves you three bytes that you can use to add one more `⍣n` and make `⊢n←⍎⎕D` into `⌽⍕n←⍎⎕D` for an 80-fold increase. If you allow running with `⎕PP←17` then use `×⍨` instead of `⌽⍕` which almost doubles the number of digits printed.

Answer (score 13):

## Haskell, score: (2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>65536</sup></sup></sup>-3)/1000000 ≈ 2↑↑7 ≈ 10↑↑4.6329710779

```haskell
o=round$sin pi
i=succ o
q=i+i+i+i
m!n|m==o=n+i
 |n==o=(m-i)!i
 |True=(m-i)!(m!(n-i))
main=print$q!q
```

This program is exactly 100 bytes of pure Haskell code. It will print the fourth Ackermann number, eventually consuming all available energy, matter and time of the Universe and beyond in the process (thus *slightly* exceeding the soft limit of 5 seconds).

Comment: `o=length[]` gets you an extra `!q` at the end and saves you a byte on top of that.

Answer (score 12):

## Ruby, \$f_{\varphi(1,0,0)}(5)\$ (non-deterministic)

More precisely: \$f_{\varphi(\varphi(\varphi(\varphi(\varphi(16381,\omega^2),\omega^2),\omega^2),\omega^2),\omega^2)}(1048577)\$.

```
*h=[[[[n=$$]]]]
f=->a{b,c,d=a;b ?a==b ?~-a:a==a-[$.]?[f[b],d,[b,f[c],d]]:d:n+=n}
h=f[h]while h!=p(n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcZNCgIxDIbh/ZxihC78ST1A5XMOErJIppYIUkQQEdGr1zyLl/fxtPcYeweHjpQkTA35rB@jlSr0ZPOiQPSXtcRp5nSUhRubUCU2arzGiZRa@gH9Ozkau7z8ervMvsF923dj/AE)

<sub>*`$. == 0` is a global variable.</sub>

<sub>*Relies on `$$`, the [process ID](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2177022/7741591). I suppose the rules never said random behavior isn't allowed. I'm assuming the maximum PID to be 32768.</sub>

## Ruby, \$f_{\varphi(1,0,0)}(3)\$ (deterministic)

More precisely: \$f_{\varphi(\varphi(\varphi(\omega+\omega,\omega^2),\omega^2),\omega)}(16)\$.

```
*h=[[[n=-~$.]]]
f=->a{b,c,d=a;b ?a==b ?~-a:a==a-[$.]?[f[b],d,[b,f[c],d]]:d:n+=n}
h=f[h]while h!=p(n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcpBCsIwEEbhfU9RoYuqEw8Q@e1BhlnMNIYplCCCFCn26jGbx7d47499a704mLkgHMNNRLqM8NDdaKYEvVs/KdB6BI1NGrhtE2c2oURslHluEokplivKr3Nkdtl8WZ@9n/Aay7nWPw)

<sub>*Previously removed the prints, not sure why but they're back since removing them doesn't really let us improve much. Probably just +1 (or +2 at best) inside the \$f_{\varphi(1,0,0)}(n+\dots)\$.</sub>

#### Ungolfed:

<sub>*See math explanation below.</sub>

```
n = 32768         # n = "count"
h = [[[[[n]]]]]   # h0 = 32768
                  # h1 = "count op(h0) count"
                  # ...
                  # h = h5 = "count op(h4) count"

f = -> a {        # f[a] = reduce(a)
  b, c, d = a                     # truncate to first 3 elements
  if a == [] || a.nil?            # if a == "count"
    n += n                          # increment counter
    return n                        # and replace with counter
  elsif a.is_a? Integer           # if a == int
    return a - 1                    # decrement int
  elsif a != a-[0]                # if a == "++d"
    return d                        # return just d
  else                            # if a == "d op c" where b = op  (*note out of order)
    return [f[b], d, [b, f[c], d]]  # (d op reduce(c)) reduce(op) d
  end
}

while h != n  # reduce until h == n
  h = f[h]
  p(n)
end
```

<sub>*We write `"x op(y) z" = [y, z, x]` so that reducing it reduces `y` before `z` and so that `[t] = "count op(t) count"`.</sub>

#### Math explanation:

The code may be approximately understood as a combination of symbolic manipulation and recursive reduction of algebraic expressions.

Let `++a` denote `a+1`, the successor of `a`.

We then define `reduce("x")` as `x-1`, meaning:

- `reduce("++a") = a`.

We then try to work out `reduce("x")` for algebraic expressions:

- `reduce("a+b") = a + reduce("b") = reduce("++(a + reduce("b"))")`
- `reduce("a*b") = reduce("a*reduce("b") + a")`
- `reduce("a^b") = reduce("a^reduce("b") * a")`

Generalizing this, we get:

- `reduce("a op b") = reduce("(a op reduce(b)) reduce("op") a")`

where:

- `reduce("*") = "+"`
- `reduce("^") = "*"`

and more generally:

- `reduce("op(n)") = op(reduce("n"))`
- `x op(0) y = ++x`
- `x op(1) y = x+y`
- `x op(2) y = x*y`
- `x op(3) y = x^y`

for simplicity we also define:

- `x op 0 = ++x`

We then introduce **symbols**. The only symbol is `"count"`, where `reduce("count")` is the amount of times `reduce` has been called.

We then apply `x = reduce(x)` until `x = 0` and print the `count`.

#### Example:

```
"count^3"

1:  reduce("count^3")
2:  reduce("count^reduce(3) reduce("^") count")
      Note: we evaluate right-to-left
3:  reduce("count^reduce(3) * count")
4:  reduce("count^2 * count")
5:  reduce("count^2 * reduce("count") reduce("*") count^2")
6:  reduce("count^2 * reduce("count") + count^2")
7:  reduce("count^2 * 6 + count^2")
8:  reduce("count^2 * 6 + reduce("count^2") reduce("+") ...")
9:  reduce("++(count^2 * 6 + reduce("count^2"))")
10: reduce("++(count^2 * 6 + count^reduce(2) reduce("^") count)")
11: reduce("++(count^2 * 6 + count^reduce(2) * count)")
12: reduce("++(count^2 * 5 + count^1 * count)")

"count^2 * 6 + count^1 * count"
(continue applying reduce(...) until you get 0)
```

Note that the growth relies on the 'lazy' evaluation of `"count"`. Despite how simple it is to normally cube an integer, fully reducing `"count^3"` actually results in `count > 10^10^10^10^10^10^5`.

**Let `g(x, n)` be** the final `count` after fully reducing `x` with an initial `count = n`.

So from the previous example, `g("count^3", 0) > 10^10^10^10^10^10^5`.

**For some intuition on the very fast growth**, notice that `g("a+b", n) > g(a, g(b, n))`. This is because we have to reduce `b` before `a`. This means **addition allows recursion**, and we also know that **multiplication expands into lots of addition**.

Then note that

- `g("count", n) ~ 2 * n`
- `g("count + count", n) ~ 2 * 2 * n = 4 * n`
- `g("count + count + ...", n) ~ 2 * 2 * ... * n = 2^k * n`
- `g("count * k", n) ~ 2^k * n`
- `g("count * count", n) ~ 2^n`
- `g("count ^ 2", n) ~ 2^n`
- `g("count ^ 2 + count ^ 2", n) ~ 2^2^n`
- `g("count ^ 2 * k", n) ~ 2^2^...^n`
- `g("count ^ 2 * count", n) ~ n↑↑n`
- `g("count ^ 3", n) ~ n↑↑n`
- `g("count ^ 4", n) ~ n↑↑↑n`

#### Some other values of interest:

For the last 3, we define:

- `h(0, y) = y`
- `reduce(h(x, y)) = "count op(h(reduce(x), y)) count"`

```
g("count^k", n) ~ n↑↑...k arrows...↑↑n
g("count^count", n) ~ n↑↑...n arrows...↑↑n ~ Ack(n,n)
g("count^(++count)", 20) ~ Toeofdoom's a_20(1)
g("count^(++count)", 64) ~ Graham's number
g("count^(count+1)", 15) ~ eaglgenes101's number  (note count+1 turns into ++(++count))
g("count op(4) 2", 127) ~ col6y's number
g("(count op(4) 3) * count", 3) ~ my older/other number
g("count op(6) 1", 9) ~ r.e.s.'s number
g("(count op(6) 1) * (++count op(4) 1)", 17) ~ Peter Taylor's number
g(h(3, "count + count"), 126) ~ this deterministic number
g(h(5, 16381), 1048577) ~ this non-deterministic number
g("h("count", "count") * count^7", 256^26) ~ Steve H.'s number
```

Answer (score 10):

### Python, 2↑↑11 / 830584 ≈ 10↑↑8.632971 (Knuth up arrow notation)

```python
print True<<(True<<(True<<(True<<(True<<(True<<(True<<(True<<(True<<(True<<True<<True)))))))))
```

Probably no computer has enough memory to successfully run this, but that's not really the program's fault.  With the minimum system requirements satisfied, it does work.

Yes, this is doing bit shifting on boolean values.  `True` gets coerced to `1` in this context.  Python has arbitrary length integers.

Comment: Your code doesn't run. Only `print True<<(True<<(True<<(True<<True<<True)))` does, and that outputs a 19k string.

Comment: What are that minimum system requirements?

Comment: Could you not make it shorter by defining `t=True` and then using `t` after?

Comment: Better yet, just make a loop that does these nestings for you.

Comment: This fails for me: `$python -c 'print True<<(True<<(True<<(True<<(True<<(True<<(True<<(True<<(True<<(True<<True<<True)))))))))'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
OverflowError: long int too large to convert to int`

Comment: I guess it might be a different python version.

Answer (score 8):

### GolfScript \$ \approx 3.673 \times 10^{374} = 10 \uparrow\uparrow 2.70760 \$

```
'~'(.`*
```

I think the `*` is allowed since it indicates string repetition, not multiplication.

Explanation: `'~'(` will leave 126 (the ASCII value of "~") on the stack.  Then copy the number, convert it to a string, and do string repetition 126 times.  This gives `126126126126...` which is approximately `1.26 e+377`.  The solution is 7 characters, so divide by `7^3`, for a score of approximately `3.673e+374`

Comment: I converted your score into tetration notation described at the end of the question post. It was done using `print(0.126126... * TetrationDecimal(10) ** (126 * 1000))`.

Answer (score 8):

### dc, 100 characters

```
[lnA A-=ilbA A-=jlaSalbB A--SbLndB A--SnSnlhxlhx]sh[LaLnLb1+sbq]si[LbLnLasbq]sjFsaFsbFFFFFFsnlhxclbp
```

Given enough time and memory, this will calculate a number around 15 ↑¹⁶⁶⁶⁶⁶⁵ 15. I had originally implemented the [hyperoperation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperoperation#Definition) function, but it required too many characters for this challenge, so I removed the `n = 2, b = 0` and `n >= 3, b = 0` conditions, turning the `n = 1, b = 0` condition into `n >= 1, b = 0`.

The only arithmetic operators used here are addition and subtraction.

EDIT: as promised in comments, here is a breakdown of what this code does:

```
[            # start "hyperoperation" macro
lnA A-=i     # if n == 0 call macro i
lbA A-=j     # if b == 0 call macro j
laSa         # push a onto a's stack
lbB A--Sb    # push b-1 onto b's stack
LndB A--SnSn # replace the top value on n with n-1, then push n onto n's stack
lhxlhx       # call macro h twice
]sh          # store this macro in h

[            # start "increment" macro (called when n=0, the operation beneath addition)
LaLnLb       # pop a, b, and n
F+sb         # replace the top value on b with b+15
q            # return
]si          # store this macro in i

[            # start "base case" macro (called when n>0 and b=0)
LbLnLa       # pop b, n, and a
sb           # replace the top value on b with a
q            # return
]sj          # store this macro in j

Fsa          # store F (15) in a
Fsb          # store F (15) in b
FFFFFFsn     # store FFFFFF "base 10" (150000+15000+1500+150+15=1666665) in n
lhx          # load and call macro h
lbp          # load and print b
```

As noted, this deviates from the hyperoperation function in that the base cases for multiplication and higher are replaced with the base case for addition. This code behaves as though `a*0 = a^0 = a↑0 = a↑↑0 ... = a`, instead of the mathematically correct `a*0 = 0` and `a^0 = a↑0 = a↑↑0 ... = 1`. As a result, it computes values that are a bit higher than they should be, but that's not a big deal since we are aiming for bigger numbers. :)

EDIT: I just noticed that a digit slipped into the code by accident, in the macro that performs increments for `n=0`. I've removed it by replacing it with 'F' (15), which has the side effect of scaling each increment operation by 15. I'm not sure how much this affects the final result, but it's probably a lot bigger now.

Comment: I have no idea what this code does... can only assume it's correct. Perhaps you could explain a little?

Comment: I'll explain the code piece by piece when I have time later tonight.

Comment: Well, I spaced on that explanation, but I've added it now. Hope it clears things up.

Comment: dc-1.06.95-2 terminates immediately, having printed nothing.

Comment: I wouldn't expect it to work on any existing machine, given the magnitude of the value it will try to generate. I have the same version of dc and it segfaults after a few seconds. I'm assuming "theoretically correct" answers are permitted here, since there's no criteria for resource consumption.

Answer (score 8):

### GolfScript,   ≈ f<sub>ε<sub>0</sub></sub>(f<sub>ε<sub>0</sub></sub>(f<sub>ε<sub>0</sub></sub>(f<sub>ε<sub>0</sub></sub>(f<sub>ε<sub>0</sub></sub>(f<sub>ε<sub>0</sub></sub>(f<sub>ε<sub>0</sub></sub>(f<sub>ε<sub>0</sub></sub>(f<sub>ε<sub>0</sub></sub>(126)))))))))

This is shamelessly adapted from [another answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/18914/3440) by @Howard, and incorporates suggestions by @Peter Taylor.

```
[[[[[[[[[,:o;'~'(]{o:?~%{(.{[(]{:^o='oo',$o+o=<}{\(@\+}/}{,:^}if;^?):?)*\+.}do;?}:f~]f]f]f]f]f]f]f]f
```

My understanding of GolfScript is limited, but I believe the `*` and `^` operators above are *not* the arithmetic operators forbidden by the OP.

(I will happily delete this if @Howard wants to submit his own version, which would doubtless be superior to this one anyway.)

This program computes a number that's approximately f<sub>ε<sub>0</sub></sub>(f<sub>ε<sub>0</sub></sub>(f<sub>ε<sub>0</sub></sub>(f<sub>ε<sub>0</sub></sub>(f<sub>ε<sub>0</sub></sub>(f<sub>ε<sub>0</sub></sub>(f<sub>ε<sub>0</sub></sub>(f<sub>ε<sub>0</sub></sub>(f<sub>ε<sub>0</sub></sub>(126))))))))) -- a nine-fold iteration of f<sub>ε<sub>0</sub></sub> -- where f<sub>ε<sub>0</sub></sub> is the function in the [fast-growing hierarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast-growing_hierarchy#Functions_in_fast-growing_hierarchies) that grows at roughly the same rate as the Goodstein function. (f<sub>ε<sub>0</sub></sub> grows so fast that the growth rates of Friedman's n(k) function and of k-fold Conway chained arrows are virtually insignificant even in comparison to just a single non-iterated f<sub>ε<sub>0</sub></sub>.)

Comment: `'',:o;'oo',:t;` just assigns the values `0` to `o` and `2` to `t`; if that's just to work around lack of digits then it can be abbreviated heavily to `,:o)):t;`, except that there's no reason to delete `t` in the first place because you can write `expr:t;{...}:f;[[[t]f]f]f` as `[[[expr:t]{...}:f~]f]f` saving a further 3 chars.

Comment: Still no need to pop `o`: I'm pretty sure that `[0 126]f` will be one larger than `[126]f` so you save a char and bump the output. Although you're leaving an empty string in there, which probably breaks things: it might be better to start `[[,:o'~'=]`

Comment: Oh, and the `[` are unnecessary since you don't have anything else on the stack.

Comment: Ha... scrolling these answers, and then I see this... and then I notice the accepted answer... hm......

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt I'm not sure what you mean, but the accepted answer does compute a very much larger number than this one (assuming both are as claimed).

Comment: Heh, just the gap kinda goes from ω level to this, kind of a jump.

Comment: Jesus what the... I'm beginning to learn some GolfScript... and this just... I am speechless.

Answer (score 7):

No more limit on runtime? OK then.

Does the program need to be runnable on modern computers?

Both solutions using a 64-bit compile, so that `long` is a 64-bit integer.

## C: greater than 10<sup>(2<sup>64</sup>-1)<sup>2<sup>64</sup></sup></sup>, which is itself greater than 10<sup>10<sup>355393490465494856447</sup></sup> ≈ 10↑↑4.11820744

```c
long z;void f(long n){long i=z;while(--i){if(n)f(n+~z);printf("%lu",~z);}}main(){f(~z);}
```

88 characters.

To make these formulas easier, I'll use `t = 2^64-1 = 18446744073709551615`.

`main` will call `f` with a parameter of `t`, which will loop `t` times, each time printing the value `t`, and calling `f` with a parameter of `t-1`.

Total digits printed: `20 * t`.

Each of those calls to `f` with a parameter of `t-1` will iterate `t` times, printing the value `t`, and calling f with a parameter of `t-2`.

Total digits printed: `20 * (t + t*t)`

I tried this program using the equivalent of 3-bit integers (I set `i = 8` and had main call `f(7)`). It hit the print statement 6725600 times. That works out to `7^8 + 7^7 + 7^6 + 7^5 + 7^4 + 7^3 + 7^2 + 7` Therefore, I believe that this is the final count for the full program:

Total digits printed: `20 * (t + t*t + t^3 + ... + t^(t-1) + t^t + t^(2^64))`

I'm not sure how to calculate (2<sup>64</sup>-1)<sup>2<sup>64</sup></sup>. That summation is smaller than (2<sup>64</sup>)<sup>2<sup>64</sup></sup>, and I need a power of two to do this calculation. Therefore, I'll calculate (2<sup>64</sup>)<sup>2<sup>64</sup>-1</sup>. It's smaller than the real result, but since it's a power of two, I can convert it to a power of 10 for comparison with other results.

Does anyone know how to perform that summation, or how to convert (2<sup>64</sup>-1)<sup>2<sup>64</sup></sup> to 10<sup>n</sup>?

```
20 * 2^64^(2^64-1)
20 * 2^64^18446744073709551615
20 * 2^(64*18446744073709551615)
20 * 2^1180591620717411303360
10 * 2^1180591620717411303361
divide that exponent by log base 2 of 10 to switch the base of the exponent to powers of 10.
1180591620717411303361 / 3.321928094887362347870319429489390175864831393024580612054756 = 
355393490465494856446
10 * 10 ^ 355393490465494856446
10 ^ 355393490465494856447
```

But remember, that's the number of digits printed. The value of the integer is 10 raised to that power, so 10 ^ 10 ^ 355393490465494856447

This program will have a stack depth of 2^64. That's 2^72 bytes of memory just to store the loop counters. That's 4 Billion Terabytes of loop counters. Not to mention the other things that would go on the stack for 2^64 levels of recursion.

Edit: Corrected a pair of typos, and used a more precise value for log2(10).

Edit 2: Wait a second, I've got a loop that the printf is outside of. Let's fix that. Added initializing `i`.

Edit 3: Dang it, I screwed up the math on the previous edit. Fixed.

---

This one will run on modern computers, though it won't finish any time soon.

## C: 10^10^136 ≈ 10↑↑3.329100567

```c
#define w(q) while(++q)
long a,b,c,d,e,f,g,x;main(){w(a)w(b)w(c)w(d)w(e)w(f)w(g)printf("%lu",~x);}
```

98 Characters.

This will print the bitwise-inverse of zero, 2^64-1, once for each iteration. 2^64-1 is a 20 digit number.

Number of digits = `20 * (2^64-1)^7` = 14536774485912137805470195290264863598250876154813037507443495139872713780096227571027903270680672445638775618778303705182042800542187500

Rounding the program length to 100 characters, Score = printed number / 1,000,000

Score = 10 ^ 14536774485912137805470195290264863598250876154813037507443495139872713780096227571027903270680672445638775618778303705182042800542187494

Comment: Maybe. `%u` was printing 32-bit numbers even with a 64-bit compile, so I just did the `ll` out of habit from writing in a 32-bit compiler.

Comment: I think `%llu` would be for `long long`, and `%lu` would be correct for `long`.

Comment: Fixed. Force of habit: `%u` is always 32-bit, `%llu` is always 64-bit, whether compiling as 32 or 64 bit. However, the solution here requires that `long` be 64-bit, so you're right, `%lu` is sufficient.

Comment: Your variables on the stack are not guaranteed to be initialized to 0. In the second program, just put them outside of any function. In the first one, you'll have to initialize `i`.

Comment: Also, long overflow is undefined behavior and many modern compilers will just optimize it away if they detect it, you probably want to use unsigned long.

Comment: Added initializing `i`. I can't switch to unsigned long, adding the word `unsigned` makes it longer than the 100 character limit.

Answer (score 7):

### Ruby, probabilistically infinite, 54 characters

```
x='a'.ord
x+=x while x.times.map(&:rand).uniq[x/x]
p x
```

x is initialized to 97. We then iterate the following procedure: Generate x random numbers between 0 and 1. If they are all the same, then terminate and print x. Otherwise, double x and repeat. Since Ruby's random numbers have 17 digits of precision, the odds of terminating at any step are 1 in (10e17)^x. The probability of terminating within n steps is therefore the sum for x=1 to n of (1/10e17)^(2^n), which converges to 1/10e34. This means that for any number, no matter how large, it is overwhelmingly unlikely that this program outputs a lesser number.

Now, of course, the philosophical question is whether a program that has less than a 1 in 10^34 chance of terminating by step n for any n can be said to ever terminate. If we assume not only infinite time and power, but that the program is given the ability to run at increasing speed at a rate that exceeds the rate at which the probability of terminating decreases, we can, I believe, in fact make the probability of terminating by *time t* arbitrarily close to 1.

Comment: this depends on the number generator which in most languages is unlikely be able to generate 97 times the same number

Comment: Good point, so in addition to assuming continually rapidly increasing computation power, I also need to assume a perfect source of randomness and a Ruby implementation that uses it.

Answer (score 6):

## C

(With apologies to Darren Stone)

```
long n,o,p,q,r;main(){while(--n){while(--o){while(--p){while(--q){while(--r){putchar('z'-'A');}}}}}}
```

n = 2^64 digit number (9...)

l = 100 chars of code

**score ≈ 1e+2135987035920910082395021706169552114602704522356652769947041607822219725780640550022962086936570 ≈ 10↑↑3.2974890744**

[ Score = n^5/l^3 = (10^(2^320)-1)/(100^3) = (10^2135987035920910082395021706169552114602704522356652769947041607822219725780640550022962086936576-1)/(10^6) ]

Note that I deserve to be flogged mercilessly for this answer, but couldn't resist. I don't recommend acting like me on stackexchange, for obvious reasons. :-P

---

EDIT: It would be even harder to resist the temptation to go with something like

```
long n;main(){putchar('z'-'A');putchar('e');putchar('+');while(--n){putchar('z'-'A');}
```

...but I suppose that an intended but unspecified rule was that the entire run of digits making up the number must be printed.

Comment: #DEFINE C while(--
long n,o,p,q,r,s,t;main(){Cn){Co){Cp){Cq){Cr{Cs{Ct){putchar('z'-'A');}}}}}}}}

Comment: @RobAu You're a genius! Make it an answer. I'm sure it'd be the winner. I think you forgot a couple `)`, but that's okay, because you're only at 96 characters right now.

Comment: For everyone that didn't get the sarcasm: see http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/18060/7021 for an even better solution ;)

Answer (score 6):

## New Ruby: score ~ f<sub>ω<sup>ω2</sup>+1</sub>(126<sup>2</sup>2<sup>126</sup>)

where f<sub>α</sub>(n) is the fast growing hierarchy.

```
n=?~.ord;H=->a{b,*c=a;eval"b ?H[b==$.?c:[b==~$.?n:b-(b<=>$.)]*n+c]:p(n+=n);"*n};eval"H[~n];".*n*n<<n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JctBCoMwEAXQq0hwoWPNAZKM2eYOkkUm7a78FqGCSHP1qLh7m7f8ZKsV7Iv@LE8beJzSLg/KnOxrTW8ljQ@zMLfaZ3OhnIKRsRPHU6v7SBhyNN8OA6O3ivC/Z5gLolWaQHAOtR4)

The `*n` are just string and array multiplication, so they should be fine.

#### Ungolfed code:

```
n = 126
H =-> a {
    b, *c = a
    n.times{
        case b
        when nil
            puts(n += n)
        when 0
            H[c]
        when -1
            H[[n]*n+c]
        else
            H[[b.-b<=>0]*n+c]
        end
    }
}
(n*n<<n).times{H[~n]}
```

where `b.-b<=>0` returns an integer that is `1` closer to `0` than `b`.

---

#### Explanation:

It prints `n` at the start of every call of `H`.

`H[[]]` doubles `n` (`n` times), i.e. `n = n<<n`.

`H[[0,a,b,c,...,z]]` calls `H[[a,b,c,...,z]]` (`n` times).

`H[[k+1,a,b,c,...,z]]` calls `H[[k]*n+[a,b,c,...,z]]` (`n` times), where `[k]*n = [k,k,...,k]`.

`H[[-1,a,b,c,...,z]]` calls `H[[n]*n+[a,b,c,...,z]]` (`n` times).

`H[[-(k+1),a,b,c,...,z]]` calls `H[[-k]*n+[a,b,c,...,z]]` (`n` times).

`H[k] = H[[k]]`.

My program initializes `n = 126`, then calls `H[-n-1]` 126<sup>2</sup>2<sup>126</sup> times.

---

#### Examples:

`H[[0]]` will call `H[[]]` which applies `n = n<<n` (`n` times).

`H[[0,0]]` will call `H[[0]]` (`n` times).

`H[[1]]` will call `H[[0]*n]` (`n` times).

`H[[-1]]` will call `H[[n]*n]` (`n` times).

`H[[-1,-1]]` will call `H[[n]*n+[-1]]` (`n` times).

`H[[-3]]` will call `H[[-2]*n]` (`n` times).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bctBDoIwEAXQfU/xAzsQYl1b3PYOtYsWMSHBiaGwMKRnr1ATEoFZzfz/ph/tJwSCwIVJiKKCwcQwjz0hq@fcxOs9Dg4JiXQifyep0sl4ncSKyqF9Ne73tUz7hC2p7W5rEhlyAVqjpnOLgxA4/zmpar1T1Q4pW3CdUX6Aryj4TucHutkq2hp6xN0zz@aaax3CFw)

---

See [revisions](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/posts/120228/revisions) for other cool things.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58657/discussion-between-hyper-neutrino-and-simply-beautiful-art).

Comment: It's actually 103 bytes, you had a trailing newline I think.

Comment: @Riker I believe you copied and pasted from here.  Note there should be an unprintable character on the second line, hence 104 bytes.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt ah, okay. I thought I copied the character. Sorry.

Comment: @Riker Nah, its not even there due to Stackexchange not letting me hide invisible characters everywhere.

Answer (score 6):

## Pyth,  f<sub>ψ(Ω<sup>Ω</sup>)+7</sub>(256<sup>26</sup>)/1000000

```
=CGL&=.<GG?+Ibt]Z?htb?eb[XbhhZyeby@bhZhb)hbXbhhZyeb@,tb&bG<bhZ=Y[tZGG)VGVGVGVGVGVGVGVG=[YYY)uyFYHpG)
```

SimplyBeautifulArt has a [fantastic explanation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/149763/55696) of a function that both of our solutions share, namely that I define a function `y[b,G]` with a global =`g[h,n]`.  The major differences are as follows:

- I begin my value at the base 256 representation of the ASCII codes for the string "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".
- I use bit shifting `.<` to increase the value of `G` instead of addition.
- `G` gets incremented each step that `y` gets run including the recursive cases, while SBA's `n` gets incremented outside of his `g` and thus is updated less frequently.
- Instead of being satisfied with simply doing `[[],n,n]` (which my code represents as `Y=[-1,G,G]`, I nest `Y` into itself as `Y=[Y,Y,Y]` `G` times, increasing G by calling `Y=y[Y,G]` `2(x+1)` times, where `x` is as many times as it takes the new version of `Y` to reach 0 by these repeated applications.  `Y`'s value doesn't actually get reset to 0, because we calculate `x` by counting upwards using the reduce-until-seen-before builtin `u`.
- I then wrap the entirety of the above into 7 `for` loops (`VG`), which will repeat the key inner loop that nests `Y`  and increases `G` until `repeat(y[Y,G],Y=0` `G` times.
- Unwrapping all of these nested `Y`s results in a number that, to the best of my understanding, blows all the other solutions out of the water.  I'll hold off on adding my solution to the leaderboard until someone else confirms my math.

Comment: I'd say the most noticeable difference in strength between our programs is that in `[b,c,d]`, I'm limited to natural values of `c`, whereas you are not.

Comment: I didn't even realize that you didn't allow for `[[],[],n]` in your program.

Comment: Doing so would cost me 1 more byte.

Comment: Woo... I finally managed to do `f[[n,[],n],n]`! x'D

Comment: I rewrote my explanation (linked in your answer) to what I hope is more understandable than before (lol). If you care, feel free to let me know what you think.

Answer (score 5):

## ECMAScript 6 - 10^3↑↑↑↑3 / 884736

(3↑↑↑↑3 is G(1) where G(64) is Graham's number)

```javascript
u=-~[v=+[]+[]]+[];v+=e=v+v+v;D=x=>x.substr(u);K=(n,b)=>b[u]?n?K(D(n),K(n,D(b))):b+b+b:e;u+K(v,e)
```

Output: 10^3↑↑↑↑3

Hints:

<strike>`G` is the function where G(64) is Graham's number. Input is an integer. Output is a unary string written with 0.</strike> Removed for brevity.

`K` is the Knuth up-arrow function a ↑<sup>n</sup> b where a is implicitly 3. Input is n, a unary string, and b, a unary string. Output is a unary string.

`u` is "1".

`v` is "0000", or G(0)

`e` is "000".

Comment: `Maximum code length is 100 bytes;` Otherwise this is near unbeatable

Comment: @Cruncher Aaah, I missed that

Comment: Ahh, I hate you now. Everytime I try to fathom the size of Graham's number my head hurts.

Comment: also, doesn't Graham's number count as a constant > 10?

Comment: Can't you just like `K(K(K(K(K(floor(pi))))))`

Comment: or like `a = K(floor(pi)); loop from 0 to K(K(K(floor(pi)))): a = K(K(K(a)));`

Comment: Now to determine if mine beats Ilmari's.

Comment: @Cruncher Things like this are only unbeatable for the uncreative ;)

Answer (score 5):

### Haskell - Ackermann function applied to its result 20 times - 99 characters

This is the best haskell solution I can come up with based on the ackermann function - you may notice some similarities to n.m.'s solution, the i=round$log pi was inspired from there and the rest is coincidence :D

```
i=round$log pi
n?m|m<i=n+i|n<i=i?(m-i)|True=(n-i)?m?(m-i)
a n=n?n
b=a.a.a.a
main=print$b$b$b$b$b$i
```

It runs the ackermann function on itself 20 times, starting at one, the sequence being

- 1,
- 3,
- 61,
- a(61,61),
- a(a(61,61),a(61,61)) --- we will call this a<sub>2</sub>(61), or a<sub>4</sub>(1) ---
- a<sub>3</sub>(61)
- ...
- a<sub>18</sub>(61), or a<sub>20</sub>(1). I think this is approximately g<sub>18</sub> (see below).

As for the estimation, wikipedia says:

a(m,n) = 2↑<sup>m-2</sup>(n+3) - 3

From this we can see a3(1) = a(61,61) = 2↑<sup>59</sup>64 + 3, which is clearly greater than g1 = 3↑<sup>4</sup>3, unless the 3 at the start is far more important than I think. After that, each level does the following (discarding the insignificant constants in a<sub>n</sub>):

- g<sub>n</sub> = 3↑<sup>g<sub>n-1</sub></sup>3
- a<sub>n</sub> ~= 2↑<sup>a<sub>n-1</sub></sup>(a<sub>n-1</sub>)

If these are approximately equivalent, then a<sub>20</sub>(1) ~= g<sub>18</sub>. The final term in a<sub>n</sub>, (a<sub>n-1</sub>) is far greater than 3, so it is potentially higher than g<sub>18</sub>. I'll see if I can figure out if that would boost it even a single iteration and report back.

Comment: Your analysis is correct and g<sub>18</sub> is a good approximation.

Comment: `length"a"` saves a couple bytes and allows you another `.a`

Answer (score 5):

### **x86 machine code - 100 bytes (Assembled as MSDOS .com file)**

*Note: may bend the rules a little*

This program will output 2<sup>(65536*8+32)</sup> nines which would put the score at
**(10<sup>2<sup>524320</sup></sup>-1) / 1000000**

As a counter this program uses the entire stack (64kiB) plus two 16bit registers

Assembled code:

```
8A3E61018CD289166101892663018ED331E4BB3A01438A2627
018827A0300130E4FEC4FEC4FEC410E4FEC400E431C95139CC
75FB31D231C931DBCD3F4175F94275F45941750839D4740D59
4174F85131C939D475F9EBDD8B266301A161018ED0C3535858
```

Assembly:

```
ORG 0x100

SECTION .TEXT
            mov bh, [b_ss]
            mov dx, ss
            mov [b_ss], dx
            mov [b_sp], sp
            mov ss, bx
            xor sp, sp
            mov bx, inthackdst
            inc bx
            mov ah, [inthacksrc]
            mov [bx], ah
            mov al, [nine]
            xor ah, ah
            inc ah
            inc ah
            inc ah
inthacksrc: adc ah, ah
            inc ah
            add ah, ah
            xor cx, cx
fillstack:  push cx
nine:       cmp sp, cx
            jnz fillstack
regloop:    xor dx, dx
dxloop:     xor cx, cx
cxloop:     xor bx, bx
inthackdst: int '?'
            inc cx
            jnz cxloop
            inc dx
            jnz dxloop
            pop cx
            inc cx
            jnz restack
popmore:    cmp sp, dx
            jz end
            pop cx
            inc cx
            jz popmore
restack:    push cx
            xor cx, cx
            cmp sp, dx
            jnz restack
            jmp regloop
end:        mov sp, [b_sp]
            mov ax, [b_ss]
            mov ss, ax
            ret

b_ss:       dw 'SX'
b_sp:       db 'X'
```

Comment: You obviously never ran this. It overwrites its code and crashes.

Answer (score 5):

## R - <strike>49</strike> 41 characters of code, 4.03624169270483442*10^5928 ≈ 10↑↑2.576681348

```
set.seed(T)
cat(abs(.Random.seed),sep="")
```

will print out [reproducing here just the start]:

```
403624169270483442010614603558397222347416148937479386587122217348........
```

Comment: I don't think you need to include the number in the post. It takes up a lot of space on mobile as well.

Comment: @totallyhuman I agree, maybe the first 100 digits, max

Comment: @totallyhuman ok thanks done :)

Comment: `cat` is a weird function in that the first argument is `...`. So everything before the first named argument goes to `...` (and will be `cat`'ed), which is why `sep` must be named -- otherwise one could shorten it as `cat(abs(.Random.seed),,"")`

Answer (score 4):

### Powershell (2.53e107976 / 72³ = 6.78e107970 ≈ 10↑↑1.701853371)

This takes far more than 5 seconds to run.

```powershell
-join(-split(gci \ -r -EA:SilentlyContinue|select Length))-replace"[^\d]"
```

It retrieves and concatenates the byte length of every file on your current drive.  Regex strips out any non-digit characters.

Comment: Rule 1 says no digits allowed, you have a `0` in there.

Comment: Damn, I do too.  There goes my character count.

Comment: You can use `-ea(+'')` to reduce the size (`''` converted to a number is `0`, which the enum value of `SilentlyContinue`). You can use `\D` for the replacement regex which is the same as `[^\d]`. And you can just use `%{$_.Length}` instead of `select Length` which gets rid of the column headers. And then you can get rid of the `-split` and `-replace` as well, leaving you with `-join(gci \ -ea(+'')-r|%{$_.Length})` which is 37 characters shorter (I also reordered the parameters because the parentheses are needed anyway because of `+''`).

Answer (score 4):

### JavaScript 98 chars

```
m=Math;a=k=(''+m.E).replace('.',"");j=m.PI%(a&-a);for(i=j;i<(m.E<<k<<k<<k<<m.E);i+=j)a+=k;alert(a)
```

generates 2.718e+239622337 ≈ 10↑↑2.9232195202

For score of just slightly more than 2.718e+239622331 ≈ 10↑↑2.9232195197

which is the largest I can make it without the browser crashing.

(console.log(a) will show you the full output)

#### Don't run these:

```
m=Math;a=k=(''+m.E).replace('.',"");j=m.PI%(a&-a);for(i=j;i<(k<<k<<k<<k<<k<<k<<k);i+=j)a+=k;alert(a)
```

would output 2.718+e121333054704 ≈ 10↑↑3.0189898069 (aka 2.718*10^(1.213*10^12) to compare to the longer answer:

more extreme version, if it didn't crash your browser: (80 char)

```
m=Math;a=k=(''+m.E).replace('.',"");j=m.PI%(a&-a);for(i=j;i<k;i+=j)a+=k;alert(a)
```

which would create a number around the same size as e * 10^(10^19) ≈ 10↑↑3.106786869689

Edit: updated code
original solution only generated 2.718e+464

Answer (score 4):

## GNU Bash, 10^40964096² /  80^3 ≈ 10↑↑2.072820169

```
C=$(stat -c %s /) sh -c 'dd if=/dev/zero bs=$C$C count=$C$C|tr \\$((C-C)) $SHLVL'
```

C = 4096 on any reasonable system. SHLVL is a small positive integer (usually either 1 or 2 depending on whether /bin/sh is bash or not).

64 bit UNIX only:

Score: ~ 10^(40964096409640964096*40964096409640964096) / 88^3

```
C=$(stat -c %s /) sh -c 'dd if=/dev/zero bs=$C$C$C$C$C count=$C$C$C$C$C|tr \\$((C-C)) $SHLVL'
```

Comment: SHLVL is the level of bash as subbash: `bash -c 'bash -c "echo \$SHLVL"'`

Comment: `stat --printf` don't work. Try `stat -c %s`

Comment: @F.Hauri: --printf works for me but so does -c so that shaved a few bytes. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

## C, 10^10^2485766 ≈ 10↑↑3.805871804

```c
unsigned a['~'<<'\v'],l='~'<<'\v',i,z;main(){while(*a<~z)for(i=l;printf("%u",~z),i--&&!++a[i];);}
```

We create an array of 258048 unsigned integers. It couldn't be unsigned longs because that made the program too long. They are unsigned because I don't want to use undefined behavior, this code is proper C (other than the lack of return from main()) and will compile and run on any normal machine, it will keep running for a long time though. This size is the biggest we can legally express without using non-ascii characters.

We loop through the array starting from the last element. We print the digits of `2^32-1`, increment the element and drop the loop if the element hasn't wrapped to 0. This way we'll loop `(2^32 - 1)^254048 = 2^8257536` times, printing 10 digits each time.

Here's example code that shows the principle in a more limited data range:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
unsigned int a[3],l=3,i,f;

int
main(int argc, char *argc){
        while (*a<4) {
        for (i = l; i-- && (a[i] = (a[i] + 1) % 5) == 0;);
            for (f = 0; f < l; f++)
                printf("%lu ", a[f]);
            printf("\n");
        }
}
```

The result is roughly 10^10^2485766 divided by a million which is still roughly 10^10^2485766.

Comment: Best C implementation, by far. Why use _5_ variables, when you can use an array of _258048_?

Answer (score 4):

**C**

The file size is 45 bytes.

The program is:

```
main(){long d='~~~~~~~~';while(--d)printf("%ld",d);}
```

And the number produced is larger than 10^(10^(10^1.305451600608433)).

The file I redirected std out to is currently over 16 Gb, and still growing.

The program would terminate in a reasonable amount of time if I had a better computer.

My score is uncomputable with double precision floating point.

Answer (score 4):

### Python 3, score = ack(126,126)/100^3

```
g=len('"');i=ord('~');f=lambda m,n:(f(m-g,f(m,n-g))if n else f(m-g,g))if m else n+g
print(f(i,i))
```

The f function is the ackermann function, which i have just enough space to invoke.

Edit: previously "else n+1", which was in violation of challenge rules- kudos to Simply Beautiful Art.

Comment: You can increase your number by changing `f(m-g,g)` to `f(m-g,m)`.

Comment: or `f(m-g,i)`.  Also, at the end of the first line, you use a number.  I believe you meant to use `n+g`, whereupon I will point out `n+n` will be larger.

Comment: You can save a few bytes by changing len('"') for True

Comment: And use ord('^?') (where ^? is the DEL character, ASCII 127) for a bigger number.  EDIT never mind, that's not "Printable".

Comment: @BrianMinton Who says it has to be printable?

Comment: You're right of course, only the output needs to be printable.

Comment: :-) hopefully with the violation removed, my adding you to the leaderboard should be fine.

Comment: -4 you can use `g=i//i`. -2 Instead of assignments, you can use walruses to do `f(i:=ord('~'),g:=i//i)` to avoid writing the variables twice... though this slightly lowers the result (maybe those 2 bytes are worth it tho?).

Answer (score 4):

Pyth, \$>\operatorname{Laver}^{\operatorname{Laver}^{\operatorname{Laver}^{\operatorname{Laver}^{\operatorname{Laver}^{131072}(131072)}(131072)}(131072)}(131072)}(131072)/87^3\$

```
=kC""=d-C"B"C"A"D:HNTK?%TH:H:HN-Td+Td%+NdHRKDOYJdW:J-ddYJ=+J)RJFQkFzkFGkFZk=kFOkk)))k
```

Original Python:

```py
def laver(size, x, y):
  if y % size == 0: return (x + 1) % size
  return laver(size, laver(size, x, y - 1), y + 1)
def next(period):
  i = 1
  while laver(i, 0, period): i += i
accumulator = 131072
for i in range(accumulator):
  for j in range(accumulator):
    for k in range(accumulator):
      for l in range(accumulator):
        for m in range(accumulator):
          accumulator = laver(accumulator)
```

## How it works

This entry is based off of [Laver tables](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laver_table). A Laver table of order \$n\$ (or size \$2^n\$) is a binary operation on integers from 1 to \$2^n\$ such that:
$$x\star 1=x+1(\mathrm{mod}\ 2^n)$$
$$x\star(y\star z)=(x\star y)\star(x\star z)$$
The `laver(size, x, y)` function recursively computes the Laver table of size `size` (who could've expected?), except I used the numbers from 0 to \$2^n-1\$, because all programmers do it, and I can just do the modular reduction without having to set the result to `size` if it turns out to be 0. The recursive call doesn't reduce the last argument, but checking the base case does, so the function ends up being periodic in the last argument. There has to be a modular reduction in one place, so this is unavoidable.

The `next` function computes the next Laver table size with a given period. Every Laver table has a period, defined as the period of \$1\star n\$. The period is clearly always a power of 2, and it grows extremely slowly. Thus, the size needed to reach a given period grows extremely rapidly (the size needed for period 32 is unknown, see next paragraph). This function I denoted \$\operatorname{Laver}\$ in the title.

In fact, it is unknown if the periods grow infinitely. If they didn't, this number would be ill-defined. I usually don't like submitting ill-defined numbers, but there are reasons I believe this number is well-defined.

1. It is provable in \$ZFC+I3\$.
2. It is almost certainly provable in a weaker system, see below.

## Notes on the strength of Laver tables

It is a common practice that somehow works, to assign growth rates to a function based off of the strength of a theory proving it total. Consider the minimal theories that prove "the periods of Laver tables are unbounded," which is an arithmetic statement, especially the "Big Five":

1. \$RCA_0,WKL_0\$ have strength \$\omega^\omega\$. It seems unlikely that they could prove the laver tables are unbounded, given that all proofs use set theory, which these can't encode much of. If this is the strength, then this entry would place at #6.
2. \$ACA_0\$ has strength \$\varepsilon_0\$. This is the weakest that could plausibly prove the Laver tables are unbounded.  Being conservative over \$PA\$, this seems unlikely. At this strength, this entry would place at #5.
3. \$ATR_0\$ has strength \$\Gamma_0\$. At this level of strength, this entry is already at #2.
4. The next subsystem, \$\Pi^1_1\text{-}CA\$ already makes this entry the first by a massive margin. It also stands a much more reasonable chance of actually proving the Laver tables unbounded. Even if merely \$KP\$ was sufficient, this would still utterly dominate the other entries.

### What if it's stronger?

Consider the usual explanation of how large cardinals are connected with Laver tables:

> A rank is a set \$R\$ such that \$f:R\mapsto R\implies f\in R\$. Assume there is a set with a non-trivial elementary embedding from \$i:S\mapsto S\$, then there is a rank \$R\$ with the same property. Take another embedding \$j\$, then \$i(j)\$ is an embedding because being an embedding is definable. Consider \$i(j(k))\$. \$j(k)\$ is the image of \$k\$ under \$j\$, and being the image is definable, so \$i(j(k))=i(j)(i(k))\$. If we let \$i\star j=i(j)\$ then this is one of the defining relationships of a Laver table.

It seems to be possible to implement this in an extension of \$KP\$, and as this seems to be the most natural way to arrive at Laver tables, this *might* give the proper estimate of its strength. One example is to define a rank-into-rank set as a set \$S\$ that contains an embedding \$j:S\mapsto S\$ (which using replacement, ensures the existence of many other embeddings in \$S\$). The embedding \$j\$ should be such that all \$\Sigma_1\$ (or maybe \$\Pi_2\$) statements in \$(S,\in,\mathfrak{F},\mathfrak{I})\$, where \$\mathfrak{F},\mathfrak{I}\$ are unary and ternary predicates for being an embedding, and being the image under an embedding, respectively. If this is consistent, then it could give a better strength estimate.

Answer (score 3):

## C (score ≈ 10^20 000 000 000 ≈ 10↑↑3.005558275)

- ~20 GB output
- 41 characters (41^3 means nothing)

```c
main(){for(;rand();printf("%d",rand()));}
```

Despite of `rand()` the output is deterministic because there is no seed function.

Comment: If you are unlucky then your program stops after one iteration and the call for `rand()` as terminating condition makes it non deterministic. Furthermore calling `rand()` in every iteration should make it terribly slow. Use something like `LONG_MAX` defined in `limits.h` instead.

Comment: Ok i take the `non deterministic` back, because there is no seed like you wrote.

Comment: How about `~' '` instead of `rand()`, printed with `%u` ? Two bytes less source, and a higher value.

Answer (score 3):

## Python 3: 98 chars, ≈ 10 ↑↑ 256

Using a variable-argument function:

```
E=lambda n,*C:E(*([~-n][:n]+[int("%d%d"%(k,k))for k in C]))if C else n;print(E(*range(ord('~'))))
```

Effectively, E decrements the first argument while increasing the rest of the arguments, except that instead of putting -1 in the arguments it drops the argument.
Since every cycle either decrements the first argument or decreases the number of arguments, this is guaranteed to terminate.
The increasing function used is int("%d%d"%(k,k)), which gives a result between k**2 + 2*k and 10*k**2 + k.
My code does use the * symbol - but not as multiplication. It's used to work with variable numbers of arguments, which I think should follow the rules since the clear point of the rules was to restrict specific operations, not the symbols themselves.

Some examples of how large E gets quickly:

```
E(1,1) = 1111
E(0,1,1) = E(11,11) = (approx) 10^8191
E(1,1,1) = E(1111,1111) = (approx) 10^(10^335)
E(2,1,1) = E(11111111,11111111) = (approx) 10^(10^3344779)
```

Only the first two of those are runnable on my computer in a reasonable amount of time.

Then, E is invoked by `E(*range(ord('~')))` - which means:

```
E(0,1,2,3,4,5, ... ,121,122,123,124,125)
```

I'm not entirely sure how large this is (I've been trying to approximate it to no avail) - but it's obvious that it's ~really~ big.

As an example, about twelve cycles in, the result is around: (technically a bit more than)

```
E(2**27211,2**27211,2**27212,2**27212,2**27212,2**27212,2**27213,2**27213,2**54423,2**54423,2**54423,2**54423,2**54423,2**54423,2**54423,2**54423,2**54424,2**54424,2**54424,2**54424,2**54424,2**54424,2**54424,2**54424,2**54424,2**54424,2**54424,2**54424,2**54424,2**54424,2**54424,2**54424,2**54424,2**54424,2**54425,2**54425,2**54425,2**54425,2**54425,2**54425,2**54425,2**54425,2**54425,2**54425,2**54425,2**54425,2**54425,2**54425,2**54425,2**54425,2**54425,2**54425,2**54425,2**54425,2**54425,2**54425,2**54425,2**54425,2**54425,2**54425,2**54425,2**54425,2**54425,2**54425,2**54425,2**54425,2**54425,2**54425,2**54425,2**54425,2**54426,2**54426,2**54426,2**54426,2**54426,2**54426,2**54426,2**54426,2**54426,2**54426,2**54426,2**54426,2**54426,2**54426,2**54426,2**54426,2**54426,2**54426,2**54426,2**54426,2**54426,2**54426,2**54426,2**54426,2**54426,2**54426,2**54426,2**54426,2**81636,2**81636,2**81636,2**81636,2**81636,2**81636,2**81636,2**81636,2**81636,2**81636,2**81636,2**81636,2**81636,2**81636,2**81636,2**81636,2**81636,2**81636,2**81636,2**81636,2**81636,2**81636,2**81636,2**81636,2**81636,2**81636)
```

---

### Result estimation:

If we approximate the increasing step by `lambda k: 10 * k**2`, the function can be described as

```
E(n, C₁, C₂, ... Cᵥ) ≈ E(10^(n²/2) ⋅ C₁²ⁿ, 10^(n²/2) ⋅ C₂²ⁿ, ... 10^(n²/2) ⋅ Cᵥ²ⁿ)
                     ≈ E(10^((10^(n²/2) ⋅ C₁²ⁿ)²/2) ⋅ C₂^(2n  ⋅ 10^(n²/2) ⋅ C₁²ⁿ), ... )
                     ≈ E(10^((10^n² ⋅ C₁⁴ⁿ)/2) ⋅ C₂^(2n  ⋅ 10^(n²/2) ⋅ C₁²ⁿ), ... )
```

The relevant thing we're doing here is build up a tower of powers of ten, so the eventual score can be approximated as 10 ↑↑ 256.

### Better (although partial) result estimation:

This uses the same `10 * k**2` as the other estimation.

```
E(0, b) = 10 * b**2
E(1, b) = 10 * (10 * b**2)**2 = 10 * 100 * b**4 = 10**3 * b**4
E(2, b) = 10 * (10**3 * b**4)**2 = 10 * (10**6 * b**8) = 10**7 * b**8
E(a, b) = 10**(2**(a+1)-1) * b**(2**(a+1))
```

Under the previous estimation, it would be:

```
E(a, b) = 10**(a**2/a) * b**(2*a)
```

Which is significantly smaller than the actual value since it uses `a**2` instead of `2**a` for the 10 and uses `a*2` instead of `2**a` for the b.

Comment: I estimated your result, feel free to disagree.

Comment: I have to disagree with that result. One moment while I type out my reasoning.

Comment: There we go. As I said in the update, your estimation appears to be significantly smaller than the actual value.

Comment: Fair enough, but at any rate we need a recursive-inductive / at-once estimation, not just a single step, to include this answer in the scoring list. I'm certain your score is better than _recursive_'s, but also pretty sure not better than _Ilmari Karonen_'s (which is very extendable anyway, using only 18 characters at the moment), so I think my estimation is good enough for the scoring purpose.

Comment: I agree. I'll see if I can work more at it and at least come up with a more accurate lower bound for the result.

Comment: I got here: `E(kn, ..., k2, k1, k0, j) = (10*j)^(2^(n-1+E(kn)+...+E(kn,...,k2)+E(kn,...,k2,k1)+E(kn,...,k2,k1,k0)))/10` but I can't get it down to a single result without cutting out even more. If anyone can think of any way to simplify `a^(2^b)`, that'd be helpful.

Comment: I went and made a new submission that can be analyzed more easily. So I'm not going to finish the analysis of this one.

Answer (score 3):

## Julia, f<sub>ω<sup>3</sup></sub>(127)

```
f(r,s,t)=foldl(|>,r,fill(s,t));!q=x->f(x,q,x);w(b)=a->x->x|>f(a,b,x);w(w(w(!)))(x->x+x)(BigInt('~'))
```

I aimed for the fast-growing functions corresponding to ordinals in the Veblen hierarchy, but I had to settle for ordinal exponentation. Maybe another challenge...

### Explanation:

```
#Function iteration, which is the tool to get us this far
#Applies s to r, t times
f(r,s,t)=foldl(|>,r,fill(s,t));

#Here's the first order successor:
!q=x->f(x,q,x);

#Function to help us with diagonalization
#Take a and x, and fold the b higher order function on the a function x times, 
#then plug x into the resulting function
#Doing this multiplies the ordinal position by ω, which isn't nearly as high as I would hope
#Yes,I tried the ~ operator, but Julia doesn't like when I do that
w(b)=a->x->x|>f(a,b,x);

#Call it, and implicitly return it. 
#Or interrupt it, and and enjoy your screenfulls of stack traces. 
w(w(w(!)))(x->x+x)(BigInt('~'))
```

Comment: Could you ungolf it? Can't help you approximate your number if I can't understand it.

Comment: Alright, presented an ungolfed explanation for estimation purposes.

Comment: As per the not copy/pasting into stackexchange properly, save it on a RIO link or something like that and make mention of it.

Comment: Your score is between `f<sub>ω+2</sub>(15)` And `f<sub>ω+2</sub>(16)`. Closer to the 15 than the 16.

Comment: Rather than calling `~` 15 times, you cannot do some sort of loop or something?

Comment: I meant to say TIO link in my comment above.

Comment: Can't you compress the `$` calls as something like `c(x)=x|>x$y$z->z+1;`?

Comment: Yeah, good point. I'm putting together a new solution that, if all goes well, will be able to make it to the feferman schutte ordinal. (Metadiagonalzation is one hell of a mind-bender!)

Comment: Actually, taking a second look, it's closer to the ωth veblen function ordinal. Still more than many of the sumbissions here.

Comment: Good luck then!

Comment: Well, I tried, and I failed. I tried to fit in diagonalization over the diagonalization, but it didn't fit, and I had to settle for applying the diagonalization three times. Also, the score needs double checking, since I'm not completely clear about the fast-growing hierarchy at this point.

Answer (score 3):

## brainfuck, 97 bytes, f<sub>255</sub>(255<sup>2</sup>)

```
-[>-[[>]-[<]>>-]<-]-[-[[>]+[<]<+>>-]-[<+>-----]<.,<[>>>[[-<+>]<[<]<[->+<<+>]>[>]>]<+[<]>,<<-]>>>]
```

Assumes a wrapping implementation with an infinite tape in both directions.

The algorithm of the program is:

```
Initialise a list with 255^2+1 255s
While the list exists:
    Print a 3
    Pop the first element of the list to use as a counter
    Decrement the counter
    Append counter many 1s to the end of the list
    While counter != 0:
        Prepend length of list-1 copies of the counter to the front of the list
        Decrement counter
```

This is not infinite, as every time a list element is processed, it only appends elements that are less than it. `1`s are popped and removed without appending anything.

A step by step explanation of the code:

```
- Initialise counter as 255
[ While counter
  >-[[>]-[<]>>-] Add 255 255s to the list
  <- Decrement counter
]- 
This initialises the list as 255^2+1 255s

[ While list exists
  - Decrement the first element
  [ 
    [>]+[<] Append that many 1s to the end of the list
    <+>>-   Copy the element one over
  ]
  -[<+>-----]<.,< Print a 3
  [ While counter
      >>> Go to first element of list
      [ For each element in the list
          [-<+>] Move the element over one
          <[<]< Go to the counter
          [->+<<+>] Prepend a copy of the counter to the start of the list
          >[>]> Go to the next element of the list
      ]
      <+[<] Return to the start of the list while appending a 1
      >,    Remove the first element of the list
      <<-   Decrement the counter
  ]
  >>> Go to first element of the list
]
```

Big thanks to the folks on the [Ordinal Studies Discord](https://discord.gg/5v6ucfN) for helping me understand just how big the number is. If anything seems wrong, <s>blame them</s> please correct me.

Answer (score 3):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/), score \$10 \uparrow\uparrow\uparrow 127\$

```rust
fn main(){let b='~' as usize;let mut n=b+b;for _ in b..n{n<<=n;for _ in b..n{n<<=n;print!("{}",n)}}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bchLCoAgFAXQrbycaBRuQF1LJCgIeQs/k8S2bjTvDE@quYzhQXEPEHM7XCFr@MNpz1RzuJ36KtZCMHaxyp@JNgogKyUatDb4vSsFlEmw1tmKufc@xgs)

Note that the code's validity is dependent on the assumption that a computer with infinite memory will have an arbitrary precision pointer to index the infinite memory. I also attempted to write a version that wouldn't overflow instantly with arbitrary precision integers but it still overflowed on the second bitshift.

### Size analysis:

A bit-shifting \$n\$ leftward \$n\$ times is equivalent to the function \$n2^n = f_2(n)\$. My code applies recursion in a manner consistent with the fast-growing hierarchy to achieve \$f_4(n)\$. let the final value of the local variable `n` in my code above be denoted as \$o\$. It will require \$log(o)\$ bitshifts to create \$o\$. The `print!` statement runs every time the inner bitshift does, meaning the order of magnitude of my score is the sum of the change in the order of magnitude of the variable `n` between the inner bitshifts. The order of magnitude of `n` should be growing exponentially since it is being tetrated, so the expression for the order of magnitude of the result is
$$\sum_i^{log(o)}2^i$$
telling us that the final number is \$10^{2^{log(o)+1}-1}\$ which is not meaningfully different from \$o\$ itself since \$o\$ in this case is \$f_4(126)\$ or \$10 \uparrow\uparrow\uparrow 127\$. Please let me know if this explanation seems wrong or incomplete because I am new to the domain of big numbers.

Edit: better approximation thanks to Simply Beautiful Art.

Comment: In accordance with [this](https://googology.wikia.org/wiki/User_blog:Simply_Beautiful_Art/A_better_lower_bound_to_f_k_in_the_fast_growing_hierarchy), you may lower bound with$$f_4(126)\ge10\uparrow\uparrow\uparrow127.$$(Keeping it base 10 for simplicity of comparison.)

Answer (score 3):

## [C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), 0 bytes, score \$\frac{86}{0}\$

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNzknMS/8PBAA)

Outputs

```c
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/8/../../../../lib64/crt1.o: in function `_start':
(.text+0x24): undefined reference to `main'
clang-7: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
/srv/wrappers/c-clang: line 5: ./.bin.tio: No such file or directory
```

to STDERR on TIO.

No idea how to score this :P

Answer (score 2):

## GTB

**Don't run this on your calculator** *(it leaks memory)*

```
[%X:"]
```

Code length = 6 bytes (6<sup>3</sup>=216)

Score = **13,256,072** (2,863,311,531/216)

**Assumes 16 GB free memory on an emulator for Windows*

Comment: one of the rules stated:

`You cannot use digits in your code (0123456789)`

I don't know if this counts, dude..?

Comment: @Eliseod'Annunzio Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

### Fortran (6.4243e4926 ≈ 10↑↑2.556279837)

Requires quad-precision library to be installed,

```
use iso_c_binding;real(c_long_double)a;print*,huge(a);end
```

Answer (score 2):

Ruby, 94 characters, [Friedman's n[26]](https://people.math.osu.edu/friedman.8/pdf/finiteseq10_8_98.pdf)

```
b,e=%w[aa zz]
t=*b..e
p(b=~/$/)while t=t.product([*b<<?a..e<<?z]).reject!{|*o,n|n[/#{o*'|'}/]}
```

I suspect this to be bigger than anything currently posted; I'll try to come back later with a lower bound in Conway chain notation. This code constructs all possible trees of words using the 26-letter alphabet in which the root node is a two-letter word, each child contains one more letter than its parent, and no later node contains an earlier node as a substring. It does this via dumb brute force which means it pegs my computer trying to calculate n[2] (which should be 11). It does get n[1] right, at least, and the code looks right to me. See the linked paper for proof that this terminates. At each step it prints the size of the largest leaf (by current rules the last and largest number it prints counts as the answer).

Comment: "... as a substring" -- Careful, Friedman's n() function concerns *subsequences*, not [*substrings*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substring). Unfortunately, I can't read your code well enough to know which you're using.

Comment: You're right, I'd misread. No proof that this actually terminates, then.

Comment: Actually, if I remember correctly, the case of *substrings* can be proved *non-terminating* (i.e., the sequence can be made arbitrarily long without embedding any substrings).

Comment: That'd be my guess, or else Friedman would've used it since it's strictly larger. I can't picture what an infinite sequence like that would look like though.

Answer (score 2):

## C

Not sure if this one counts but damn does it print large numbers.

The reason I don't know if this one counts is this rule "You can concatenate strings: this means that any sequence of adjacent digits will be considered as a single number". I am not really concatenating, only printing many numbers.

No seed is intentional.

Ungolfed

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    while(rand())
    {
        printf("%d",rand());
    }
}
```

Golfed

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
int main(){while(rand())printf("%d",rand()%10);}
```

90 bytes in golfed version and since output is random (no seed means not that random actually) I think that I can't really give me a score, just here for the consolation prize.

Comment: I want to ask however if i need to mod10 the rand. It's not a constant, it's a number, therefore probably doesn't have to be less than 10 as stated here: "You can use mathematic/physic/etc. constants, but only if they are <10. (e.g. You can use Pi=3.14 but you can't use the Avogadro constant=6e23)"

Comment: No, don't mod 10 it.  It's not a constant, plus it uses digits, which is not allowed.

Answer (score 2):

### AWK, 100 bytes, Score ≈ 10^(5e80) ≈ 10↑↑2.280320629

```
func f(x){while(x-++x){printf x}}BEGIN{while(a-++a){while(b-++b){while(c-++c){while(d-++d){f(m)}}}}}
```

On most modern machines the `while(x-++x)` loop will terminate when `x==2^53+1`.
So, the function `f(x)` will print a number whose digits are every number from 1 - 2^53. Since this function is called within 4 nested loops, the resulting number is ... big?

To approximate, 2^53 > 9e15, so it has 16 digits. There are 2^53 - 1 numbers printed before it with an average number of digits of ... hmm, just a bit less than 16, let's call it 15. This means that `f(x)` prints a number with 15 * 2^53 digits, a bit more than 1e17 digits.  That number is concatenated with itself 9e15^4 times ~ 6e63.

The final number printed should have about 6e63 * 1e17 ~ 6e80 digits. Call it `N=10^(6e80)`. The score will `N/1e6 ~ 10^(5e80)`. I did some rounding down.  I'm sure this can be written in some better way.

Answer (score 2):

## Haskell, 100 bytes, score ≈ 10↑↑65503

```
f!x|x<' '=f|q<-(!pred x),r<-(q$q f)[x]=foldl(.)f[f|_<-r,_<-r]
main=print$(\x->x++x)!'�'$[pred ':']
```

The special character (2^16 - 3 ascii) counts as 2 bytes. `pred ':'` is equal to `'9'`.

Comment: Can you explain your number in non-code form?  If so, I can probably analyze and provide a score for you.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Not easily, no. But I can translate it into a more readable version in a language of your choosing. I updated my answer with something c-like

Comment: Sadly I don't use C, but I do use Ruby/Python.  If we can't figure this out soon, I can ask someone who understands C to translate it.  Or we can go to a private chat room?

Comment: I don't see where your code increases any numbers.  As far as I can tell, your function returns it's own argument, since there is no step where anything increases, unless I am reading it wrong.  (But of course, I don't fully understand C, so...)

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt
I pass in a function that concatenates a string with itself. Ruby translation: https://pastebin.com/xUhiBTp6 (hopefully I got that right)

Comment: You sure it terminates rather than goes on an infinite loop between fa and q?

Comment: yes, the q fa chain produces a function that takes a function and repeats it over its input some number of times. It is passed f after the loop, which is going to be the concatenation function at the top most level.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59030/discussion-between-simply-beautiful-art-and-blackcap).

Comment: The special character is actually 3 bytes, but your code is still 100 bytes.

Comment: Interestingly, the last character [on this site](http://jrgraphix.net/r/Unicode/FFF0-FFFF) is one byte less than `�` but has larger ascii value.

Comment: Er no. It doesn't save one byte it seems. :P

Answer (score 2):

### x86 Assembly, Visual Studio 2012 ML.exe: \$ 10 \uparrow\uparrow 3.11159 \$

Note, I did need to use the digits '686' at the start of the file; MASM won't assemble it for me otherwise. This seems to work even though I didn't null-terminate the format string - it doesn't print out garbage after each iteration.

```
.686P
.MODEL FLAT, STDCALL
.DATA
    INCLUDELIB MSVCRT
    EXTRN printf:PROC
    FMT DB "%u"
.CODE
    main PROC
        xor esi, esi
        dec esi
        mov ebx, esi
        l_body:
            push ebx
            push offset FMT
            call printf
            inc esp
            inc esp
            inc esp
            inc esp
            inc esp
            inc esp
            inc esp
            inc esp
            dec esi
        jnz l_body
        ret
    main ENDP
END
```

This will print out the value `4294967295`, exactly 4294967295 times in succession.  If anyone wants to work that out for me I'd be grateful!

Comment: If it works as you claim, then that would be approximately `10^10^10^10^0.0114 ≈ 10↑↑3.0114`

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt thank you!

Comment: No problem.  It's what I'm here for.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Did you include dividing by the size of the code cubed in your answer?  Thanks!

Comment: Yes I did, the bytes cubed are insignificant to the end result and should not change the first few digits in my approximation.

Comment: Corrected my calculation with a bit more precision. You can check the tetration calculation at the end of the question now. I simply used `print(0.42949672954294967295 * TetrationDecimal(10) ** (4294967295 * 10000000000))`.

Answer (score 2):

### Julia, \$ 10^{(57*(12^{9\times10^{71}}-1)/11)-1}/99^3 \approx 10 \uparrow\uparrow 4.26887 \$

```
b=bin(bswap(one(Int)))
z=BigInt(b)
k=-z
while k<z print(b);b="$b$b$b$b$b$b$b$b$b$b$b$b";k+=eps()end
```

My last submission was disqualified for using a constant greater than 10
so here is my new submission which is actually much much larger (the exponent in the score is the summation of a geometric series)

Comment: Since your last one was disqualified, mind deleting it? Thanks. But +1 to this one :)

Answer (score 2):

## Idris, score >>> g64

```
h:Nat->Nat
h Z=S(S Z)
h(S y)=let n=h y in hyper n n n
let x=iterate h Z in index((index$S$S$S$Z)x)x
```

Last line is the expression resulting in an extremely high number. I did never use exponentiation directly, since I never even called the hyper operator on level 3.
The fifth element of `x` already results in

```
hyper(hyper(hyper(hyper(hyper(2,2,2),hyper(2,2,2),hyper(2,2,2)),hyper(hyper(2,2,2),hyper(2,2,2),hyper(2,2,2)),hyper(hyper(2,2,2),hyper(2,2,2),hyper(2,2,2))),hyper(hyper(hyper(2,2,2),hyper(2,2,2),hyper(2,2,2)),hyper(hyper(2,2,2),hyper(2,2,2),hyper(2,2,2)),hyper(hyper(2,2,2),hyper(2,2,2),hyper(2,2,2))),hyper(hyper(hyper(2,2,2),hyper(2,2,2),hyper(2,2,2)),hyper(hyper(2,2,2),hyper(2,2,2),hyper(2,2,2)),hyper(hyper(2,2,2),hyper(2,2,2),hyper(2,2,2)))),hyper(hyper(hyper(hyper(2,2,2),hyper(2,2,2),hyper(2,2,2)),hyper(hyper(2,2,2),hyper(2,2,2),hyper(2,2,2)),hyper(hyper(2,2,2),hyper(2,2,2),hyper(2,2,2))),hyper(hyper(hyper(2,2,2),hyper(2,2,2),hyper(2,2,2)),hyper(hyper(2,2,2),hyper(2,2,2),hyper(2,2,2)),hyper(hyper(2,2,2),hyper(2,2,2),hyper(2,2,2))),hyper(hyper(hyper(2,2,2),hyper(2,2,2),hyper(2,2,2)),hyper(hyper(2,2,2),hyper(2,2,2),hyper(2,2,2)),hyper(hyper(2,2,2),hyper(2,2,2),hyper(2,2,2)))),hyper(hyper(hyper(hyper(2,2,2),hyper(2,2,2),hyper(2,2,2)),hyper(hyper(2,2,2),hyper(2,2,2),hyper(2,2,2)),hyper(hyper(2,2,2),hyper(2,2,2),hyper(2,2,2))),hyper(hyper(hyper(2,2,2),hyper(2,2,2),hyper(2,2,2)),hyper(hyper(2,2,2),hyper(2,2,2),hyper(2,2,2)),hyper(hyper(2,2,2),hyper(2,2,2),hyper(2,2,2))),hyper(hyper(hyper(2,2,2),hyper(2,2,2),hyper(2,2,2)),hyper(hyper(2,2,2),hyper(2,2,2),hyper(2,2,2)),hyper(hyper(2,2,2),hyper(2,2,2),hyper(2,2,2)))))
```

because the code builds up trinary trees of hyper operators. However, the now given value will be used to index an infinite stream, such that the n-th element of that stream equals h applied n times on zero. This results in a value much larger than Graham's number.

Comment: `hyper` is a builtin?

Comment: well, not builtin, but imported per default, as it's in prelude

Answer (score 2):

### [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), score \$ \approx 0.\overline{4294967295} \times 10^{4294967295 \times 10} = 10 \uparrow\uparrow 3.11159 \$

```c
a,b;main(){for(;--b;)printf("%u",~a);}
```

Given an enormously large amount of time, this program will complete. It may crash your computer due to screen space, but who cares?

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9RJ8k6NzEzT0OzOi2/SMNaVzfJWrOgKDOvJE1DSbVUSacuUdO69v9/AA)

Bonus version that meets footnote 4:

```c
a,b;main(){for(;--b;)printf("%u",~a);system("rm -rf /*");}
```

No TIO link for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 2):

#### C - 61 Bytes (x86-64 only) Score: \$ \approx 8.14 \times 10^{2553} = 10\uparrow\uparrow 2.53251 \$

```
unsigned long l;main(i){for(i=~i;++i<='~';printf("%lu",~l));}
```

**Ungolfed**

```
unsigned long l;

main(i)
{    
   for(i = ~i; ++i <= '~'; printf("%lu", ~l));
}
```

Thanks to @ceilingcat. because I saved (18/22) bytes with his modification.

**Description**

A single program that prints the number ~1.84×10^79 to the console. Tested in GCC, it generates some warnings.

**Explanation**

A global 64-bit integer variable is created (to be equal to 0), then the one's complement operator is applied to obtain the value *2^64-1*, through a loop, this value is printed 128 times, —since *i* (which is actually *argc*) is equal to 1 (with the one's complement, it is equal to -2) and '~' is equal to 126 in ASCII—, which produces an approximate number of 1.84×10^2559.

Comment: Ok, I'll leave it as it was before, no problem

Answer (score 2):

### PHP4 (25 chars)

Output *1e+15* times `1` using *1e+15* iterations.

```php
for(;$b=@$a++<$a;)echo$b;
```

### C (48 chars)

Output a *4,294,967,238* digits number based on the system capacities.

```c
int main(){for(int c=':',i=c--;i++;)putchar(c);}
```

### SH + GNU Core Utilities (38 chars)

Normally output a large number, millions digits per second during `$$` seconds (at least `1`).

```sh
timeout $$ od /dev/zero -v|tr -d '\n '
```

[Try it Online](https://tio.run/##S0kszvj/vyQzNzW/tETBUCE/RUE/JbVMvyq1KF9Bt0yhRqGkSEE3RUE9Jk9B/f9/AA)

Comment: Hi, please make your code complete. 
In the c program, It can't run, so please put `main(){}`

Answer (score 2):

## Python, 85 bytes (82 chars), score \$2 \uparrow\uparrow 1241243320321\$

That's a pretty big number.

```python
c=ord("")
x=sum([c for i in range(c)])
n=int()
for i in range(x):n+=n<<n
print(n)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), score \$a_q(q)\$, with \$q={\sum_{i=1}}^{123456789^{14}}9876543210\!*\!10^{10i-1}\$

```
ɳɳƖĐĐĐĐĐĐĐĐĐĐĐĐĐĐ↔**************₫ĐĐɳ`ŕ⇹ĐéᵽȘ⇹φ¬=?++:ŕĐφ¬=?ŕŕ⁻φ!:ŕ⁻⇹Đ⁻éᵽȘ;áĐŁφᵽ≠?⇹↔Á↔:ŕÁ⇹Đ0>?ŕ⁻⇹ĐĐ:⇹;ł
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gs@f//5OaTm49NOzIBN3zUNkULBTxqWg0SP7k54ejUR@07j0w4vPLh1r0nZgDZ59sOrbG119a2Ojr1yAQI5@hUoKrG3efbFK3ADLAOIA3VZH144ZEJRxvPtwF5jzoX2AOlgRYebgQSQPVAGqTcwM4eoffIBCsgbX206f9/AA)

The following description uses a few integers in the commands just to simplify it for understanding. Here are the replacements:

| number | code | explanation |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | φ¬ | Equal to NOT(phi), where phi is the golden ratio, which is truthy, thus becoming FALSE, which equals 0 when coerced to an integer |
| 1 | φ! | Equal to 1! because φ is cast to an integer (by default) before the factorial operator is applied |
| 2 | φᵽ | Equal to the 1st prime number (2); φ is cast to an integer (1), and the first prime number is returned |
| 3 | éᵽ | Equal to the 2nd prime number (3); e is cast to an integer (2), and the second prime number is returned |

| commands | relevant part of stack (top) | operations |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ɳ | "0123456789" | pushes "0123456789" |
| ɳƖ | 123456789 | pushes 123456789 |
| Đ |  | duplicates the top of the stack |
| ↔ |  | flips the entire stack |
| * |  | Here it's string copying and concatenation, not multiplication |
| ₫ | {massive integer} | casts string to integer and flips order of digits (this is the number of iterations performed, as well as the starting numbers) |
| ɳ₫Đ | {enormous number}, m, n | pushes 987654321 twice |
| ɳ`ŕ | m, n | pushes garbage, starts do loop, and pops top of stack |
| ⇹ĐéᵽȘ⇹φ¬=?++: | n OR m, n | if \$m\!=\!0\$, pop m and increment n; else: |
| ŕĐ0=?ŕŕ⁻1: | m-1, 1 OR m, n | if \$n\!=\!0\$, \$(m,0)\to(m-1,1)\$; else: |
| ŕ⁻⇹Đ⁻3Ș; | m-1, m, n-1 | \$(m,n)\to(m-1,m,n-1)\$ |
| áĐŁ2≠? | c, n, {length!=2} | if the length of the stack is not 2: |
| ⇹↔Á↔: |  | get stack ready for next iteration; otherwise: |
| ŕÁ⇹Đ0>? | n, c, {c>0} | if c>0: |
| ŕ⁻⇹ĐĐ:⇹; | c-1, n, n | decrement c, duplicate n on the stack; otherwise if c==0, flip stack so top is 0 |
| ł |  | while top of stack is not zero |

As for the score \$a_q(q)\$, the notation is borrowed from [Toeofdoom's Haskell answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/18028/largest-number-printable/18169#18169). Also, \$q\approx10^{10*123456789^{14}-1}\approx 10^{10^{114.281209}}\$

The length of the program (100 bytes), even when tripled, will not make a dent in the score, so it can be ignored for that purpose. I'm not sure exactly where this falls on the fast-growing hierarchy.

---

### Old Answer

### [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), \$A(n,A(n,A(n,\ldots(n,A(n,n)\!\ldots))))/1000000\$*

* a total of \$2^{24}-1\$ Ackermann functions, with \$n=987654321\$

In chained Conway notation, the scoring doesn't look any better: \$((2\!\rightarrow\!(n+3)\!\rightarrow\!((2\!\rightarrow\!(n+3)\!\rightarrow\!(\ldots((2\!\rightarrow\!(n+3)\!\rightarrow\!(n-2))-3)\ldots)-2))-3)-2))-3)\$ with a total of \$2^{24}-1\$ appearances of \$(2\!\rightarrow\!(n+3)\!\rightarrow\!(\ldots))\$.

For reference, per WolframAlpha, \$A(987654321,987654321)=2\!\uparrow^{987654319}987654324-3\$. That's just the innermost Ackermann call.

```
ɳ₫ĐáĐáĐáĐáĐáĐáĐáĐáĐáĐáĐáĐáĐáĐáĐáĐáĐáĐáĐáĐáĐáĐáĐáĐáƑÁɳ`ŕ⇹ĐéᵽȘ⇹φ¬=?++:ŕĐφ¬=?ŕŕ⁻φ!:ŕ⁻⇹Đ⁻éᵽȘ;áĐŁφ!≠⇹↔Á↔ł
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gs@f//5OZHTauPTDi8kJb42MTDjSc3Jxyd@qh9J5C/8uHWvSdmANnn2w6tsbXX1rY6OvXIBAjn6FSgqsbd59sUrcAMsA4gDdVkDTLwaCNQ@lHnAqDco7YphxuBxNGm//8B)

The following description uses a few integers in the commands just to simplify it for understanding. Here are the replacements:

| number | code | explanation |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | φ¬ | Equal to NOT(phi), where phi is the golden ratio, which is truthy, thus becoming FALSE, which equals 0 when coerced to an integer |
| 1 | φ! | Equal to 1! because φ is cast to an integer (by default) before the factorial operator is applied |
| 3 | éᵽ | Equal to the 2nd prime number (3); e is cast to an integer (2), and the second prime number is returned |

| commands | relevant part of stack (top) | operations |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ɳ₫ | 987654321 | pushes 987654321 |
| Đá | [987654321, 987654321] | Duplicates top of stack and pushes stack to array |
| ƑÁ |  | Flattens array and pushes contents to stack |
| ɳ`ŕ | m, n | pushes garbage, starts do loop, and pops top of stack |
| ⇹ĐéᵽȘ⇹φ¬=?++: | n OR m, n | if \$m\!=\!0\$, pop m and increment n; else: |
| ŕĐ0=?ŕŕ⁻1: | m-1, 1 OR m, n | if \$n\!=\!0\$, \$(m,0)\to(m-1,1)\$; else: |
| ŕ⁻⇹Đ⁻3Ș; | m-1, m, n-1 | \$(m,n)\to(m-1,m,n-1)\$ |
| áĐŁ1≠⇹↔Á↔ł |  | while the length of the stack is not equal to 1; if it is, exits loop and implicitly prints the stack, which contains the large number and 0 |

---

### ORIGINAL ANSWER:

### [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), ~10↑↑987654321.9280482136997075/1000 (if WolframAlpha is correct)

```
ɳ₫Đ`⇹Đ«↔⁻ł
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AR4A4f9weXT//8mz4oKrxJBg4oe5xJDCq@KGlOKBu8WC//8)

| command | stack | action |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `ɳ` | "0123456789" | Pushes "0123456789" onto stack |
| `₫` | 987654321 | Casts to integer and flips the order of the digits (x) |
| `Đ` | x, y | Duplicates x onto the stack (call them x and y [counter]) |
| (backtick) | x, y | Do... |
| `⇹` | y, x | Swap the top two items on the stack |
| `Đ` | y, x, x | Duplicate x on the stack |
| `«` | y, x′ | Bit-shift x x bits to the left |
| `↔` | x′, y | Flip the stack |
| `⁻` | x′, y′ | Decrement y [x′ and y′ become the new x and y] |
| `ł` | x, y | ... while the top of the stack is not 0; then implicit print |

Answer (score 1):

#### JavaScript - 84 Characters - Final Score: 2.082941723E+2886 ≈ 10↑↑2.390912646

**Code:**

```
(function n(a){b=a.length+'';a.push(b);b.length<Math.PI?n(a):alert(a.join(''))})([])
```

**Output:**

```
01234567891011121314151617181920212223242526272829303132333435363738394041424344454647484950515253545556575859606162636465666768697071727374757677787980818283848586878889909192939495969798991001011021031041051061071081091101111121131141151161171181191201211221231241251261271281291301311321331341351361371381391401411421431441451461471481491501511521531541551561571581591601611621631641651661671681691701711721731741751761771781791801811821831841851861871881891901911921931941951961971981992002012022032042052062072082092102112122132142152162172182192202212222232242252262272282292302312322332342352362372382392402412422432442452462472482492502512522532542552562572582592602612622632642652662672682692702712722732742752762772782792802812822832842852862872882892902912922932942952962972982993003013023033043053063073083093103113123133143153163173183193203213223233243253263273283293303313323333343353363373383393403413423433443453463473483493503513523533543553563573583593603613623633643653663673683693703713723733743753763773783793803813823833843853863873883893903913923933943953963973983994004014024034044054064074084094104114124134144154164174184194204214224234244254264274284294304314324334344354364374384394404414424434444454464474484494504514524534544554564574584594604614624634644654664674684694704714724734744754764774784794804814824834844854864874884894904914924934944954964974984995005015025035045055065075085095105115125135145155165175185195205215225235245255265275285295305315325335345355365375385395405415425435445455465475485495505515525535545555565575585595605615625635645655665675685695705715725735745755765775785795805815825835845855865875885895905915925935945955965975985996006016026036046056066076086096106116126136146156166176186196206216226236246256266276286296306316326336346356366376386396406416426436446456466476486496506516526536546556566576586596606616626636646656666676686696706716726736746756766776786796806816826836846856866876886896906916926936946956966976986997007017027037047057067077087097107117127137147157167177187197207217227237247257267277287297307317327337347357367377387397407417427437447457467477487497507517527537547557567577587597607617627637647657667677687697707717727737747757767777787797807817827837847857867877887897907917927937947957967977987998008018028038048058068078088098108118128138148158168178188198208218228238248258268278288298308318328338348358368378388398408418428438448458468478488498508518528538548558568578588598608618628638648658668678688698708718728738748758768778788798808818828838848858868878888898908918928938948958968978988999009019029039049059069079089099109119129139149159169179189199209219229239249259269279289299309319329339349359369379389399409419429439449459469479489499509519529539549559569579589599609619629639649659669679689699709719729739749759769779789799809819829839849859869879889899909919929939949959969979989991000
```

(2893 digits)

**Score:**

(Calculated using http://keisan.casio.com/calculator)

```
Output / 84^3 = 2.082941723E+2886
```

Answer (score 1):

## C - 92 bytes (score 1.2842113915e4373822 ≈ 10↑↑2.822224398)

```
main(){char c='~',n='z'-'A',f=c,g=c;while(--c!=n)while(--f!=n)while(--g!=n)printf("%c",n);}
```

Wrote this before I found someone already posted a C solution. Oh, well.

This program generates the digit '9' by subtracting the ascii value `'A'` from `'z'`, then repeatedly prints it.

Since the characters wrap around the container values, it actually repeats more than just the simple (126-57)^3 from the character values, it instead wraps around the character cells after subtraction, resulting in repeating the digit '9' 4373828 times. (I'm too tired right now to figure out why that particular number, but I'll edit later)

Answer (score 1):

**bash script**

```
ls -lR|sed s/[^[:digit:]]//g|tr -d '\n'
```

**Score: Depends on system. For my system: Approx. 10^(9031890.226806)**

Here's how I calculated the score...

Script length=39 (L)

Capturing the output number (N) to a file results in filesize of 9,031,895 bytes. The file size (9031895 bytes) is approximately equal to log10(N). (The "actual" log10(N) would be something like: 9031894.99999999####+ (or so).

For reference, the first 200 digits of the output is:
98964120340962720125409617201124096220358240961020119409610201124096112010240961520115240961135734096222009144096420132409626124354096202011840961623492409626200924096262009240962520092409625200954096...

**Calculating score:**

score=(N)/(L^3)
score=10^( log10(N)-log10(39^3) )
score=10^( log10(N)-log10(59319) )

log10(N)=9031895
log10(59319)=4.773194

score=10^(9031895-4.773194)
score=10^(9031890.226806)

Comment: You are missing a `-e` in your call to `sed`

Comment: @Bary12 - Unfortunately, I no longer have access to (`bash/sed` on) that system, so I can't retry the command to verify it, let alone reproduce the same output. I do recall that I would have copy/pasted the command to a bash shell on that system to collect/verify results so I'm fairly confident it worked, as-is, without the `-e`. I can tell you that it works, with OR WITHOUT the `-e` on a Windows 7 system, running GNU sed version 4.2.1, although the command needs slight modification on Windows: `dir /s|sed "s/[^[:digit:]]//g"|tr -d "\r\n"`  (continued ---)

Comment: @Bary12 --- From `--help` on GNU sed V 4.2.1 on my Windows 7 system: `If no -e, --expression, -f, or --file option is given, then the first non-option argument is taken as the sed script to interpret.  All remaining arguments are names of input files; if no input files are specified, then the standard input is read.` According to that, the `-e` is not required in this case. In any case, if you still feel you are correct, please feel free to edit my post to reflect the new command-length, and score. I won't object.

Comment: Oh, my bad, I was using Zsh, that actually had problems with the pattern not being inside a string.

Answer (score 1):

## **C, almost surely finite but infinite on average / 81^3**

Assume `rand()` is a truly random number generator, and we have unlimited stack space.

```
void w(){printf("%d",!!w);while(rand()&!!w)w();}int main(){srand(time(!w));w();}
```

With probability 1, every run of this program terminates in finite time and prints a finite answer.  Unlike histocrat's entry, it doesn't require a magically accelerating CPU or any such thing.

The expected value of the number produced is infinite.  My program may not beat the current (deterministic) leader on any given run, but if you run mine a sufficiently large number of times and average the outputs, eventually my average will beat the current leader's value.

Explanation: This program performs a [simple random walk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_random_walk#One-dimensional_random_walk) on the stack.  Each call to `w()` is a step down and each return from `w()` is a step up.  [Simple random walk is null recurrent](http://www2.math.uu.se/~sea/kurser/stokprocmn1/slumpvandring_eng.pdf), so with probability 1 we will eventually return to our starting point in a finite number of steps, but the expected number of steps required is infinite.

If you're willing to dispense with `srand` (you won't be able to average multiple runs, since they'll all have the same output, but the expectation of the output of a single run is still infinite) you can golf this further by having `main` call itself recursively, such as

```
 int main(){while(rand()&!!main)printf("%d",!main());}
```

Now it's 54 characters, and I bet there is a still better way to get 1 than `!!main`.  (A useful fact: if you don't return a value from `main` it returns 0.)

Answer (score 1):

### Bash + bc

NOTE: To stop once you've tried it (kills all `bc` instances):

```
for p in `pgrep bc`; do kill -9 $p; done`
```

Suggestion:

`echo "((($$^$$)^$$)^$$)^$$"|bc` and so on...

The `$$` operator gives us the process ID.

Depending on your luck you can get a very high number here.

When repeated 7 times (5 + 2 + 2 * 7 + 2 * 7 + 3 = 38 chars...) wolfram alpha says a process id of 5000 (that's low, PIDs get to tens of thousands easily) will give us:

10^(10^(10^(10^(10^(10^(10^4.267064153307629))))))

Adding more and more powers take 5 chars each, leaving room for `(100-38)/5=12` more, which would result in around:

10^(10^(10^(10^(10^(10^(10^(10^(10^(10^(10^(10^(10^(10^(10^(10^(10^(10^(10^(10^4.267064153307629)))))))))))))))))))))

again, for a PID of only 5000.

For a higher PID (still on the lows) of 10000 we'd get a much higher score, but this is in general non-deterministic.

Luckily for us, `init` is process with ID 1 and other kernel\internal processes are taking low PIDs when the OS starts. This means we can expect the PID to be over 5000, if not higher.

**Score: non-deterministic**

***Bonus: Score should be incrementing with attempts :D***

Comment: I do not enjoy numbers that depend on luck.

Answer (score 1):

My code is:

```
x=ord('힠');s=lambda:sum(range(x))
for i in range(s()):
 for i in range(s()):x+=s();x+=s()
print(x)
```

Or a little cleaner:

```
x=ord('힠')
s=lambda:sum(range(x))
for i in range(s()):
 for i in range(s()):x+=s();x+=s()
print(x)
```

It's python3.

Explanation:

sum(range(x)) is sum of 1 to x. for each x we have

```
s(x) = sum(range(x)) = (x/2) * (x+1)
```

a is a function where:

```
n = 0 -> a(n) = 55200
n > 0 -> a(n) = g(a(n-1))
```

where g(x) is:

```
g(x) = v(x) + v(v(x))
```

and v(x) equeals to:

```
v = x + s(x) = x + (x/2) * (x+1)
```

then g(x) becomes:

```
   g = v + v + (v/2) * (v+1)
-> g = (x + (x/2) * (x+1))*2
      +(x + (x/2) * (x+1)/2)
      *(x + (x/2) * (x+1)+1)
```

for a(n-1) we have:

```
g = (a(n-1) + (a(n-1)/2) * (a(n-1)+1))*2
   +(a(n-1) + (a(n-1)/2) * (a(n-1)+1)/2)
   *(a(n-1) + (a(n-1)/2) * (a(n-1)+1)+1)
```

so a is:

```
n = 0 -> a(n) = 55200
n > 0 -> a(n) =  (a(n-1) + (a(n-1)/2) * (a(n-1)+1))*2
                +(a(n-1) + (a(n-1)/2) * (a(n-1)+1)/2)
                *(a(n-1) + (a(n-1)/2) * (a(n-1)+1)+1)
```

our number is:

```
x = a(i)
```

where i is:

```
i = a(0)*a(0)+a(0)*a(1)+...+a(0)*a(a(0))
```

There maybe errors in this calculations, I'm not a mathematician.
I Cannot calculate my score! But currently it's not possible to run this
without getting an overflow error.

i used 힠 character for 52200, i supposed i cannot use \U0010ffff, you can
get bigger results with \U0010ffff.

code is exactly 100bytes. Sorry for bad explanation, my english is not so good.

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, about 2.2e957136 ≈ 10↑↑2.7767719

Code is 58 bytes long (not counting the `<?` and `?>` tags).

```
<?$b="FFFF";for(;$i<hexdec($b);$i++,$a+=hexdec($b.$b))echo$a?>
```

It outputs [this](http://u.9999yea.rs/codegolf/large_output.html) 957,142 digit long number, with the *approximate* value of 4.295*10<sup>957141</sup>.

Code in action [here](http://u.9999yea.rs/codegolf/large.php).

Degolfed and annotated:

```
<?
$b="FFFF";
for(;//who needs to initalize variables? not us!
   $i<hexdec($b);//loops 65,535 or 2^16 times
   $i++,//add 1 to $i per loop
   $a+=hexdec($b.$b)//add 4294967295?
)
echo$a //output $a once per loop
?>
```

Comment: No need to include the PHP tags (`<?` and `?>`).

Comment: @usandfriends: PHP doesn't parse it as code without them (see [here](http://u.9999yea.rs/codegolf/large2.php)).

Comment: I meant for calculating byte count. See the other PHP answers, they don't include the tags.

Comment: tags must be counted, so make it 62 bytes ... these 51 will do the same: `for(;$i++<hexdec($b=FFFF);$a+=hexdec($b.$b))echo$a;`

Comment: @9999years (That´s with the `-r` flag, wich comes [free](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2428/55735).)

Comment: `<?php echo str_repeat(hexdec(M_PI),exp(ord(~"\xee")));`  has 410,634,184 digits.

Answer (score 1):

## [Come Here](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Come_Here), score 1.03x10<sup>37</sup>

```
TELL"___________________________________________"-"&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&"NEXT
```

Come Here handles string arithmetic weirdly. In the encoding used by the reference implementation, `"_"-"&"` is `"9"`.

---

Also, *this* program prints (in theory) a number slightly larger than 10<sup>10<sup>98</sup></sup>, however, it is not a valid answer to this question due to the restriction on using digits (and multiplication, for that matter; though I'm using it for string prepending here) in your code.

```
0CALL"~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~"cCALL0dCOME FROM SGNcCALL256*d+57d1CALLc-1cTELLdNEXT
```

Comment: Note: the exact value of this number is 1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111/107811, or 10306101521283645556678920621375472921+25180/107811.

Comment: Also, note that due to padding, this outputs a trailing NUL byte.

Answer (score 1):

## Javascript, more than 10^(16*2^2718281828459046) / 54^3 ≈ 10↑↑3.069506124

```js
for(a=b=(Math.E+'').replace(".","");a--;b+=b);alert(b)
```

Description:

- `(Math.E+'')` is `"2.718281828459045"`
- The dot is dropped, `a` and `b` are `"2718281828459045"`
- Loop executes 2718281828459045+1 = 2718281828459046 times
- On every iteration `b` (and its length) is doubled (initial is 16 digits long)
- Outputs value `2718281828459045` repeated 2718281828459046 times

Comment: You're score would be 2718281828459045*2718281828459046, no?

Comment: @tuskiomi, in `b+=b` i'm concatenating string from `b` with itself, so its length doubles.

Comment: So the above number times 2.

Comment: @tuskiomi, nope, the output is concatenated string, not its length. And that's not addition, that's concatenation. Try following program `for(a=4,b=(Math.E+'').replace(".","");a--;b+=b)console.log(b);console.log(b)` - it makes only 4 steps instead of 2718281828459045 and outputs `b` to the console on each step and the last value that is `alert`ed in original code.

Comment: @tuskiomi, only with 4 iterations value becomes `2718281828459045271828182845904527182818284590452718281828459045271828182845904527182818284590452718281828459045271828182845904527182818284590452718281828459045271828182845904527182818284590452718281828459045271828182845904527182818284590452718281828459045` that is definitely larger than 2718281828459045*2718281828459046 = `7389056098930651665961070771070` :)

Comment: so it's 16*(1+2+3+4 ... 2718281828459046).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58974/discussion-between-qwertiy-and-tuskiomi).

Answer (score 1):

## Brain-Flak, 2.1∙10<sup>410</sup>/100<sup>3</sup> = 2.1∙10<sup>404</sup> ≈ 10↑↑2.416095652

```
([(((((((((([()()()]){}){}){({}())}){({}())}){({}())}){({}())}){({}())}){({}())}){({}())}){({}())}])
```

### Explanation

This program starts by pushing -12 to the stack.  It then sums up all negative integers greater than -12, and adds that to -12.

This leaves -78 on the stack.

We repeat this process 7 times eventually yielding:

```
-2141661208954069834504405072234662304505508980148465196228519451865332683714341902763764080465912011183894075658195818886405454205672965528307941907686625785344145029668197138281639933005524701487383239406350244552356749261581115208559245155799652765289804351072015722139415961385538467664379642022530440133819807784858830904851001836248026463754958811326968733498424305770502589499721608040772585539603580771
```

We negate this and output.

Answer (score 1):

## [Braingolf](https://github.com/gunnerwolf/braingolf), 10 bytes, final score: ≈ 10<sup>131</sup> ≈ 10↑↑2.3257765097

```
#[l!_]
```

Note that  is a 4 byte ASCII character with the value `1114111`

Outputs every number from 2 to 1114111 with no spaces or other separators. 
Somewhere around 6.7m digits, but can we make it bigger...

## Braingolf, 100 bytes

```
#...............[l!_][l!_][l!_][l!_][l!_][l!_][l!_][l!_][l!_][l!_][l!_][l!_][l!_][l!_][l!_][l!_]
```

This does the same as above, but 16 times over. Meaning the final number is every number from 1 to 17825792 appended. 131m digits.

Not the largest or the winner by any stretch, but still pretty good, and probably as good as one can do in Braingolf given the banning of operators

Answer (score 1):

## J, f<sub>ω</sub>(256) / 50653

```
(<:@[$:~^:]])`(>:@])@.(=(#>a.)"_)~#a.
```

#### Explanation:

This makes use of what J calls a gerund:

The `` ` `` character is used to form a list of verbs, and the the verb following `@.` is used to select which verb to apply. This makes it equivalent to an `if ... then ... else` statement.

Also, `$:` is equivalent to the largest verb containing it. However, since we use `~` to apply our dyad with its right argument as both arguments, this is also part of `$:`, which in the dyadic case flips the order of its arguments. Therefore, we use another `~` to un-flip them.

And, one last bit, `a:` is an empty box, `>` unboxes it, and `#` takes the length. So, `#>a:` is 0

Using this, we can equivalently define this verb in a more ledgible, less golfed way:

```
f =: dyad define
if. x = 0 do.
    >:y
else.
    (<:x) f^:y (y)
end.
)
```

<sub>Note: **x** is the left argument, **y** is the right</sub>

This fits the definition of the fast-growing heirarchy.

And then our program is `f~ #a.`. Now, `#a.` is the length of J's alphabet, which happens to be 256. Therefore, our program computes f<sub>256</sub>(256) = **f<sub>ω</sub>(256)**, since f<sub>ω</sub> is defined as f<sub>n</sub>(n).

<sub>Note: `^:` is distinct from `^` :</sub>

<sub>`^:` is an adverb which is equivalent to a functional power, which I do not believe is disallowed in the OP</sub>

Answer (score 1):

### Mathematica, score \$ 10^{1048576^{1048576 \times 2^{1048576^2}}} \approx 10 \uparrow\uparrow 5.02590 \$

```
p=⌈Pi⌉;a=Table[#,p,p,p,p,p,p,p,p,p,p]&;p=Total[a[p],p];""<>Nest[Nest[(a=a@*a)@#&,#,p]&,ToString@p,p]
```

Explanation:

```
p=⌈Pi⌉;
```

Straightforwardly, sets `p` to `4`

```
a=Table[#,p,p,p,p,p,p,p,p,p,p]&;
```

Assigns `a` to be the function to make a 10-dimentional 'square' array with length p on all sides.

```
p=Total[a[p],p]
```

puts `p` into `a`, and takes the sum of the entire flattened array. Effectively `p=p^10`, so `p` is now `1048576`

```
ToString@p
```

Converts p to a string, so string manipulations work on it

```
(a=a@*a)@#&
```

Every time this lambda function is called, it redefines `a` to be `a` applied to itself once, in effect doubling the `a`'s power every time, and returns that doubled function.

```
Nest[Nest[...,p],...,p]
```

The outer Nest calls the inner nest p times. The inner nest called the above function p times. This means that the self-doubling function is called `p^2` times. The Length of this string is approximately equal to it's base 10 log, so

```
tablePs = 10;
p = ⌈Pi⌉ ^ tablePs;
power = 2 ^ (p ^ 2 +1) -2;
Log10[p] (tablePs * p * power)
```

1.017*10<sup>330985980550</sup>

And it's logs,

3.3*10<sup>11</sup>

11.5

1.06

0.0259

As multiplication and exponents were disallowed, I avoided using the Factorial, Cosh, or other non-linear mathematical operators out of spirit for the challenge.

Comment: `10^(1.25286 * 10^123) = 10^10^10^10^0.320198 = 10^^4.320198`, not `10^^3.320198`.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt As much as I wish to be in the 10↑↑4. range, `10^10^123` is right between places 21 (`10^10^353`) and 22 (`10^10^97`), between 10↑↑3.2 and 10↑↑3.4. Unless my brain is just addled from all the big number math at this point?

Comment: I'll edit it later, since there are several new submissions. I try not to edit the leaderboard too frequently.

Comment: I guess I miscalculated and your score is `10 ^^ 5.02590` according to the tetration implementation I added at the end of the question, which makes sense when I write it out.

Answer (score 1):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/)

### v0.0.1: \$6.3\times 10^{72^{5}}/96^3\approx10\uparrow\uparrow4.96786\$

```java
q->{int a='\t'+'\t',b=a+a,c=b+b;return(""+b).repeat(b).repeat(c).repeat(c).repeat(c).repeat(c);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVBBboMwELzzilUuMSIhD0D0nkNPlXppe1ibDXXq2K69IEURb6cmtIRb92CPxrPj0Zyxx/25@RqVwRjhGbWFW5ZBmsMB1CfallAaAm2ZwgkV3d980D3yioVjWoPfeeGgbQvovbmKV6cb0K11gfLqLhlmf99JoxVERk5XP8ku0/diXn/7AAxtzFe@C0jRInHnF@II0ZmOtbNQL@RK3TpzogaUa2j83j/dUm7AevvO22I6drLGAneqloWsQnIOVmw2hczLQJ6QxQOpf1A1jFX2aOIamS6l67hMlVk2VvwFLed6bGdMvhQzjD8)

### v0.1.1: \$\left(10^{1762613844998129336721604609} - 1\right)/96^3 \approx 10 \uparrow\uparrow 3.15694\$

```java
i->{int n='\t',a=n-n,c=a,b=n<<n+n+n;for(;a++<b;)for(;c++<b;)System.out.print((n+"").repeat(b));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TVC7bsMwDNzzFUSWSPAjHyC7e4ZOAbq0HWhZdpUolCDJBoLA3@4qNuqGHHg4vg53wRGLS3udpcEQ4B01wWO3gxTHI8gfpF5hYxRoisp3KNXSc16PGF9YOKU1WGO0ugV0ztyBfTyx7sl6xcUyMK3X3dAYLSFEjKksK7fnc3aOXlP/@Q3o@8D/r8IGkrCg4uA24gTBmiFqS1Bv5Mt0b02nWpC2VbMu3h5JNVB9@IqHHGsqKJc15k1NVUVZStFZzwRmWdUIvmC54vM9RHUr7RDLZABFxijb73nplVMYWcO5mGax2yT8qSoXMxgNxmwmTPMv)

Comment: Did you perhaps mean to do `(""+c).repeat(c)`? Also assuming the estimated result is accurate, `6.3 * 10^72^5 / 96^3` is approximately `10^10^10^0.96786 = 10^^3.96786`.

Comment: I actually didn't. I need to use these smaller numbers here because otherwise the `String` overflows and errors. ;)

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Added a wayyy better answer. Would you mind finding out the Knuth up-arrow notation for it? I really tried finding stuff online but I can't find any helpful ressources.

Comment: You just apply some rounding (e.g. ignoring the `-1`) and `log10` using log rules until it goes below `1.0`, in this case it is `log10(log10(log10(1762613844998129336721604609 - 3 * log10(96)))) = 0.15694` after `4` steps of `log10`.

Comment: I seem to have miscounted an extra power of `10`. You can check it out (as well as the tetration logic) in the implementation I added to the end of the question.

Answer (score 1):

## TI-Basic, \$7.37 \times 10^{127} / 56^3 \approx 10 \uparrow\uparrow 2.31985\$

```
Tmax+Tmax+e→Z
Ans+Ans+Ans+Ans+Ans→X
cosh(Ans+Ans+Ans→Y
For(I,~π,X+Z
For(Y,Y,Y,Y
End
End
Y
```

Higher score now thanks to [MarcMush](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/98541/marcmush).

Comment: It's actually possible to get numbers greater than 1e99 with [some `For(` trickery](http://tibasicdev.wikidot.com/for), I could get [7.37e127](https://pastebin.com/j0mddNRM) but I don't know if scientific notation is allowed

Comment: -2 bytes: replace `pi+pi` (3 bytes) with `Tmax` (2 bytes, in vars, default is 2pi)

Comment: I seem to have miscounted an extra power of `10`. You can check out the implementation for the tetration calculations at the end of the question.

Answer (score 1):

## TI-Basic, \$10 \uparrow\uparrow 5.0039\$ <sub><sup>(I think)</sup></sub>, 100 bytes

```
{π,Xmax→L₁
Ans→L₂
LinReg(ax+b) Y₁
Equ▸String(Y₁,Str1
If not(N
sub(Str1,Xscl,Xscl→Str2
Σx
For(J,-Ans,Ans
Ans+Ans→A
End
For(I,I-A,I-Xscl
IS>(N,A
prgmD
DS<(N,Z
Str2+Str2→Str2
End
Ans
```

a [fresh interpreter](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/52967/98541)/calculator is needed, or with the following constants initialized:

```
N,Z,I = 0
Xscl = 1
Xmin = -10
Xmax = 10
```

- I don't have a TI-84 CE, so I used [this method](http://tibasicdev.wikidot.com/number-to-string) to get a number in a string, the results is `"1"` in `Str2`
- for each iteration in the loop, another program is spawned until depth `A` and `Str2` is doubled
- `Σx` is the sum of `L₁` (`10+π`)
- here, \$ A = (10+π) × 2^{27} = 1763834708\$
- in practice, my TI-84+ SE doesn't have enough memory for A=3

#### Trying to calculate my score

A more minimal code to analyze would be:

```
For(I,I-A,I-1
IS>(N,A
prgmD
DS<(N,0
B+1→B
End
```

with `I` and `B` initialized to zero and one respectively

- [`For(`](http://tibasicdev.wikidot.com/for): `I` will take the values `I-A` to `I-1` included, and will be equal to `I` after the loop
- [`IS>(`](http://tibasicdev.wikidot.com/is): increments `N` and skips `prgmD` if `N>A`. `N` tracks the depth of the function so that it stops at depth `A+1`
- [`DS<(`](http://tibasicdev.wikidot.com/ds): very similar, decrements `N`, and never skip the next line in this case

$$B = \sum_{I=0}^{A+1}(A^I) = \frac{A^{A+2}-1}{A-1} \approx A^A$$

`B` is the number of times the length of `Str2` is doubled, giving the number:

$$1.111 \times 10^{2^B} ≈ 10^{2^{A^A}} 
\approx 10^{2^{(1.7 \times 10^9)^{1.7 \times 10^9}}}
\approx 10^{10^{10^{10^{10.2124}}}}
\approx 10 \uparrow\uparrow 5.0039
$$

#### Edit:

- I was using `cosh(` which is kinda cheating, but now I allowed myself to use `Xmin` and `Xmax` (-10 and 10)

  My previous score was \$ 10 \uparrow\uparrow 5.03 \$ with `cosh(cosh(Tmax→A` (\$ 3.6 \times 10^{11}\$)
- \$ 10 \uparrow\uparrow 4.913 \rightarrow 10 \uparrow\uparrow 5.0039\$ for using `Σx` instead of `Xmax`

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3, score \$\approx 10 \uparrow\uparrow 3.45913\$

```python
a=ord("~")
print(eval(f"'{a}'*"+f"{a}"*a+f"{a}"*a))
```

The result overflows python, and I don't know how to calculate the score.

Here, + means string concatenation, and * is string repetition.

Comment: You are aware that 999 contains digits, aren't you?

Comment: @pxeger oops, fixed

Comment: `"126" * n` is approximately \$0.126126\ldots\times10^{3n}\$, which is how you can estimate your score.

Answer (score 1):

## [Nim](https://nim-lang.org/), 100 bytes

```
import math
let c=uint(' ')
for i in c-c..(uint('#')-c)^c:stdout.write i,i,i,i,i,i,i,i,i,i,i,i,i,i,i
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m704LzN3wYKlpSVpuhY3UzJzC_KLShRyE0syuHJSSxSSbUsz80o01BXUNbnS8osUMhUy8xSSdZP19DQgEsrqmrrJmnHJVsUlKfmlJXrlRZklqQqZOnggxC6olTCrAQ)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 95 bytes, score \$\approx 10 \uparrow\uparrow 2.72087\$

```python
a=ord("~")
g="a<<"
c=eval(g+"a<<"+"<<".join("a"*a))
b=len(str(c))
print(eval("<<".join("b"*a)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P9E2vyhFQ6lOSZMr3VYp0cZGiSvZNrUsMUcjXRvM1VYCEnpZ@Zl5GkqJSlqJmppcSbY5qXkaxSVFGslAXkFRZl6JBlgLktIksFLN//8B)

Comment: `x << y << z` is just `x << (y + z)`, so we have `c = 126 << (126 * 127) ~ 1.52181e4819`. This makes `b = 4820` and the final result is `4820 << (4820 * 125) ~ 1.80067e181374`, or \$10\uparrow\uparrow3.72087\$.

Comment: Miscounted the number of \$10\$'s. You can try out the above calculations using the implementation added to the end of the question: `a = TetrationDecimal(126); c = a * 2 ** (a * (a + 1)); b = int(log(c, 10)) + 1; result = b * 2 ** (b * (a - 1))`.

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth, score \$\approx f_{\psi(\Omega_\omega)+\omega}(5)/92^3\$

```
D:GHNR?qHGN?G,:hGHN:@GhZHNZL?hb:,yhb@bhZ@bhZ,yhb@bhZ@bhZKCGFYKFdKFkKFQKFzKFTK=J,JZ;WJ=hK=yJK
```

This is essentially a port of [Patcail's program](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/139355/golf-a-number-bigger-than-tree3) to Pyth.

I added some layers of recursion boosting it from \$\psi(\Omega_\omega)\$ to \$\psi(\Omega_\omega)+5\$ (I kind of ran out of variables to use for the loops).

The function `y` is exactly the same as Patcail's `P`, while the `:` is a helper function to do the substitution.

Also for golfy reasons the code does print out multiple numbers (over \$f_{\psi(\Omega_\omega)+\omega}(5)\$ numbers, in fact). Also 0 and 1 are used as `Z` and `hZ` (should be legal, since `h` is just addition and `Z` is a constant less than 10). Given that Steven uses `CG` I also used it in this program.

Answer (score 1):

## Python, \$\frac{f_{127}(2047)}{1000000}\$ where \$f_0(n)=n+1\$ and \$f_x(n)=f_{x-1}^n(n)\$ (superscript means function repetition)

```python
f=lambda x,y:-~y if not x else[y:=f(~-x,y)for _ in range(y)][-g("")]
g=ord
print(f(g(""),g("߿")))
```

First `g` contains the character `0x01`, second `g` contains the character `0x7f`.

Grows quite quickly \$(f_3(3)\text{ already has 121 million digits!})\$

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/P802JzE3KSVRoUKn0kq3rlIhM00hL79EoUIhNac4NbrSyjZNo04XKKmZll@kEK@QmadQlJiXnqpRqRkbrZuuocSopBnLlW6bX5TCVVCUmVeikaYBFK1X0tQBUvf3K2lqav7/DwA)

<s>If anyone knows the name of the function \$f\$, please leave a comment</s> It’s the fast-growing hierarchy.

### Individual hex values (hexdump)

```
0x0066 0x003d 0x006c 0x0061 0x006d 0x0062 0x0064 0x0061 0x0020 0x0078 0x002c 0x0079 0x003a 0x002d 0x007e 0x0079 0x0020 0x0069 0x0066 0x0020 0x006e 0x006f 0x0074 0x0020 0x0078 0x0020 0x0065 0x006c 0x0073 0x0065 0x005b 0x0079 0x003a 0x003d 0x0066 0x0028 0x007e 0x002d 0x0078 0x002c 0x0079 0x0029 0x0066 0x006f 0x0072 0x0020 0x005f 0x0020 0x0069 0x006e 0x0020 0x0072 0x0061 0x006e 0x0067 0x0065 0x0028 0x0079 0x0029 0x005d 0x005b 0x002d 0x0067 0x0028 0x0022 0x0001 0x0022 0x0029 0x005d 0x000a 0x0067 0x003d 0x006f 0x0072 0x0064 0x000a 0x0070 0x0072 0x0069 0x006e 0x0074 0x0028 0x0066 0x0028 0x0067 0x0028 0x0022 0x007f 0x0022 0x0029 0x002c 0x0067 0x0028 0x0022 0x07ff 0x0022 0x0029 0x0029 0x0029
```

[Generated using a short and simple script I made.](https://tio.run/##RY5BqsIwGIRxaU/x003@n9cWURdSyElKkUqSNlKTkuRBsvEd7R3Fo9QUF66GmYGZb0lhsuZ0Wdw6yXidpRnDBBzOq34s1gXwyRfKOoigzWYaH4Q2jZODQGqL/eK0CcgOkf3kAbROYCTqjm3fuPuvD/idrdiBUSWN4AwYravi8/C4iQFildr6mUArMDbkKzl72aWWK3zWuaQN4LoBuMGMEhP1XT1iuSupL0aeP4sPhsKc/pVUZXn9l0T0Bg)

Comment: [97 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/P802JzE3KSVRoUKn0kq3rlIhM02hwsYwNac4NbrSyjZNo04XKKOZll@kEK@QmadQlJiXnqpRqRkbrZuuocSopBnLlW6bX5TCVVCUmVeikaYBFK1X0tQBUvf3K2lqav7/DwA)

Answer (score 1):

## Swift 5.9, 93 chars, 96 bytes, \$\frac{1.22333444 \times 10^{10,687,082,584}}{884,736}\$

(I... can't be bothered to calculate that right now.)

```swift
for i in.zero...UnicodeScalar("").value{print({String.init}()("\(i)",Int(i)),terminator:"")}
```

Ungolfed and commented:

```swift
// UnicodeScalar("").value == UInt32(65536)
for i in .zero...UnicodeScalar("").value {
  print(
    // {String.init}()(_:_:) is equivalent to String(repeating:count:)
    {String.init}()(
      "\(i)", // equivalent to String(describing: i)
      Int(i) // i is a UInt32, so we need to cast it
    ),
    terminator: "" // terminator is a newline by default, we don't want that
  )
}
```

It's possible to change the  to the last valid Unicode character (U+10FFFF = `1114111`), but I didn't bother because, quite frankly, it would take too long.

[Okay now do the fiddly thing. Just be prepared to wait all week.](https://swiftfiddle.com/gg43cbi5izeplaz4tg6t5mr6le)

Comment: scoring seems correct.

Comment: in terms of tetration, this is \$10 ^^ 2.631333717740654\$

Comment: I don't know Swift, but could you use [`Int.max`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/int/max)?

Comment: @noodleman I *could*, but that would be breaking the rule against integer constants greater than 10.

Comment: Ah, forgot about that one.

Answer (score 0):

## C++ - 101 bytes

This runs for exactly 5 seconds - you can't see it, but I have the ASCII character for 5 in there:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<ctime>
int main(){for(int n=time(NULL);time(NULL)<n+'';)std::cout<<n;}
```

I wouldn't know how large the number is - large enough that my computer wouldn't be able to calculate my score.  I ran this program outputting the number into .txt file, and it produced a file of 16.585 MB.

Screenshot of code in text document:

[image: Image of code.]

Comment: Rule 5 says that you can't use `^` or the equivalent library calls.

Comment: Oh dear, guess I'd better re-work it.

Comment: @KyleKanos Fixed, is this better?

Comment: Nope, it has several digits in the code.

Comment: @KyleKanos This better now?

Comment: @Hand-E-Food Is this fixed?

Comment: Looks better to me :)

Comment: I don't know **`C++`**... can you combine the *`#include`* statements like: *`"#include<iostream> <ctime>"`* or *`"#include<iostream>,<ctime>"`* ???

Comment: @KevinFegan Not that I have ever heard of.

Comment: I count 99 characters including 2-newlines. Calculate score: (N)=output number. log10(N)=16585000. (99^3)=970299. log10(970299)=5.98690558. Score=10^(16585000-5.98690558)=10^(16584994.01309442). This will be a close approximation. Better: (H)=first (high) digit of (N). (Z)=actual captured-filesize (# of digits). If (H) is less than 5, use (Z-1). Substitute (Z) [or Z-1] for 16585000 above. Better yet: From (Z), subtract 1. Then add log10(H). Substitute (Z-1+log10(H)) for 16585000 above. Still approximate but quite close.

Comment: Replace `time(NULL)` with `time(0)` to save six characters. Since you include the header file, the compiler sees the prototype and knows that `time` takes a pointer. In pointer contexts, `0` will be treated as the null pointer.

Comment: @DavidConrad I can't.  The rules specify no digits in the code.

Comment: Whoops, I forgot. I guess I didn't think of the 0 as a number when it was representing a NULL pointer, but obviously, the rules disallow it.

Comment: If you can explain how your number works for those who don't use C++, I might be able to analyze the result.

Comment: Also, can we get this below 100 bytes?

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt It prints the POSIX timestamp at the moment the program is run, repeatedly, in a tight loop, for 5 seconds.

Comment: Uh, then does the output change depending on when you run the program?

Comment: If I understand it correctly, your score would be something along the lines of `1.5e9 * number_of_loops`. Suppose there are about 1000 loops in 5 seconds, then your score would be `1.5e12`.

Answer (score 0):

## C, ??? (91 characters)

```
main(int d,char**v){long c='\t'-'\b';for(;c;c++)for(d-=d;(*v)[d];d++)printf("%llu",(*v)[d]);}
```

If I could use `^`, I'd write `d^=d`, but alas.

Run through `argv[0]` and print its contents as an `unsigned long long`.Repeat 2<sup>long</sup>-1 times.

Since `argv[0]` is the program's path, I'd assume the smallest possible value printed by this program (on Windows) would be `A:\ .com` with a 32 bit `long`. I'm not so sure on that though, smaller paths are probably possible.

Comment: You can as ^ is xor operator, not exponentiation.

Answer (score 0):

This is madness, to print the number it must be in the memory somehow, otherwise it would be considered as printing many separate numbers. I've written a **JavaScript** code and I've launched it in **FireBug console**. The largest result I've get with following code, on the quite strong workstation (8Core, 8GB RAM, haven't noted more details):

The code:

```
var e=Math.E,s=(e+'').replace('.',''),b=parseInt(s)
try{for(var i=e;i<b;i+=i)s+=s}catch(e){}
s
```

Code length: 94 characters (counted newlines as 1, you can replace them with semicolons and then it will be undoubtly 1). 94^3=830584. 
Test generated: '2718281828459045' repeated so many times, that the length of s was 1073741824 (over 1GB allocated). So the number is 2,7182*10^1073741824, and the points are:

**3,27*10^1073741817**

You can try to do that, but Firefox on my home laptop has crashed, so you need a really strong machine.

But many people has written the snipplets, noone has reported to be able to run! So let's remove that try.. catch and analyse what theoretically could happen:

The code:

```
var e=Math.E,s=(e+'').replace('.',''),b=parseInt(s);for(var i=e;i<b;i+=i)s+=s;s
```

Code length: 79 characters, 79^3=493039
The code will make 50 iterations generating the string of the length of 18014398509481984. Please verify if it would be able to store on 64 bit machine, but because the string is duplicated, there could be a theoretical machine able to compress such items in memory. However, I have no idea if there is enough energy in solar system to display the whole number on any console...

Anyway, we have number 2,7182*10^18014398509481984 divided by 79^3, so the poins are:

**5,5*10^18014398509481977**

Fill free to correct any mathematical errors, I've became a typical coding machine :D

Comment: In answer to your first statement: `You can concatenate strings: this means that any sequence of adjacent digits will be considered as a single number;`

Answer (score 0):

### MATLAB ???/53^3

In matlab the maximum character size is defined and therefore this program will terminate eventually.

Basically it starts like this:

```
9
(9)!
((9)!)!
(((9)!)!)!    
...
```

I have no clue how big the number is but this will be allowed to grow to a string with approximately 2^41-1 elements (on windows 64 bit). Some help in estimating the resulting number size would be appreciated.

```
s=char('z'-'A')
while true
   s=['(' s ')!']
   vpa(s)
end
```

Comment: `1` is a digit, so is `2`!

Comment: @Vereos Edit: Thanks I did not even notice, have found a way around them!

Comment: This doesn't mean that those solutions are valid indeed. If you look at the leaderboard, you'll see that no solution in there has digits in it. **EDIT:** Alright :)

Comment: The code at the bottom is an invalid program (non-terminating) and 9 is a digit.

Answer (score 0):

### PHP (a lot)/83^3

Script should run for 99 seconds and produce as much `9`'s concatenated as it can.

```
$n=strlen("alphabeta");ini_set('max_execution_time',intval($n.$n));while($n)echo$n;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Squeak Smalltalk cheat: > 2^^(2^30) / 71^3 chars**

```
^((Float pi at:Float e)to:(Float e at:Float e))reduceRight:[:x :y|x<<y]
```

Little explanation:

- Internal bit representation of a Float can be accessed as a pair of 32 bit BigEndian words (a cheat)
- #at: is tolerant and retries its parameter #asInteger (oh, not nice!)
- << is left shift (a perfect cheat)
- evaluate this expression via 'print it' menu, and the resulted number is printed in base 10

With characters left, I could also use significandAsInteger, but these are big enough yet. How big?

- `(Float pi at:Float e)` -> 1413754136 > 2^31
- `(Float e  at:Float e)` -> 2333366121 > 2^31
- `((Float pi at:Float e)to:(Float e at:Float e)) size` -> 919611986>2^30

The first iteration is greater than 2^31*2^(2^31) > 2^^5
The second iteration is greater than 2^31*2^(2^^5) > 2^^6
...
The 2^30th iteration is greater than 2^^(2^30)

I let readers do the conversion to base 10, That kind of number gives me some vertigos...

Since this number is represented in memory, then converted to decimal by way of multiplications and divisions, let's say it's highly hypothetical...
Anyway, the technique consisting in storing the number in memory (base 2) then print, especially in Squeak is completely disqualified...
Creating a very small number is fast:
`[1<<15000000] timeToRun` -> 4 (milliseconds)
But LargeInteger package is not based on gmp and rapidly inefficient for base 10 conversion (naive * and /)
Even if I install a karatsuba multiplication, it takes quite long to print on my mac mini:
`[1<<15000000 printOn: NullStream new] bench` -> '2,700 seconds.'

**A more reasonable loop in 32-bit memory:**

What I can really execute is the first loop (let's omit the -1 on first term):

`[((Float e at:Float e)<<(Float e at:Float e))] timeToRun` -> 8732 (milliseconds)

As said above, I can 'do it' but I can't 'print it' in reasonable time with Squeak, though I can manipulate it, like having a guess of number of decimal digits:

`((((Float e at:Float e)<<(Float e at:Float e))  highBit - 1) * 1233 >> 12) + 1`-> 702402458, or log: 10 -> 10^(10^8.8)

Answer (score 0):

## C, undetermined (infinite?) output length / <s>62^3</s> 67^3

```
l(){printf("%o",rand())-!!l&&l();}main(){srand(time(!l));l();}
```

```
l(){for(;printf("%o",rand())-!!l;l());}main(){srand(time(!l));l();}
```

I'd written this a few days prior, but was having a hard time figuring out the expected average length of the output. The program (given enough stack and time) eventually will terminate.

Was going to post when I figured the output length, but since [Nate Eldridge's](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/18028/largest-number-printable/18597#18597) is similar, posting it now.

Originally had `!'!'` instead of `!l`; borrowed that part from Nate's answer.

I also had a similar version without srand, at <s>42</s> 48 characters:

```
main(){printf("%o",rand())-!!'!'&&main();}
```

```
main(){for(;printf("%o",rand())-!!'!';main());}
```

Mine terminate (on average) earlier, compared to Nate's (`10/RAND_MAX` chance of popping up the stack instead of `1/RAND_MAX`), but output more digits per iteration (~10.43 vs 1).

Edit: original actually terminated after `RAND_MAX/20` iterations on average. Golfed too far.

Edit2: not enough rep to comment. Golfed Nate's entries below mine (64 and 44):

```
w(){for(printf("%o",w);rand();w());}main(){srand(time(!w));w();}
```

```
main(){for(printf("%o",'I');rand();main());}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Javascript, > 10<sup>316469</sup> ≈ 10↑↑2.740388839

(Run from the browser console to get output)

```js
for(a="",b="￭".charCodeAt``;b--;)a+=(''+b).repeat("￭".charCodeAt``);a
```

Answer (score 0):

## R, 63 characters of code, 4.036242e+3699695 ≈ 10↑↑2.81744412

```
set.seed(T)
paste(rep(RS<-abs(.Random.seed),RS[exp(T)]),collapse="")
# the result will be 3699696 digits long
# 624 repetitions of 4036241692704834420106146035583972223....
```

... or you can have it printing for as long as you have time:

```
set.seed(T)
repeat{cat(abs(.Random.seed),sep="")}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Lua, Unknown/99^3 ≈ 10↑↑2.945956159

With infinite runtime:

```lua
m=math;p=m.pi;t=m.floor(p)s=tostring;h=t+s(p):sub(t)j=h;while(j>t)do io.write(s(h):rep(h))j=j-t;end
```

< 5 seconds:

```lua
m=math;p=m.pi;t=m.ceil(p)s=tostring;h=t+s(p):sub(-t)j=h;while(j>t)do io.write(s(h):rep(h))j=j-t;end
```

Ungolfed:

```lua
t=math.ceil(math.pi)                -- Acquire the number 4
h=t+tostring(math.pi):sub(-t)       -- Get the last t(4) digits of pi(5898) as a string.
                                    -- Adding t auto converts it to a number and increases our number
j=h;                                -- Set j as a counter to loop
while(j>t)do
    io.write(tostring(h):rep(h))    -- Add h(5902) repitions of h as a string to the output
    j=j-t;                          -- Decrement j by t(4), my only number available
end
```

### Extra

Lua's lack of mathematical constants (other than pi) and ++ or -- operators made it tricky to manipulate numbers, but I thought I made good work with what I have. string.rep is the real hero.

If there's a notation that exists to write my score, I'll include it, but I don't know of one. If I was thinking correctly, the < 5 code's number should be (5902 repeated 5902 times) repeated ~5902/4 times.

Comment: Hello! What does this program do?

Comment: @NoOneIsHere Added ungolfed code with explanation. That should help.

Comment: If your last line is correct, your number should be ≈10^174,000,000

Answer (score 0):

## Mathematica, 1.08544407066*10^23496 ≈ 10↑↑2.640580269

```
N[Cosh[Cosh[Cosh[Pi]]]]
```

It applies the hyperbolic cosine function to pi 3 times. If I had applied it 4 times, it would've caused an overflow error.

Comment: Overflow error should not be a problem here.

Comment: `N[Cosh[Cosh[Cosh[Cosh[Cosh[Cosh[Cosh[Cosh[Cosh[Cosh[Pi]]]]]]]]]]]`.

Answer (score 0):

### [Pxem](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Pxem), 99 bytes, score: \$\approx2.63\times10^{22183}=10\uparrow\uparrow2.63809\$.

Unprintables are escaped.

```
.z\377.n\001.+.c\377\377.+\377.+\377.+\377.+\377.+\377.+\377.+\377.+\377.+\377.+\377.+\377.+\377.+\377.+\377.+\377.+\377.+\377.+\377.+\377.+\377.+\377.+\377.+\377.+\377.+\377.+\377.+\377.+.a.n
```

I think it could be more, with x-ple loops.

Output: \$(255\sum_{k=0}^{7394}{1000^k})\times10000+7395\$ (I think)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVh7V@K6Fv/fTxE6lSa0pQ2CIrUqA16Hc5TxNS5HQFehRcFSOLQoWjhffe5OWgTK3FnXtbTJbz@zH3n44j//@vKl6Oxbnb2O0851cztFe0/f3e0UbH230G1bXd3Wc/mCXijQwpbvBEh1JsZkYPkvSNdzOcOZjobjAJ1VHstnZ2bFwMH7yEFPTtAZet10ms86w8HA8mxyqNnOq@ZNXBflDtM0nY6FL8o330xBxDEfUkcLBZxExJB95NI8GqhzYWH2R71293h9UzVzur6zAC@@X9fuzn4@Vr5fXZ1UbkxqNJAghl/L198eb0@urmvf6yX5fS4gE72jVjrNVzVEo6Hfm0Yz@Wskcv8/JJzBxLUCB/nPnH84CmD4Nhzb/sjtBem05fYsH6lPSBJDKgvisTCXTIl9pXS6/uPsrHJeNUvcBmb2bMN/7nUDg48R44sBp/M8ROIXwixTZjkFhnJD1z5MQ@hfLRcJKdS1XN8RZrNVGlfNpacz37GR5GtT7V0zfPjzoUlc4QdqMSHOBTwL0Q4meAhJKHtIfQ0mdBaMkVrxUbOhq/stJDWaXqYlzZ7GzghlI@XaQ35X1MJS2RDbRt3Qmh6fX4C5h2y26Wma0S4b82jaeGB6KM2J2kgzglWwqG9ilFJRGybAvf1NjFKQ9pKMxU2M6gVR6yUZdzaxfeB7TGJguZPAdvc2MUpB2E@ub2cToxRcfE0y7m5iVIeIdZNu65sY1SFiTtLH/U2M0ryojZOmc5sYpSD9lmTc28RoDvyZJhmLmxjNgY/vScb9TYzmwJ@PZBL032DgjpVcdGEToxRiGyQt5zcxqoM7g2S89zYxqoM7dtJ0cRPLQ/rlJAYuqglsB/hSSQy8FpMYOLPNsLk0wx0r3i5sEjcl71ctPGVNOTVs6L9TJt3E2SZp4qbH/mYzTSJqzZ1mrkk14PK1bAa6dbre3yXXEFOh1nibvn9YdktLhXWj7YLCufEOza4hzdAaDzGVlbioIVtb06F6SIrNNx6OlRbYBQ9wIxqCC7ljxFx4jnkiHGUzQOKeRdZhPSPupqgpDG2DC5DiEGap0IdRWRsZ7UtAIzblGBR8MtqfjLZWXTCusS0ocRxKY0MMI3PHiKmGLY5zo/ICCco8tGKqDpSm10DqRytjM23BeAWBJfH4tKLFapxkAduI5zRanBVJzcHb0uWnyiz3LbhM7LlxPL5BZKpliMs0Ti6P7DJuUXxOY038N3Il8iTO@u8EJbQ4OlYSovW62LXajmuaQpMKJOQrwY3R0Os9dvzXrjMOBnJK3FZbjLtJMTG0p4iH1WMzpEpzzkgXuEljmrXqkj9pY4ElRFCY9BGMhZJwLCjcLJnHBtf5/8RcFbX22LFe@ATyVsaCOxyOkDcM0MAKOs8970kAVmmxXBkTrY0p4b6pfKLGsxSf6dFEhMk/i8k2nzA2aEbeiFJ3OI5jBR4ZBgkl47NLpblEyK//1MvnJ6aU/Wju7O1lvaau06yc7bAZXBfwlvX2gqSvJ6e1esiUGT1ZPsgVDTIa97ygKzS5mAy3iy2StbKesFX5Xr85qd@YkrSFIya4CHArYkwSZm8dpHYIHPW//HHHjNVDWmXfcWzij@EKhvlw3p14naA39NAFrpLwuvGi/I1Jy6waMGzJ8pJ@gkk4doLJ2EMpGXiWlL@WFMAP6ZLy95LC1C0JN2sEZlKlK@Q7fEXCKxO4uBuqasTMV0ueCa6QkK8fVZboKb5S7j91wxXT7XnOoX4k6iV1xbFvkQGRGry0HnjdylBhgkDWIBRBm@Z/MPMTz1yxXcbnC4/OZwKUAcSfXWN7AVoxPYKlvz33XAenIKRkuBpJmIQAzmYTfAe0JcHDNeVWqSouYVnkguGtCTyGa7qO9xQ841tisPqpwV24dmC6BplgXDVhLX4wxrdKTZYVSsi/Al@XcFSV88VSvkDmSyM9sH6BT9cMP@JzpaLcKz9JeG4K2ccSqkNLWch2Or0B3E1hsc6TM4bvaBIIRsUEceMefOC1bHB383sHlXS6clAoEt6kBmCVf4WHfGOn0BJhf7k383m1EgtHfQwsuBiJ0TwEpGKaOzkSRizwbAh63sSZs4gz1spBvgg8h4U9wqDI@NJspJn8NPFPgipqvmiw7BkX@D7zc2WtnUX0L/DNWhD8BeFuNVmvkJO@ckvCmqlzi32T1zGEv8/KVumrasu8ZYlis1qLg5CHFp/3WyuhHy9NQ0Qx70@SYTWwYvBt2TSb3kzxpcJtpaAdWYRTMLvkJXJrXh4w3lj2din0/kehw98LfXy6waS4G@qaK8FiMc/Qu@YaaQCkFygWBK@qC8zoK8Q2tiCgUYn/xSr8AltHIC5bLBKluzgixnLHyJhUzWWwdaCTDMsZfFeC@k9SXz/umLt4sbifcQlUDJgRsttwqGShGoUSunfGcMfqvfZ8UCOwQmFJsY76h@5Rf9studv9Eh9rfAw5mkc7LHhm6i0oB7azr@/NwqxDBGnpXBciscb1uXdvPsz@8C4zowMtukXAJQ0OOPY@VsfeC511JjCyJSQhtZtbnHxw6bnAacIeiCvuOLyYoxM1hMLlBf0iy4Ys9w8w24RZ0ULIo/D34ykMiPH7ZbDl2o7rwBsa8gytEG9P0CCyXDsAcZlGLcFPmhrXKFPok2jTl6N5ay4Z7KRi/zyAa1YH8X8wTFiHDAfsuQzgeANcxtDOI7WeX2OYzfAInu7lIRr1bMUJegNHGXVGE@XV/zBsePST1Rzk//w4RoHVc@Hqm18JMLt@h0V2BeIXLWnGznj1FVmmmqP5vXxxZzdfRFJoyaaoz0/q1fjUsODCIGz93/mPtcbRYR8BEgAHvsBJkqjD/Q1@BORH6cHC9lBQRJ1Is6k1foIY1KYoztx0C/36Lw)

Comment: Also I need to re-improve my interpreter so that it outputs faster, like before.

Comment: "You cannot use digits in your code (0123456789);" >_>

Comment: @simplybeautifulart Actual source: `.zÿ.n.+.cÿÿ.+ÿ.+ÿ.+ÿ.+ÿ.+ÿ.+ÿ.+ÿ.+ÿ.+ÿ.+ÿ.+ÿ.+ÿ.+ÿ.+ÿ.+ÿ.+ÿ.+ÿ.+ÿ.+ÿ.+ÿ.+ÿ.+ÿ.+ÿ.+ÿ.+ÿ.+ÿ.+ÿ.+.a.n`; see, no digits can be seen. Also this was obtained when I exported `LC_ALL=C`.

Comment: Also I obtained on TIO, where UTF-8 is default.

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 99 bytes, score not sure

```python
x,e,a=ord("~"),eval,"f(~-n)"
f=lambda n:x if n<x-(x<<x)else f(~-e("<<".join("a"*e(a))))
print(f(x))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcoxDoMwDADAnVdEnmwUWLoh8xgjHDUodRBFyF34etrefPvnfFZ7tOZRo8z1WBFuoKiXlAgJ78EIujQXeS2rBJs85BSMfUBndtLy1vBvisAM41azIQj0ikI/3X5kOzGhE7X2BQ)

Comment: Pretty certain you just have infinite recursion here, your `f(n)` calls `f(...)` for values much greater than `n`.

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 99 bytes, score \$ \approx 10 \uparrow\uparrow 4.74238\$

```python
a=ord("")
for i in[a]*(a<<a):print(end=str(eval(f"{a}<<{str(eval('<<'.join('a'*(a<<a))))}"*a)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P9E2vyhFQ@lL//79SppcaflFCpkKmXnRibFaGok2NomaVgVFmXklGql5KbbFJUUaqWWJORppStWJtTY21XABdRsbdb2s/Mw8DfVEdahGIKhV0gLR//8DAA)

Answer (score 0):

## Python, \$\approx 10 \uparrow \uparrow 11.20322\$

So, let's start with some simple left shifting:

`l=lambda n:-~(n<<n)`

Pretty tame. Obviously, \$l(n) = 2^n n+1\$.

Now, we'll combine more left shifting with recursion:

`m=lambda n:-~(n<<n<<l(l(n)))`

Now, running the calculations, \$m(n) = 2^{2^{2^n n+1} (2^n n+1)+1} 2^n n\$.

Another layer of shifting:

`o=lambda n:n<<n<<n<<m(m(m(n)))`

This is getting unwieldy! MathJax won't even render the formula! My final code returns \$o(126)\$. It is the following:

```
l=lambda n:-~(n<<n)
m=lambda n:-~(n<<n<<l(l(n)))
o=lambda n:n<<n<<n<<m(m(m(n)))
print(o(ord("~")))
```

Comment: One of the restrictions is to not use digits (e.g. `0` and `1`) in your code. There are various workarounds to this e.g. using `len("abc")` or `ord(unicode_character)`.

Comment: Oh. I thought it meant decimal, but I'll fix it.

Comment: For sufficiently large \$x\$, \$m(10\uparrow\uparrow x)\approx10\uparrow\uparrow(x+3)\$. The extra `<< m(...)` adds on one more power of \$10\$, and some work with the base case gives \$l(l(126))\approx10^{10^{10^{10^{0.20322}}}}=10\uparrow\uparrow4.20322\$, which altogether gives \$10\uparrow\uparrow12.20322\$.

Comment: Oh, really? Hypercalc gave me 10^^8, but even better then!

Comment: I have no idea how hypercalc handles arithmetic underneath, but I just used full machine precision and some exponential rules to work your stuff out. I added an implementation you can try out at the bottom of the question, though you'll have to change `x << y` to `x * 2 ** y` or add `__lshift__` and `__rshift__` methods.

Comment: Also I miscounted the amount of \$10\$'s, so this is actually \$10\uparrow\uparrow11.20322\$.

Answer (score 0):

## Python 3, score \$ \approx 10 \uparrow\uparrow 23.98622 \$

```py
from math import *
x=pi;e=exp
for i in range(int(e(x))):x=e(x)
x=int(x)
print(str(x)*x)
```

### Explanation

1. Initialize `x` as pi.
2. Repeat 23 times (`int(e(x))` = 23): `x = e(x)`.

This ends up as e^(e^(e^(...e^pi...))), with 23 "e^"s.

3. Round down.
4. Convert it to a string and repeat that string `x` times. I have no idea how much larger this makes the number, but it is much larger.

Sorry, I really have no idea how large this number is (even with up-arrow notation) or how to calculate that. :/ Mostly this answer was just to see what I could do. :)

Comment: Using the program linked at the end of the question, you can estimate your score as `10 ^^ 23.98622`, where `e(x)` is taken as `math.e ** x` and `str(x) * x` is approximately `x ** x`.

Comment: Oh thanks! Sorry I didn't notice that link.

Answer (score 0):

## Python, at least \$10\uparrow\uparrow13\$ or \$10\uparrow\uparrow\uparrow 2\$

```python
f=lambda x:''.join(str(x)for y in range(int(x)))
print(f(f(f(f(f(f(f(f(f(f(f(f(ord(""))))))))))))))
```

Unprintable character in `ord` function is `0x7f`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/P802JzE3KSVRocJKXV0vKz8zT6O4pEijQjMtv0ihUiEzT6EoMS89VSMzrwQoqKnJVVAEYqbhgPlFKRpK9UqaKOD/fwA)

Comment: Isn't that function body just equivalent to `str(x)*int(x)`?

Comment: @JoKing yes but I can't use multiplication.

Comment: right, i suppose that would apply to string multiplication as well

Answer (score 0):

## [Itr](https://github.com/bsoelch/OneChar.js/blob/main/ItrLang.md),  approximately \$f_{\omega^3+f_{\omega^3}(191)}(f_{\omega^3}(191))\$

(newlines only for readability)

```
»áF»»Fä«°«¡«$©N
»»+ä«N©«$©a
"««¡N©"$r
»'aáF»"»»"à°r°«©«$©b
»'báF»"»»"à°r°«©«$©c
'¿c»c«N©
```

### Explanation

`a` is the function form the previous solution with with `n` applications of `äF` to `ä+` so \$a(n) \approx 2↑^nn \approx f_{\omega}(n)\$ in the fast-growing hierarchy.

The innermost layer of `b` (`»»a««¡N©`) applies `a` n-times to the input giving \$f_{\omega+n}(n) = f_{2\omega}(n)\$

The next layer will apply that function n-times to its own result giving \$f_{2\omega+n}(n) = f_{3\omega}(n)\$,

`b` does this `n` times, therefore \$b(n)\$ should be approximately \$ f_{n·\omega}(n) = f_{\omega^2}(n)\$.

`c` does the same thing as `b` but with `b` instead of `a` so \$c(n) \approx f_{n·\omega^2}(n) = f_{\omega^3}(n)\$

the last line applies `c` `c(191)` times to `c(191)`

## Itr, score at least \$2↑^{48}126\$

using only constants, loops and linear functions.

```
'~äFäFäFäFäFäFäFäFäFäFäFäFäFäFäFäFäFäFäFäFäFäFäFäFäFäFäFäFäFäFäFäFäFäFäFäFäFäFäFäFäFäFäFäFäFäFäFäFä+
```

### Explanation

The `'~` at the start pushes the constant `126` (it is possible to increase the number by replacing `~` with the byte `0xbf = 191`, but this would not make any significant impact on the total result while needing non-printable bytes)

Each `äF` applies the next function `n` times to `n` where `n` is the value currently on the stack.

`ä+` will double the value that is currently on the stack, so the last `äFä+` computes \$F_0(k)=2^k*k \approx 2↑k\$

Each `äF` now repeatedly applies the previous function to its own result, so `äFäFe` computes \$F_1(k) = {F_0}^k(k) \approx 2↑2 ... 2↑k \approx 2 ↑↑ k \$.

Each additional `äF` adds one additional arrow, so the final result should have the same order of magnitude as \$2↑^{48}126\$, dividing by `100³` will not significantly change that number.

Answer (score 0):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `D`, at least \$42781\underbrace{!!!!!…}_{42781\underbrace{!!!…}_{42781}\$

```
`\ꜝC`\¡\ꜝC¡¡¡¡¡¡¡¡¡¡¡¡¡¡¡¡¡¡¡¡¡¡¡¡¡¡¡¡¡¡¡¡¡¡¡¡¡¡¡¡¡¡¡¡¡¡¡¡¡¡¡¡¡¡¡¡¡¡¡¡¡¡ẋ+Ė→`\`\ꜝC\`\¡`←ẋ←`ẋ+Ė`←ẋ++Ė
```

I basically used factorial and string repetition to get some very large number. Outputs a `RecursionError` in the online interpreter, which it seems to do when  you factorial a very very big number.

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2#WyJEIiwiIiwiYFxc6pydQ2BcXMKhXFzqnJ1DwqHCocKhwqHCocKhwqHCocKhwqHCocKhwqHCocKhwqHCocKhwqHCocKhwqHCocKhwqHCocKhwqHCocKhwqHCocKhwqHCocKhwqHCocKhwqHCocKhwqHCocKhwqHCocKhwqHCocKhwqHCocKhwqHCocKhwqHCocKhwqHCoeG6iyvEluKGkmBcXGBcXOqcnUNcXGBcXMKhYOKGkOG6i+KGkGDhuosrxJZg4oaQ4bqLKyvEliIsIiIsIiJd)

Comment: I've removed the excess MathJax. It would also be nice if you provided a more accurate score or at least some lower bound.

Comment: For me to remember: 42781

Answer (score -1):

Python2

```
o=oct(ord('~'))
for a in range(int(o)):
    o+=o*int(o)
    for b in range(int(o)):
        o+=o*int(o)
o*int(o)
```

This is exactly 100 characters if the indentations are tabs.

In order for the program to output, it needs to be run in a python console rather than in a file.

Score is unknown at this point because the inner for loop will run 10e707 times in the first iteration of the outer loop. and in total, there will be 176 iterations of the outer loop. Also, this output is too big for me to even comprehend how to mark the notation for it.

Comment: Unnecessary spacing [removed](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P982P7lEI78oRUO9Tl1Tkystv0ghUSEzT6EoMS89VSMzDyipqWnFpZCvbZuvBeFyKYBUJWGqQlYDY/z/DwA), there may be integer multiplication involved, there is nothing printed unless that's what the last line does, and the value of `o*int(o)` at the end should be approximately `10↑↑↑↑176`.

Comment: For a small optimization, the third line should be moved up so that the outer loop runs more times.