# Emoticon numbers!

Tags: math, code-challenge, restricted-source, integer, palindrome

[(related)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/18028/largest-number-printable)

Your challenge is to output the highest number you can. You can output as a number or as a string. You must output something that matches the regex `^\d+$`, as in only 0-9.

## The Twist

Your source code must be:

1. Same forwards and backwards
2. 3 bytes long
3. The middle byte must be different from the other two

Example valid:

```
0_0
)-)
m.m
xvx
W$W
@\@
```

Example invalid:

```
mnop
l__l
___
T_+
O_o
0_o
```

**Snippets are allowed**, you don't need a full program / function.

## Highest number outputted wins!

Comment: This is easy to brute force for any language.

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing highest number wins

Comment: @xnor true, but will produce intresting submissions.

Comment: Why the downvotes? **This was +2 in the sandbox**

Comment: @programmer5000 Perhaps because its trivial, boring, and leaves little room for interesting solutions? I haven't voted on it, but this might be why it stands currently at +1/-4

Comment: I downvoted because there are so few possible answers that it's impossible to be at all imaginative, and for most languages the optimal answer is the same (989, 9^9, 9e9, ...).

Comment: @Doorknob actually, many of the answers below use none of those.

Comment: All of which are, notably, esolangs. (And if you're counting by number of languages, the majority of them do.)

Comment: Is there a time limit?

Comment: "*You must output something that matches the regex `^\d+$`*" - So `e` isn't allowed in the output at all?

Comment: Quick, someone find a language in which `0/0` is `Infinity`. It's `NaN` in JS :/

Comment: @StephenS *"You must output something that matches the regex `^\d+$`"*

Comment: @programmer5000 Since snippets are allowed, does this mean that it could be assumed that the value returned is wrapped in a format call of some form - ie, could a snippet that outputs as `9000000000.0` or `9.00E+09` be assumed to return `9000000000`? - (this would add 16+ languages onto my polyglot :P )

Comment: @StephenS - I did it :P ; With `0/0` MATL takes input, implicitly convert to a numeric, and devides it by 0. This outputs `Inf` for all inputs which do not implicitly convert to `0`.

Comment: Can someone tell me what J outputs for `_ _`?

Comment: @carusocomputing I'm getting no output from that for particular string

Comment: I wonder what the *lowest* number would be... probably just `000` in most languages.

Answer (score 16):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 10<sup>3000</sup>

```
ȷ*ȷ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///Edq0T2///BwA)

#### How it works

`ȷ` denotes an scientific-notational number, as in `2ȷ6` for `2000000`. Without digits on either side, it defaults to a value of `1000`. `*` is exponentiation, giving 1000<sup>1000</sup>.

Answer (score 15):

## Polyglot (28+ Langs), \$9\times10^9\$

#### Works With:

#### APL, AWK, Arcyou, C#, CJam, Convex, Excel, Google Sheets, J, Japt, Java, JavaScript, MATL, MATLAB, MY-BASIC, Perl 5, Perl 6, PHP,  PowerShell, Python, R, RProgN, TI-BASIC, Uiua, VB, VB.NET, VBA, VBScript

This is a polyglot, if it works in your language add it to the list

```vb
9e9
```

or

```vb
9E9
```

or (Pretty much only for TI-BASIC)

```ti
9ᴇ9
```

[Try it Online.](https://tio.run/##K8ssLk3M0U1KLM5M1s1LLdHNzc/L///fNz@lNCdVwZEruDRJwTcxM48ruLK4JDVXzzk/rzg/J1UvvCizJFXDMtVSk8s1L0UBqAxMQ/T9/w8A) (VB.Net)

*(dependant on language)*

- Added Uiua thanks to @RomanPro100
- Added APL and J thanks to @Adám
- Added Python thanks to @VoteToReopen
- Added Japt thanks to @Shaggy
- Added Perl 5/6 thanks to @bradgilbertb2gills
- Added PowerShell thanks to @tessellatingheckler
- Added C# thanks to @TheLethalCoder
- Added Visual Basic Family
- Added R thanks to @JarkoDubbeldam
- Added AWK, Arcyou, CJam, Convex, MATL, MATLAB, PHP, RProgN, TI-Basic, MY-BASIC
- Added Java thanks to @KevinCruijssen
- Added Excel and Google Sheets

> Note: With formatting, supported by: Clojure, Common Lisp, Crystal, D, Go, Haskell, Java, Julia, Kotlin, Lua, Maxima, NIM, Racket, Rexx, Ruby, Rust, Scala

Comment: Works in APL and J.

Comment: Was this downvoted because it is a snippet,? If so, note that snippets have been allowed by the OP. If not, I fail to see why "this answer is not useful" applies.

Comment: [Brute force for J](https://tio.run/##XVDrToMwFP7fp/hEk1HdKgyXOAx7FdLQIp1AE2AqMeHV8ZSLM/vTnnO@y7mcx1GWpf3SKu2QxAjwglcm28wYl17iaI8nGHE8sEp2WaGVK/szYesFzwOmmFMSknpKWCtznSrrqBHIlHVNLwB4Aj3LnI@goq6VYJxNDGw2rLLK5EgEjsH@QMIHbLE0pebfprpUzjFNWfWhexeSKLdNajrdCMxyZQUDTC6wE/CDH4dx7GjmcIlnxqcsXat1UgctOocQZ4qvt9FiQHQXBz7B/A93GQaaieNRIHR97hc9uV39TlgXWBHg30pEWYvLZss8wHSk@bt55vvprLDYIDnRc7ambrvG1O/wYmiZFbPf29qL8XH8BQ). `9E9` (or `9e9`) is the largest possible value.

Comment: Works in [Japt](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=OWU5&input=).

Comment: Works in [Perl 5](http://perl.org) and [Perl 6](https://perl6.org).

Comment: I'm tempted to downvote this because it's pretty much an exact copy of programmer5000's answer, but since you don't have enough rep to see deleted things yet, I'll pass on calling you out for that. Have an upvote instead ;P

Comment: @HyperNeutrino programmer5000's answer had been down voted and deleted for the reason he answered his own challenge with a trivial solution before even waiting for answers. I think posting another solution is pretty legitimate in such a case, I mean, someone **had** to post this.

Comment: @Uriel Yes; I said I'd pass on saying it's a dupe partially because this is the obvious answer and because this answerer can't see that post in the first place.

Comment: I believe this should be turned into a community wiki

Comment: Apparently this works in C# too (who knew?).

Comment: As per my previous comment, I submitted a brute-forcer for this challenge, as an idea in the sandbox: https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12804/571

Comment: @HyperNeutrino someone mentioned it in the comments on Sandbox, so that's why programmer5000 posted it, probably.

Comment: @StephenS That would be a good explanation. Thanks.

Comment: I think it is safe to add `R` as well.

Comment: Already on the board as JS @CraigAyre :P but thanks - I'll correct my abbreviation

Comment: Works in Java as well. [The lowercase and uppercase letters at least, the third one with `ᴇ` doesn't work.](https://tio.run/##y0osS9TNL0jNy0rJ/v8/OSexuFjBNzEzr5pLQaGgNCknM1mhuCSxBEiV5WemKOQCpTSCS4oy89KjYxUSNUHKFBRS8oEqUxUqFGwVLFMtrZHFKkFirlAxfX2oaBVI9OGWdrB4LVft//8A)

Comment: [Works in Uiua](https://uiua.org/pad?src=0_10_0__OWU5Cg==)

Answer (score 10):

## Brainfuck, 255

```
-+-
```

Assuming 8-bit bounded cells.

---

<sub>Per [this meta consensus](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/), `the contents of the tape post-execution may be used as a Turing machine's output`.</sub>

Comment: You could also go for `-.-` which outputs the ASCII character code 255, and is also a relatively common emoticon.

Comment: @ZackC. I thought about it, but `.` will print `ÿ` where the question demands matching `\d+`. outputting through tape contents seemed to oversee this because it uses numbers (until printed).

Comment: By assuming larger cells (I think 32-bit cell interpreters exist, possibly even 64-bit cells), you can get bigger values!

Comment: @CalculatorFeline yea, but then I can claim for 1024, 2048, 4096... and there's no end (storage boundaries are not assumable). so I took on the common specs (and implementations) that lists 8 as a default when one exists.

Comment: "Languages are defined by their interpreters", so if you can find a 9999999999999999-bit interpreter, you can get 2^9999999999999999-1.

Comment: @CalculatorFeline python's int are almost unbeatable, so surely an interpreter that uses the whole RAM for calculating this overflow design can come to trillions of bits.

Comment: Python's integers are signed, so this would produce -1. You'd need an interpreter that wraps, finitizing the byte count.

Comment: @CalculatorFeline I meant there could be an interpreter that tries to produce the highest possible number in case of overflow

Comment: `the contents of the tape post-execution may be used as a Turing machine's output`

Answer (score 9):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 1.001001001001001e+299 = 100100100100100100100100100100100100100100100100100100100100100100100100100100100100100100100100100100100100100100100100100100100100100100100100100100100100100100100100100100100100100100100100100100100100100100100100100100100100100100100100100100100100100100100100100100100100100100100100100100100100

Found a bigger one thanks to ETHproductions informing me that strings were permitted.

```
LçL
```

[Try it](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=TOdM&input=)

---

### Explanation

- `L` is the Japt constant for the number `100`.
- The `ç` method, which takes string `s` as an argument, when applied to a number `n`, repeats `s` `n` times. If a number is passed as the argument, it's cast to a string.
- So, reading `LçL` backwards, it's "100 repeated 100 times".

---

### Original, 10<sup>200</sup>

```
LpL
```

[Try it](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=THBM&input=)

Comment: Explanation please.

Comment: Explanation added, @CalculatorFeline.

Answer (score 5):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 100! (93326215443944152681699238856266700490715968264381621468592963895217599993229915608941463976156518286253697920827223758251185210916864000000000000000000000000)

```
!т!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f9f8WKT4v//AA)

`т` is the constant 100 and the first `!` is just ignored.

Comment: Ah! `! > °` I see.

Answer (score 3):

## Mathematica, 387420489

this one

```
9^9
```

## Mathematica,  3265920

```
9!9
```

Comment: `9^9` is a larger number.

Comment: yes I realised it right after I posted it :-)

Answer (score 2):

## Vim, 999999999

```
9i9
```

Since *snippets are allowed*, this works in vim as well as V, so you'll have to hit escape after this.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v/3zLT8v9/AA)

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), `10e100`

```
°т°
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//0IaLTYc2/P8PAA)

*also it looks more like a uterus than a face...*

Comment: Looks like a bear face to be

Answer (score 2):

## [QBIC](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B0R1Jgqp8Gg4cVJCZkRkdEthZDQ), 10

```
?z?
```

The challenge specifically asks to "output" the number, and the only way to do that in QBIC is using `?`. So this prints `z` (which is 10 in QBIC) followed by 2 newlines.

A slightly more relaxed take on the rules would give us this snippet:

```
z^z
```

which is good for 10,000,000,000. It doesn't output anything (in fact, it doesn't even assign the result), but as a 3-byte `ABA` snippet it reaches the highest number possible.

Answer (score 2):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 39916800

```
ḟjḟ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r//@GO@VlA/P///ygA)

#### Explanation

```
ḟ      Factorial: the Input is a free variable, so it considers that its input is 0
 j     Juxtapose: 11
  ḟ    Factorial: 39916800
```

Answer (score 2):

## Japt, 2550

```
#ÿ#
```

3 bytes in extended ASCII, where `ÿ` has code 255. `#` gets it's code and returns it, while the second `#` returns simply 0, because nothing follows it.

[Try it online!](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=I/8j)

## Japt, 91

Really bad score. That's just an experiment

```
;I;
```

[Try it online!](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=O0k7)

```
;I;
;   Alternative variables mode
 I  Constant for 91
  ; Command separator - does nothing
```

## Japt, ~`1e+102` (cheating?)

Probably not valid answer, because Japt is transpiled to JS which automatically converts numbers to scientific notation.

```
LeL
```

It's basically 100^100.

[Try it online!](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=SWVJ&input=)

Comment: I don't see why `XeX` would be cheating; `9e9` is the best possible answer in a number of languages, including JS. And even if scientific notation was cheating, this technically isn't using it, because `e` is actually a method here, multiplying the first number by 10 to the second ;-)

Answer (score 1):

## [Braingolf](https://github.com/gunnerwolf/braingolf), 126

```
#~#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLz89J@/9fuU75/38A)

Yep, that's as high as Braingolf can go under these restrictions.

### Explanation:

```
#~   Pushes codepoint of ~ (126)
  #  Does nothing
     Implicit output of last item on stack
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Yabasic](http://www.yabasic.de), \$2^{1024}−2^{971}\$

Yabasic appears to have handle division by zero by returning the maximum `double` float value of \$2^{1024}−2^{971} \approx 1.797693134862316\times10^{308}\$. This means the snippet

```
0/0
```

returns a value of

```
1797693134862315708145274237317043567980705675258449965989174768031572
6078002853876058955863276687817154045895351438246423432132688946418276
8467546703537516986049910576551282076245490090389328944075868508455133
9423045832369032229481658085593321233482747978262041447231687381771809
19299881250404026184124858368.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##q0xMSizOTP7/395A30ChtDgzL11BSdXYwELPIE3p/38A)

*Note: the `Print` command converts any number with a length greater than 10 digits to scientific notation, so a `Using` command is used to print the value without converting it to scientific notation*

Comment: Is this some kind of integer overflow?

Answer (score 1):

## [Psi](https://psi.vazkii.us/index.php), 99980001

[image: Spell]

Not super inventive. And it's probably cheating.

I'd love to use Operator: Power instead, but the "base" and "power" arrows are different colors, making it not symmetrical.

Answer (score 0):

## [Aceto](https://github.com/aceto/aceto), 387420489

Since snippets are allowed,

```
9F9
```

*may* push 9^9 on the stack, depending on where in the code it is. An example of it working would be:

```
 9F9
   p
```

(the `p` merely prints, you could replace it with a nop and it would still work)