# How to improve Ruby code under some restrictions

Tags: code-golf, tips, ruby

I'm (still) trying to make another submission to the [Largest Number Printable](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/18028) question, and I've got the following bit of code:

```
f=->a{b,c,d=a;b ?a==b ?~-a:a==a-[c-c]?[[b,c,f[d]],~-c,b]:b:$n}
h=[],$n=?~.ord,[]
h=f[h]until h==p($n+=$n)-$n
```

Ungolfed:

```
f=->{b,c,d=a
if b
  if a==b # a is not an array
    return a-1
  elsif a==a-[0] # a does not contain 0
    t = [b,c,f[d]]
    return [t,c-1,b]
  else # a is an array containing 0
    return b
  end
else # if a == []
  return $n
end}

$n = 126
h = [[],n,[]]

until h==0 do
  $n += $n
  p $n
  h = f[h]
end
```

The conditions I'm working with:

- Maximum 100 bytes.
- No digits allowed in my code.

My code is currently at 108 bytes, but I can't figure out how to golf it further.

The `h==p($n+=$n)-$n` may be replaced with `h==0`, but I can't use digits and I still need to print `$n` and apply `$n+=$n` in the `until` loop.

I'm also satisfied with code that replaces `$n+=$n` with `$n+=1`, but I can't use digits unfortunately.

Any suggestions?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could include in your question a version of the code with whitespace and comments so we don’t have to figure every bit out on our own.

Comment: @Jordan Updated, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## 100 bytes

For my purposes, this is good enough.

```
h=[],n=?~.ord,n
f=->a{b,c,d=a;b ?a==b ?~-a:a==a-[c-c]?[[b,c,f[d]],~-c,b]:b:p(n+=n)}
h=f[h]until h==n
```

Replacing `h==0` with `h==n` will not cause the program to fail to terminate, which is what I needed.

Also improves on Jordan's answer by declaring `h` and `n` in the same line.

Answer (score 2):

## 105

You can save three bytes by declaring `n` as a local variable (instead of a global) before `f`:

```ruby
n=?~.ord
f=->a{b,c,d=a;b ?a==b ?~-a:a==a-[c-c]?[[b,c,f[d]],~-c,b]:b:n}
h=[],n,[]
h=f[h]until h==p(n+=n)-n
```

Comment: Thanks! For my purposes, this can be written [like so](https://tio.run/##FcpBCsIwEEbhfU/RpcUZD5Dym4MMs5gkhAgySrELEXP1WDePb/G2Pb3HaBAlR@yXx1bIpwq@2idRpgJb0xwNONrZwiFjyZw1ivyPKkWVOmdKGlLw79RQpenur9t9bsDz5Gf4wj7GDw), making it 103 bytes.