# Biggest number challenge (Brainfuck)

Tags: code-challenge, brainfuck

This is a brainfuck version of [Largest Number Printable](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/18028/largest-number-printable), and [this](http://djm.cc/bignum-results.txt).

---

Let's think about [brainfuck](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Brainfuck) interpreter such that,

1. Has array that can be stretched left & right arbitrary large
2. Each cell can contain arbitrary large integer

   - Can contain negative integer too
3. When the interpreter starts, every cell is intialized by 0
4. `.` prints integer representation of value of cell, then LF.

For example, `<<+++.>--.` prints

```
3
-2
```

, then terminate.

---

## Description

Your goal is to write a brainfuck program that prints a number/numbers.
The bigger the number, the more points you'll get.

There are some rules to follow.

- Your program **must** terminate.
- You **should not** use `,`.
- You **can** print multiple integers.
- Your score will be largest number that the program prints.
- Maximum code length is 1024 bytes. (Only `[]+-><.` counts)

[Here](https://gist.github.com/0xrgb/3b71cc150073d4e9a251ef8303db11ee) is sample brainfuck interpreter that you could test.

---

## Leaderboards

:)

Comment: What's the point in having a separate challenge while such answers can as well be posted to the other challenge?

Comment: @user202729 largest number printable challenge's maximum code lengths are 100, and it is quite short for brainfuck.

Comment: Here's a [TIO link](https://tio.run/##lVPBboMwDL33K3KDiBK12m0q/RHKIgqhjQQhCnQr/Xlmpxk0VEJaJIRj@z3bL4ke@murPsZRNro1PemGbuNMIzalqEhRi1zxoi1FeKefGwLLiP5mFPxYdzuHJki/TukpO7HDMYqzYEsC@O7UoiupSl63rZ7AA0lIKYs@pHb7gG2aWbNqDZFEAnGuLiKshQKQQ@GSFbmnMiNJQoI0mP2WhuVaC1WGkk5@Ub8isgXCiG8o/WAaeov31IsNFoQpCzd4MCCtO@86YXrb54NijR19lWewApibClG8LUEV3DSNBpKdNYvZPFe8EY0vz89V1gKTDgTrIJOvCHrSQj9njBYzPhnTBsNuwy6iDxu9hWZJRPa@WB5Z/D@yeJWMLci0kaoP31joCsVxQQEiRslq0cM7Il5HLK8VxN8nxZP206aDxDNGspUSy3vo4TwVCzcgMHCu8kZwbhk4b3KpOHdE0CAWABZ4vKzrS6mYEXnpbtAcfnnJzjllYH3ImF@rl4B32Dm2f9l0HCP2Cw) for your brainfuck interpreter

Comment: Is there any sort of time limit?

Comment: @JoKing There are no time limit for program. But it **must** terminate.

Comment: Doesn't really make a difference. Also we havecompressed BF too.

Comment: @user202729 Also, this challenge disallows to concatenate string(output). Therefore, we cannot use technique like `+...........`

Comment: Well, I watched Jo King 's answer. @user202729 is right. 100 bytes is enough for BF, and there is no point to have a seperate challenge. ~Please mark~ I will mark this challenge as duplicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Score: 2↑↑45306

Edit: Replaced it with a more modifiable version. Try [2↑↑2](https://tio.run/##lVPRjqsgEH1ev4I3NVSym/u2ofwI5RJXcZdEkaDdrf353gG5ttrEZEmMcGbOGeYAdhq/evPndtOd7d2IhmlI4tSppFYNqlpVGln1tcou@XuCYDg1np2BHxnOH5lL@d8TP4kToQwXIj2gFL5LHtiNNrVs@94u5AkdUa2rMcvD8gpLLsK06R3SSINwaT5V1ioDpMjyQzfowrVAxyNKeXrHgwwprVWmznS@4Kp9ZIgNw6lvKH0lFvZWvOWr2BRIPmUDA@IDOsDlMCg3hn1ec1/jNX@0ZwoGuLPJvHkH5F2I3XQWRF7DtLpPPxrZqW5tz8@XbpVPosjX8UprRzzCKzv3iDc9zoq88@G4IJ9qzDp7gM0ijN7WZq3Eit@JFbtiZCNmnTZj9qSS70iwjQSYiI@7Rekzo9hnbK8VxJ879Se9TlsO0p@xF9spsb2HK97KxSo2CApSmrJTUgYFKbtSGymjEGzQFwAVeLxkGGttiFNlHW/QPfzwkiO4ZPj6kHF/rasEf4cjcPifnd9uGCcMY5rwkMR4wRhmmFI6t88YC/85/EJ5QTHFjIllDckieWGsCIgAZI6BRJGIhJF/), [2↑↑3](https://tio.run/##lVPRjqsgEH1ev4I3NVSym/u2ofwI5RJXcZdEkaDdrf353gG5ttrEZEmMcGbOGeYAdhq/evPndtOd7d2IhmlI4tSppFYNqlpVGln1tcou@XuCYDg1np2BHxnOH5lL@d8TP4kToQwXIj2gFL5LHtiNNrVs@94u5AkdUa2rMcvD8gpLLsK06R3SSINwaT5V1ioDpMjyQzfowrVAxyNKeXrHgwwprVWmznS@4Kp9ZIgNw6lvKH0lFvZWvOWr2BRIPmUDA@IDOsDlMCg3hn1ec1/jNX@0ZwoGuLPJvHkH5F2I3XQWRF7DtLpPPxrZqW5tz8@XbpVPosjX8UprRzzCKzv3iDc9zoq88@G4IJ9qzDp7gM0ijN7WZq3Eit@JFbtiZCNmnTZj9qSS70iwjQSYiI@7Rekzo9hnbK8VxJ879Se9TlsO0p@xF9spsb2HK97KxSo2CApSmrJTUgYFKbtSGymjEGzQFwAVeLxkGGttiFNlHW/QPfzwkiO4ZPj6kHF/rasEf4cjcPifnd9uGOOEYUwTHrIYLxjDDFNK5/4ZY@E/h18oLyimmDGxrCFZJC@MFQERgMwxkCgSkTDyDw), and [2↑↑4](https://tio.run/##lVPRjqsgEH1ev4I3NVSym/u2ofwI5RJXcZdEkaDdrf353gG5ttrEZEmMcGbOGeYAdhq/evPndtOd7d2IhmlI4tSppFYNqlpVGln1tcou@XuCYDg1np2BHxnOH5lL@d8TP4kToQwXIj2gFL5LHtiNNrVs@94u5AkdUa2rMcvD8gpLLsK06R3SSINwaT5V1ioDpMjyQzfowrVAxyNKeXrHgwwprVWmznS@4Kp9ZIgNw6lvKH0lFvZWvOWr2BRIPmUDA@IDOsDlMCg3hn1ec1/jNX@0ZwoGuLPJvHkH5F2I3XQWRF7DtLpPPxrZqW5tz8@XbpVPosjX8UprRzzCKzv3iDc9zoq88@G4IJ9qzDp7gM0ijN7WZq3Eit@JFbtiZCNmnTZj9qSS70iwjQSYiI@7Rekzo9hnbK8VxJ879Se9TlsO0p@xF9spsb2HK97KxSo2CApSmrJTUgYFKbtSGymjEGzQFwAVeLxkGGttiFNlHW/QPfzwkiO4ZPj6kHF/rasEf4cjcPifnd9uGEbCMKYJD2mMF4xhhimlswGMsfCfwy@UFxRTzJhY1pAskhfGioAIQOYYSBSJSBj5Bw) ([2↑↑5](https://tio.run/##lVPRjqsgEH1ev4I3NVSym/u2ofwI5RJXcZdEkaDdrf353gG5ttrEZEmMcGbOGeYAdhq/evPndtOd7d2IhmlI4tSppFYNqlpVGln1tcou@XuCYDg1np2BHxnOH5lL@d8TP4kToQwXIj2gFL5LHtiNNrVs@94u5AkdUa2rMcvD8gpLLsK06R3SSINwaT5V1ioDpMjyQzfowrVAxyNKeXrHgwwprVWmznS@4Kp9ZIgNw6lvKH0lFvZWvOWr2BRIPmUDA@IDOsDlMCg3hn1ec1/jNX@0ZwoGuLPJvHkH5F2I3XQWRF7DtLpPPxrZqW5tz8@XbpVPosjX8UprRzzCKzv3iDc9zoq88@G4IJ9qzDp7gM0ijN7WZq3Eit@JFbtiZCNmnTZj9qSS70iwjQSYiI@7Rekzo9hnbK8VxJ879Se9TlsO0p@xF9spsb2HK97KxSo2CApSmrJTUgYFKbtSGymjEGzQFwAVeLxkGGttiFNlHW/QPfzwkiO4ZPj6kHF/rasEf4cjcPifnd9u2I@EYUwTHvIYLxjDDFNKZwcYY@E/h18oLyimmDGxrCFZJC@MFQERgMwxkCgSkTDyDw) times out)

Just testing the waters with a short answer.

```
+>+>++>++>++>++++>++[>[<+++++>-]<<]>
>++<
[
    >[->>+>+<<<]
    >>>
    [
        <[-<+<+>>]
        <[->+<]
        >>-
    ]
    <[-]<<<-
]
>.
```

The ↑↑ indicate [Knuth's arrow notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%27s_up-arrow_notation), where a single ↑, such as `X↑Y`, means (((X*Y)*Y)*Y)... X times = X^Y, and two ↑↑s means (((X↑Y)↑Y)↑Y)... X times. For example, 2↑↑4 = 2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2</sup></sup></sup>.

(I'm not familiar with bignum notation, so please tell me if there's a shorter way of representing this, or there's an error in my calculations)

## Explanation:

```
+>+>++>++>++>++++>++[>[<+++++>-]<<]>
```

Produces the number 45306. (Taken from the [brainfuck constants page on Esolangs](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Brainfuck_constants#45306), an immensely useful page). This will be used as the counter.

```
>++<
```

Sets the current value as two and move back to the counter

```
[ Loop until the counter is 0

    Square the current value
    >[->>+>+<<<]
    >>>
    [
        <[-<+<+>>]
        <[->+<]
        >>-
    ]<[-]

    Decrement the counter
    <<<-
]
```

A few ways to extend this:

- Increase the counter. Pretty easy to do.
- Increase the initial value. To be simple, you could just set the initial value and the counter as the same number
- Remove the clear cell in the squaring operation, which compounds the result
- Create another counter and put another loop around the whole thing

  - This effectively adds another Knuth's Arrow to the result (I think)
  - Further addition, for each iteration of the outer loop, copy the current value to use as the inner loop's counter
  - And then put another loop around the whole lot again.

Comment: Squaring 2 45306 times only gives you 2^2^45306.

Comment: @lirtosiast Yeah, I feel kinda stupid looking back at this. I was mixing up \$((2^2)^2)^2...\$ with \$2^{2^{2^{2...}}}\$