# Busy beaver of sorts

Tags: code-challenge, busy-beaver

I'm surprised this hasn't been done yet, but here we go.

Create a program which prints some number of 1s (ideally as large as possible) before halting.

The rules are simple:

Your program is bounded to 50 bytes in size.

Your output must only be a continuous row of 1s (plus trailing newline if it has to be added), without any breaks in the middle.

Your program must halt. No infinite loops.

Your program must not use STDIN or output to STDERR.

Your program must use STDOUT or closest equivalent.

Your score is the amount of 1s your program prints before halting.

Have fun.

Comment: Well, there have been many extremely related challenges, with the only significant difference that they didn't arbitrarily demand unary output (https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/18028/largest-number-printable is the first one I can recall; there have been some like "Golf a number bigger than [insert large number name here]")

Comment: I was looking to emulate busy beaver Turing machines in this challenge.

Answer (score 3):

## [Runic Enchantments](https://github.com/Draco18s/RunicEnchantments/tree/Console), Score: Aproximately <s>(10↑↑200)</s> (10↑↑303)<sup>18.877</sup>

```
>>>yybbqf:p'!A'!A'!A'!A'!A'!A'!A'!A'!A'!AFm1)b*?*@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyrNy0z@/9/Ozq6yMimpMM2qQF3REQ9yyzXUTNKy13L4/x8A)

Utilizes Stephen's idea of factorials (they're kind of expensive in Runic, so I hadn't considered them originally) and managed to squeeze out <s>two</s> *three hundred* of them via implicit edge looping. Value-in is `15^15` (`437,893,890,380,859,375`) and the resulting value is then multiplied against the *string* `1111` (`bbq` is just as long as `"1"` and produces more 1s).

`200->300` accomplished by removing flow control logic and simply raising the "skip when true" to jump over the start of the program (executes the `:p` for bonus length, but is dwarfed by the factorials, but is responsible for the extra 3 powers of 10 in the tower).

["Wolfram|Alpha doesn't understand your query"](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%283%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29)

Answer (score 2):

## Python, 9^9^9^9^9^9^9^9^9^9^9^9^9 (or 9↑↑13)

```
print("1"*(9**9**9**9**9**9**9**9**9**9**9**9**9))
```

I hope this is right

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v6AoM69EQ8lQSUvDUkuLMLLU/P8fAA)

Comment: you are right, my bad

Answer (score 2):

## MATLAB, Score: 9↑↑(2↑(10↑313))

```
x=9;
while(cputime<realmax/2)
x=x^x;
end
ones(1,x)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f@/wtbSmqs8IzMnVSO5oLQkMzfVpig1MSc3sULXUJOrwrYirsKaKzUvhSs/L7VYw1CnQvP/fwA)

`cputime` counts the number of seconds that the MATLAB thread actually runs on the CPU as a double. `realmax` is the maximum double, `~10^308`; I divide by 2 because cputime will rollover back to zero and we actually need the loop to stop. According to the profiler, on my computer MATLAB can run the loop `1e6` times in about `3.7 seconds`. That means we'll perform `x=x^x` about `10^313` times! That isn't just 9↑↑(10↑313), because it compounds on every loop. It's  9↑↑(2↑(10↑313)) I think. I could cheat and make the condition `cputime==realmax/2`, and then it would be up to random chance when the program finally ends, making an absolutely insane number, but one that can't be calculated.

---

## MATLAB, Score: 9↑↑79 (or about (10↑↑78)<sup>8.568</sup>)

```
f=@(x) factorial(x)^x;
ones(1,f(f(f(f(9^9^9^9)))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f8/Py@1WMNQJy0xuSS/KDMxR8NUU/P/fwA)

Probly not as big as the power tower answers though. I need to figure out a short way to do that here.

Comment: @Draco18s Sorry I overwrote your edit. Can you figure out about how big this version is? Wolfram stalls out

Comment: @Draco18s Nah, the `^x` does something. `factorial(9^9^9^9)^factorial(9^9^9^9)` is already 10||9 https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=factorial%289%5E9%5E9%5E9%29%5Efactorial%289%5E9%5E9%5E9%29

Comment: @Draco18s I'll try to work it out later, with Stirling's approximation or something

Comment: Think I figured it out. On some value `x↑↑y` your lambda `f` results in `(x↑↑(y+1))^(x↑↑y)`. For some value `(x↑↑y)^(x↑↑z)` that is equal to `x↑↑(y+z)`. So your answer should have a score of 9↑↑79 (which is a little less than 10↑↑79; (10↑↑78)^8.568).

Comment: @Draco18s Nice! Go ahead and edit if you want

Comment: Was definitely one of those "go get lunch and mull over the problem" sort of solutions. I ran through what "10↑↑2 ^ 10↑↑2" *meant* and then the pattern made sense.

Comment: @Draco18s Did I calculate this new one correctly?

Comment: @Draco18s I didn't consider the loop will start running slower and slower but whatever

Comment: \*Shrug\* My answer would suffer from bit-overflow (and memory) long before actual termination. Usually with busy-beaver type problems there's an assumption of infinite memory. The loop you have *looks* like it would have linear execution, so its treated as linear (even as when more and more bits get coopted to store the result it does take longer). (I also cleaned up some no-longer-needed comments)

Comment: @Draco18s Ok yeah it should be linear. This isn't BigInteger. But I think I did goof: shouldn't it be 9||(2|(10|313))? It doubles every loop

Comment: `9↑↑(2↑(10↑313))` would be correct, yeah.

Answer (score 2):

## [cQuents](https://github.com/stestoltz/cQuents), Aproximately (10↑↑45)<sup>7.347</sup>

```
"#t!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!&1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy4sTc0rKf7/X0m5RJEUoGb4/z8A)

Note that it does not start printing the 1s until it calculates the result of the factorial, so this probably will not run on any real system.

According to Wolfram Alpha, this value equals

[image]

or in plaintext

```
10^(10^(10^(10^(10^(10^(10^(10^(10^(10^(10^(10^(10^(10^(10^(10^(10^(10^(10^(10^(10^(10^(10^(10^(10^(10^(10^(10^(10^(10^(10^(10^(10^(10^(10^(10^(10^(10^(10^(10^(10^(10^(10^(10^(10^7.346902562777663))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))
```

Comment: I originally discounted factorials because computing one in Runic takes 3 bytes, but they're individually powerful, definitely boosted my score.

Answer (score 2):

### Python 3 <strike>approx 9↑↑(36^8)</strike> 9↑↑(36↑(9↑↑3))

```
print("1"*eval("**".join("9"*int('z'*9**9**9,36)))
```

Must calculate first.

(Edited because I'm bad at math notation, and to include an improvement from  randomdude999)

Comment: `9**9**9` is larger than `9999999`.

Comment: *Pretty* sure your score is correct, though I am not 100% certain (for reference `x↑↑y` ~= `10↑↑y`; the `y` makes a bigger impact and that's a BIG `y`).

Comment: @Draco18s The `int(..., 36)` means "This number in base-36". With the first argument, it's `'zzzz....'` as an integer with 0-9 then a-z as the digits. So, I'm pretty sure that it's just one arrow.

Comment: I knew what the *command* was, I just couldn't deal with what the *resulting value* was. I think you're correct though.

Comment: @Draco18s Oh gotcha. Thanks for the help with the notation! Never been my strong suit.

Comment: Yep, ended up having some understandings in that regard, too. Just like `x^y * x^z = x^(y+z)`, `(x↑↑y)^(x↑↑z)` is [equal to](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/194680/busy-beaver-of-sorts/194690?noredirect=1#comment463538_194690) `x↑↑(y+z)`. I just found it *really* fascinating that `factorial(x↑↑y)` equals* `x↑↑(y+1)`. *Or is at least a [pretty good approximation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/194680/busy-beaver-of-sorts/194690?noredirect=1#comment463503_194703).

Comment: The result can be approximated to 9↑↑9↑↑4, which in turn is somewhere between 9↑↑↑2 and 9↑↑↑3. From my understanding, this means it should be the highest score at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 43 bytes, Score: ~1e17 (based on my PC performance)

```php
set_time_limit(-1);while(time()<4e9)echo 1;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jXwAki1NL4ksyc1PjczJzM0s0dA01rcszMnNSNUCCGpo2JqmWmqnJGfkKhtb//wMA)

This will run until `2096-10-02` and then stop. This isn't an infinite loop as it will finally halt. I can set it to longer dates, but I think `4e9` or `2096-10-02` is good enough for me, it is about the idea

Comment: This is dumb, but it works.

Comment: Even if this printed one 1 every nanosecond this would score much less than most of the other answers so far.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman, true.

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), approx. (10↑↑46)<sup>10.994</sup> amount of `1`s (50 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage))

```
žm!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!1×
```

**Explanation:**

```python
žm             # Push the builtin 9876543210
  !!!...!!!    # Take the factorial 46 times
           1×  # Push that many 1s as string
               # (after which it's output implicitly as result)
```

This will print exactly \$9876543210↑↑46\$ amount of `1`s, or approx. \$(10↑↑46)^{10.994}\$ (thanks to *@Draco18s* for explaining how to calculate this \$(10↑↑a)^b\$ approximation.

Comment: *`how large 9876543210↑↑56 is`*. Only about (10↑↑56)^11. Two arrows (10↑↑2) is just powers (10^10) (or `10↑↑3 -> 10^10^10`), so the number on the right matters more than the number on the left. It works out that each factorial adds a 10 to the tower. Also, I think your tower is 46, not 56.

Comment: @Draco18s Oops, 46 instead of 56 indeed, edited. I know \$10↑↑3\$ is \$10^{{10}^{10}}\$, I just wasn't sure how large \$9876543210↑↑46\$ is when using \$10↑↑x\$ as well. I'm still not sure how you calculated that \$11\$ in \$9876543210↑↑56 ≈  (10↑↑56)^{11}\$ to be honest, or is the \$11\$ the size of the integer on the right + 1?

Comment: I understood why you had the question, it just works out that x↑↑y is approximately equal to (10↑↑y) (or closer to (10↑↑y)^(log10(2x))). [eg 100↑↑4](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=100%5E100%5E100%5E100) and [10↑↑4](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=10%5E10%5E10%5E10). Note that the first one is (10↑↑4)^2.3, but W|A displays powers of ten up to 5 digits, but we can [extract the right value](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=log10%28200%29). The log10 bit just tacks on to the end of the stack (100↑↑4 -> 10^10^10^10^2.3), parents only distinguish it from `10↑↑(10^2.3)` (wrong!)

Comment: @Draco18s Hmm ok. But why the \$11\$ then? Since \$\log_{10}(2×9876543210)\$ [seems to be approx. \$10.296\$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=log10%282*9876543210%29) instead of \$11\$. So the \$9876543210↑↑46\$ in my answer would be roughly \$(10↑↑46)^{10.296}\$ in that case?

Comment: Works out to what happened when I plugged it (9876543210) in to W|A 5 times. I got 10.994. The `log10(2x)` is only an approximation, and its a bit low. ([100](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=100%5E100%5E100%5E100) results in a power of 200.3 on top of the tens, for example, not exactly 200). But if I plug in 15 copies instead of 5, that last value doesn't change (or if it does, its very small), so its easy to extrapolate what happens at 50 copies.

Comment: @Draco18s Ah ok, now it makes a bit more sense, thanks. I'll edit my answer to add the \$10↑↑x\$ notation.