# Calculate the a ^ b WITHOUT using *, / and ^

Tags: code-golf, math

## Challenge

Your goal is, given two positive integer numbers a and b, to calculate (and output) a ^ b without using either multiplication, division and the power itself (not directly, at least).
And, of course, built-in exponentiation functions.

## Scoring

This is code-golf, so the shorter, the better.

## Test cases

```
Input => Output
2, 3 => 8
5, 5 => 3125
100, 4 => 100000000
17, 9 => 118587876497
0, 1 => 0
3921, 0 => 1
```

Comment: I assume by `^` you mean exponentiation? In some languages `^` has a different meaning.

Comment: Welcome to Programming Puzzles & Code Golf. This is currently underspecified, since the symbols `^`, `*`, `/` and `^` can have a completely different meaning in my language of choice than you intended. Please note that [do X without Y](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/8079) challenges are rather hard to write, because of loopholes, ambiguities and similarity to other [*restricted-source*](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/restricted-source) challenges.

Comment: I think it's a possible duplicate of [Exponentiation of natural numbers using only primitive integer operations](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/54300/7416) (which might not really be a duplicate, although it's currently marked as such)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## k (19 bytes)

This is slow and uses lots of memory:

```
{#,//(x#,:)/[y;0b]}
```

The `/`s are not division, it's the [converge](http://code.kx.com/wiki/Reference/Slash#converge) operator.