# Work out \$x^y\$ using only addition and subtraction

Tags: code-golf, math, number, arithmetic, restricted-source

The challenge is to implement a function or program that takes two numbers, \$x\$ and \$y\$ and return the result of \$x^y\$.

The program cannot use any other mathematical operation other than \$+\$ or \$-\$, so no multiplication or division. Functions built into languages are also not allowed.

The code in the least amount of bytes wins.

Comment: Hi, maybe this question belongs to https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/ or https://math.stackexchange.com/ rather than here

Comment: In general, [we avoid](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8079/43319) challenges of the type "do x without y".

Comment: Are `x` and `y` guaranteed to be integers? What counts as "other mathematical operation"s ... does equality and inequality count? How about array or string multiplication that isn't a mathematical operator but creates copies of the array or string?

Comment: Duplicate of [Calculate the a ^ b WITHOUT using \*, / and ^](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/78942/calculate-the-a-b-without-using-and) which itself is a duplicate of [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/54300/43319) which is a duplicate of [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/5562/43319)…

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 7 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

Anonymous tacit infix function. *y* is left argument and *x* is right argument.

```apl
(+/⍴)/⍴
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///X0Nb/1HvFk0Q8T/tUduER719j/qmevo/6mo@tN74UdtEIC84yBlIhnh4Bv83UkhTMOYyAZJGXCC2oQGXoQGIBwA)

`⍴` cyclically reshape (gives *y* copies of *x*)

`(`…`)/` reduce by the following function:

`⍴` cyclically reshape to left argument copies of right argument

`+/` sum

Comment: I was groping toward this solution in a "traditional" mode; however, for some reason, I can never get APL to produce output on TIO - what might I be doing wrong? The test case I was trying with was `+/4⍴+/3⍴3`, to see if I was on the right track for 3^4.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin If you put code in TIO's Code field, you must use `⎕←` to output.

Comment: Thanks. I don't know a facepalm emoticon/emoji, but consider it included here...

Comment: @JeffZeitlin ︎

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 53 bytes

```python
lambda x,y:y>1and sum(x for _ in range(f(x,y-1)))or x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PcpBCoMwEADAu6/YY7KsYDaeCu1LBInYtEJdJUZIXh9zsddh9hy/m3Dxz6H83DrNDhLlR34ZJzMc56oS@C3ACItAcPJ5K6/qaI3Wunoqe1gkgleWek1gEfvmJiZbiRHtn0xHXM10iFwu)